# I am not able to link meta's questions and answers as Top Post to my Developer story

Tags: discussion, feature-request, developer-story

I want to show off my upvoted questions and answers of Meta Stack Overflow in my developer story. [Several](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2828434%20score%3A15%20duplicate%3Ano) of my questions and answers on Meta had received a great response. I strongly think that my meta post can convey my analysis and innovation skills. But I just can't add the meta SO link in my developer story.

Please provide ability to link the top posts of meta sites as well.

[image]

**Edit**:

In the answer of @abccd, @abccd linked '[Introducing the developer story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313960/introducing-the-developer-story)' meta post, that first announced developer story (and received many downvotes) and I asked this feature request based on '[The Developer Story Part 2: We didn't explain that very well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314636/the-developer-story-part-2-we-didnt-explain-that-very-well)' meta post that actually clarified the announcement and redefined the scope of developer story better.

**Why allowing to link meta post to developer story is a good idea?**

I'll take the excerpts from the sequel meta post that I mentioned above:

> It's called "Developer Story" but I'm not a developer; can I still use it?
>   Even if your title isn't developer, we have jobs posted for developers, sysadmins and project managers; this feature is available to everyone on Stack Overflow regardless of job title.

Sure, as @abccd says, Meta sites are indeed for discussions regarding Stack Exchange sites and the software that powers the sites. However, **Meta Stack Overflow** is little different. It is this site where site's major changes are announced, experimented, taken feedback on, A/B tested, put on live and bugs reported.

From clever [design](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design+bug?sort=votes&pageSize=50) bug reports, new feature requests, to major announcements like Documentation, Teams, developer story, Question template wizard etc.- most of them comes in here first, and intensely discussed, fought, trolled and signed off.

Fyi, till date,

**[678 questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20%5Bbug%5D%5Bstatus-completed%5Dscore%3A10%20)** are tagged with [bug] with [status completed] and upvotes greater than 10.

**[137 questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20%5Bdesign%5D%5Bbug%5D%5Bstatus-completed%5Dscore%3A10%20)** are tagged with [design] and [bugs] with [status completed] and upvotes greater than 10.

**[211 questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20%5Bfeature-request%5D%5Bstatus-completed%5Dscore%3A10%20)** are tagged with [Feature Request] with [status completed] and upvotes greater than 10.

**Therefore,** any of the well-received design or functional bug report, feature-request, feedback or answer on Meta SO are also good enough to convey "every aspect of <s>developer</s> job-seeker's identity" where job seeker can be designer, db admin, project manager, system analyst, full stack developer etc.

Therefore, IMO, it's a good idea to have MSO posts linked in developer story.

Comment: You can (and should) do it in your user profile page.

Comment: Although it would be a good idea if the error message can be made more explicit ("you cannot link a meta post")

Answer (score 1):

IMO, it wouldn't make much sense to allow meta links in your **developer story** as one of your "Top Post".

[According to this meta post:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313960/introducing-the-developer-story)

> [Developer story is] the way we envision you showcasing every
>   aspect of your developer identity.

Meta sites are for discussions regarding Stack Exchange sites and the softwares that powers the sites; therefore, questions and answers posted in meta carry little to no meaning regarding you as a developer nor they relate to any "aspect of your developer identity".

For that reason, I'm against this [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Comment: I have edited my question and added more points that justifies feature-request

Comment: Being a good writer and capable of presenting to a diverse audience can be part of being a good developer.