# The reputation points for writing documentation should be increased and there should be a verified documentation option

Tags: feature-request, documentation

Most of the time creating a new documentation topic requires more time than a simple answer. So in my opinion the incentive for writing documentation should be increased and there should be a way to verify documentation.

Comment: There are already enough people farming reputation by writing poor documentation :/

Comment: But the quality of the posts would improve if the points rewarded are increased in my opinion.

Comment: Nop, because people writing poor documentation validate other's one while they hope to be validated. And if they don't they'll come here and ask "why my (poor) documentation post" rejected. If you search the question tag documentation, you can see that reputation, poor posts and so on has been discussed a lot.

Comment: The points rewarded were larger in the past, the quality of documentation has not declined since points were reduced so it seems unlikely that raising them again would result in any increase in documentation quality.

Comment: @Md.IbrahimHassan The people who can/do write great content tend to care very little about rep.  The people that tend to really care about rep tend to provide low quality content, as such, the lower the amount of rep given for work on documentation, the higher the quality.

Comment: Related: [Documentation shares the work; make the rewards shared, not multiplicative](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329506) and see the "Related" sidebar there.

Answer (score 5):

It is good that you are putting efforts but there are already many [discussions happened](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328703/addressing-documentation-repgateapocalypse?noredirect=1&lq=1) on reputation provided on documentation and every unnecessary reputation are already rollbacked.

New reputation update is applied and no new reputation update will applied soon.

Citing from [Reputation update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334551/documentation-reputation-update-is-live?noredirect=1&lq=1)

> Gaining Reputation
>
> 1. Whenever a change is approved, the author receives +2 reputation,
>      unless...
>
>    - They were the last editor to all the topics modified in that
>        change or
>    - The change rolls a topic (or topic(s)) back to a previous
>        state
> 2. If an answer cites a topic or example, and that answer is
>      upvoted each contributor gets a one-time +5
>
>    - A user is considered a
>        contributor if they have ever net added 20 or more characters to the
>        topic or example (more on contributors below)
>    - This only happens once
>        per answer-user-pair, multiple links do not stack
>    - This only happens on
>        the first upvote after a documentation link has been added, no user
>        can gain more than +5 reputation per-answer from Documentation
> 3. Whenever an example is upvoted, major contributors to the example get
>      +5 reputation and minor contributors get +1 reputation
>
>    - Minor contributors are everyone who has added at least 20 characters to an
>        example as part of a single change
>    - Major contributors are the creator
>        of the example plus everyone who has added at least 350 characters to
>        an example
>    - The 350 characters may be split across several changes,
>        provided that each change adds at least 20 characters