# Index of Documentation update announcements

Tags: discussion, documentation

Is there a collated list of [Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) updates by developers?

Comment: I tried to provide a more descriptive title; in particular, this question isn't itself a Documentation update.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[image]

## Announcements

#### Pre Private Beta

- [Warlords of Documentation: A Proposed Expansion of Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow) (Aug 31 '15)
- [Warlords of Documentation: Your Quest(ions Answered)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306213/warlords-of-documentation-your-questions-answered) (Sep 16 '15)

#### Private Beta

- [Documentation: The Update-en-ing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319319/documentation-the-update-en-ing) (Mar 18 '16)

#### Public Beta

- [Documentation Has Entered Public Beta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328405/documentation-has-entered-public-beta) (Jul 21 '16)
- [Addressing Documentation #RepGateApocalypse](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328703/addressing-documentation-repgateapocalypse) (Jul 21 '16)
- [Can we use citations to evaluate the usefulness of Examples?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329474/can-we-use-citations-to-evaluate-the-usefulness-of-examples) (Jul 25 '16)
- [FYI - New Documentation Review Queue for Proposed Changes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334300/fyi-new-documentation-review-queue-for-proposed-changes) (Sep 11 '16)
- [Documentation Reputation Update Is Live](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334551/documentation-reputation-update-is-live) (Sep 14 '16)
- [Tearing Down the Structure of Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349410/tearing-down-the-structure-of-documentation) (May 18 '17)

#### Discontinuation

- [Sunsetting Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation) (Aug 1, '17)
- [Documentation is read-only. What’s next?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355115/documentation-is-read-only-what-s-next) (Aug 15, '17)
- [Removing Documentation: Reputation, Archive, and Links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356294/removing-documentation-reputation-archive-and-links) (Sep 8, '17)

---

## Periodic Updates

#### Private Beta

- [Welcome to the Stack Overflow Documentation Beta!](http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/questions/1?noredirect=1) (Nov 4 '15)
- [November 19th New Features Announcement](http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/questions/85/november-19th-new-features-announcement?noredirect=1) (Nov 19 '15)
- [December 8th New Features Announcement](http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/questions/197/december-8th-new-features-announcement?noredirect=1) (Dec 8 '15)
- [December 21st-ish New Features Announcement](http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/questions/249/december-21st-ish-new-features-announcement?noredirect=1) (Dec 23 '15)
- [January 13th New Features Announcement](http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/questions/250/january-13th-new-features-announcement?noredirect=1) (Jan 13 '16)
- [Reputation System Announcement](http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/questions/326/documentation-reputation-system-announcement?noredirect=1) (Feb 1 '16)
- [February 16th New Features Announcement](http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/questions/349/february-16th-new-feature-announcements?noredirect=1) (Feb 16 '16)
- [March 15th New Features Announcement](http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/questions/495/march-15th-new-feature-announcement?noredirect=1) (Mar 15 '16)
- [April 6th New Features Announcement](http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/questions/862/april-6th-new-features-announcement?noredirect=1) (Apr 6 '16)
- [April 13th New Features Announcement](http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/questions/984/april-13th-new-feature-announcement?noredirect=1) (Apr 13 '16)
- [May 7th New Features Announcement](http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/questions/1253/may-7th-new-feature-announcement?noredirect=1) (May 7 '16)
- [June 2nd New Features Announcement](http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/june-2nd-new-features-announcement?noredirect=1) (Jun 2 '16)
- [July 11th (**FINAL**) New Features Announcement](http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/questions/1612/july-11th-announcements?noredirect=1) (Jul 11 '16)
- [Data Migration to Stack Overflow happens July 16](http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/questions/1615/data-migration-to-stack-overflow-happens-tomorrow?noredirect=1) (Jul 15 '16)

#### Public Beta

- [Documentation Update, July 25th](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329557/documentation-update-july-25th) (Jul 25 '16)
- [Documentation Update, August 4th](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331663/documentation-update-august-4th) (Aug 4 '16)
- [Documentation Update, August 29th](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333420/documentation-update-august-29th) (Aug 9 '16)
- [Documentation Update, September 12th](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334404/documentation-update-september-12th) (Sep 12 '16)
- [Documentation Update, September 29th](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335529/documentation-update-september-29th) (Sep 29 '16)
- [Documentation Update, October 20th](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336627/documentation-update-october-20th) (Oct 20 '16)
- [Documentation Update, November 29th](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338676/documentation-update-november-29th) (Nov 29 '16)
- [The dawn of Documentation: a solstice update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339974/the-dawn-of-documentation-a-solstice-update) (Dec 20 '16)
- [Documentation Update, February 6th](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343091/documentation-update-february-6th) (Feb 6 '17)
- [What's going on with Documentation this month?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350492/whats-going-on-with-documentation-this-month) (Jun 10 '17)