# Posting equal code for answers and questions by the others to improve them

Tags: feature-request

Some questions are concepts would be use in different language but inquirers put their codes in their own language(like php) and the other answer the question only in that language. like [Yii2: logout from all browser after a user change password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32734148/yii2-logout-from-all-browser-after-a-user-change-password)

it would be interesting if we had a feature like edit ( which everyone can edit the question), which users could put equal code in other languages for codes in  answers or questions, if they know, and stackoverflow gave them bronze, silver or gold or whatever.

unless if someone's looking for a answer in c# but found it in php, maye he will post the question in stackoverflow again.

Comment: Are you referring to language-independent questions (like "how can I sort a group of objects when comparisons are very slow?") or questions specific to one language that would also be useful pertaining to others (like "how can I print italics using Java")?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think this will work in the current question/answer format.

The tags on the question need to change (or we need new answer tags or something like that) and voting will be near to impossible or even become meaningless. You didn't share much detail but I think you don't want to have the c# answer be the highest voted answer on a php question. Inspired by the comment from [Michael Meyers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306698/posting-equal-code-for-answers-and-questions-by-the-others-to-improve-them/306705?noredirect=1#comment250628_306705) I found [this gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930/factorial-algorithms-in-different-languages) that demonstrates where you could end up with...

Your feature request touches an issue that is solvable today. It is perfectly okay to ask the same question in C# about a piece of PHP code. You link to the php question, show the code you have in c# and explain what doesn't work or works/behaves differently/gives awkward code/doesn't perform as good as in php, etc...

Those questions all keep their own tag, while they are still *connected* due to the linked question box at the right side of the screen.

Another place (highly unknown and under valued) where you could do this is in tag wiki's. For example [while-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/while-loop/info) could have either examples of while loops in java/c#/c++/php/python/javascript (or link to questions that explain those statements). Instead the tag-wiki of  [while-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/while-loop) is a blatant copy of Wikipedia.

Last upcoming place where the issue your feature request tries to solve would fit in is the [documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306213/warlords-of-documentation-your-questions-answered?cb=1) feature. I see it as tag-wiki's on steroids but it can certainly held that combined knowledge across languages for a shared concept.

Comment: We used to see [tag:rosetta-stone] questions, but they didn't work out very well.

Comment: Interesting, @MichaelMyers. However  the history seems to be whipped on that. I found some [references on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=rosetta-stone) which gave me one reasonable anti-example. I'm open for other suggestions.