# What does the Stack Overflow dev team spend their time on?

Tags: discussion

I'm curious what the Stack Exchange developers are working on at the moment. What does the team spend most time on?

The question is prompted by my subjective feeling that not a lot of (visible) features are being added to the Stack Exchange sites. I don't recall any significant innovation in the last year. Smaller changes are being made, of course.

On the other hand a few long-standing problems are not being solved, such as the low quality of the duplicate search.

The team surely is working on the documentation feature now. But what did they do during the last year before that work was started?

Does Careers consume a lot of dev time?

Maybe the Stack Exchange software is being considered mostly "done"? (I would agree; there are no severe issues or sorely missing features that I'm aware of.) Or, are there many features being developed that are not easily visible?

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251095/let-s-improve-our-site-navigation) is a possibility.

Comment: [Warlords of Documentation: Your Quest(ions Answered)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306213/456814). Or [WoW](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/). One or the other.

Comment: It seems that they spend most of their time on blogs, podcasts and twitter. Since they find plenty of time for such activities while the house is on fire.

Comment: [In compiling the code](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/compiling.png)

Comment: I suspect they're [doing this](https://alchetron.com/Ascending-and-Descending#demo) all the time.

Answer (score 9):

> not a lot of (visible) features are being added to the Stack Exchange sites

Do you have many suggestions for "Visible" features? Or any in mind? Are there pros / cons to these ideas, are they really needed, is the network broken without?

> On the other hand a few long-standing problems are not being solved, such as the low quality of the duplicate search.

I think you mean the normal search - people say they use the duplicate one as their normal search.

> The team surely is working on the documentation feature now. But what did they do during the last year before that work was started?

I think by that you are suggesting they only started work when they announced it... I'd expect they've been testing, developing etc for a while - they already have some cool mockups.

Back to the visible features, here is a (truncated) list of changes to the network since September 2014.

- 2015-09-07: New user privilege at 25K reputation: Access to Site Analytics
- 2015-04-22: Flag dialog has been reworded for both questions and answers.
- 2015-04-20: Questions deleted as spam/inappropriate now have the body and title hidden.
- 2015-04-15: New profile pages have been launched on most Stack Exchange sites.
- 2015-04-08: Moderators able to manually ban users from suggesting edits.
- 2015-03-23: Criteria for making an entry in post revision history have changed.
- 2015-03-20: All questions flagged Very Low Quality now immediately enter Triage on Stack Overflow.
- 2015-03-09: "That solved my problem! / No, my question is different. I will edit to explain how" banner.
- 2014-12-18: Release of Beta Testing version of Android Tablet App
- 2014-12-10: Status of suggested edits is now displayed in your activity history as either of pending, approved, rejected.
- 2014-12-04: Triage review introduced for testing at Stack Overflow.
- 2014-11-12: Rolling question rate limits are now network-wide
- 2014-10-07: New rejection reason for suggested edits that don't make any positive changes to the post: "no improvements whatsoever".
- 2014-10-01: Intra-word emphasis now works.
- 2014-09-30: The "thanks for your edit" message now includes a link to the suggested edit page.
- 2014-09-16: Stack Snippets introduced on Stack Overflow, Code Review and Meta Stack Exchange).
- 2014-09-11: iOS app refined for iPad is released for alpha testing.
- 2014-09-10: Suggested edit review offers a new button “Improve Edit”.
- 2014-09-19: Changes to user signup and profile editing.
- 2014-09-05: Suggested edit review offers a new button “Reject and Edit”.

Notable is the new user profile page, the new .less designs, the global authentication and the 25k privilege.

See the full list for 2015 [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247647/252153), and 2014 [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214543/252153).

> Maybe the Stack Exchange software is being considered mostly "done"? (I would agree; there are no severe issues or sorely missing features that I'm aware of.) Or, are there many features being developed that are not easily visible?

Possibly both? As you say, there are no glaring holes. Okay, there are things that could be added (and 75,000+ bug reports), but what is going to be better? Spending time on WoD or some small bugs?

Comment: The dupe search is broken, people use the search on the ask question page. That one is *really* good.

Comment: Yeah, my question is not really meant as a critique. I just wonder where all the time goes. The team surely is at least 10 people in size given how many recruiting and welcome posts there were. What are 10 highly qualified devs in a well-functioning company doing all day?! Their productivity must be enormous. The lists do not seem to explain what they are doing most of the time. Those are all minor features.

Comment: @boot4life ahh that search, yes you're right. There are 29 developers, a few on the Android / iOS apps, but mostly web developers. I expect that a few take responsibility for the teams of devs (i.e. more managing than developing), but yes they must do a lot. Since the 7th of September (~3 weeks) they've fixed 50 bugs and feature requests, which is pretty good imo. And I gather that WoD has taken a lot of time.

Comment: [Login](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/upcoming-login-changes-stage-2-and-the-new-ui-now-live) is also somewhere in there. :) (Edit: oh wait, you did mention global authentication, I should've kept reading past the dates.)

Comment: @AnnaLear That date didn't seem to be in the Meta SE post - when was global auth added, and I'll update it?