# I'm resigning as a Stack Overflow community elected moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderator-resignation

I'm resigning as a Stack Overflow moderator.

Thank you to everyone who has worked hard to make this Q&A site what it is.

I'm resigning for three reasons:

1. Stack Overflow Inc. has forgotten how to lead, how to persuade, and how to talk with the community. This has been a slow decline since 2014 and we are now at the point where the company's actions show they no longer want to build a relationship with the community they have.

   All criticisms of company actions have been lumped together as "this is just meta, they're malcontents, and we don't need to listen to them." They do not partake in the activities that are needed to build and grow a community.  They overwork their Community Managers and force them to act as intercessors without giving them the authority to help build the community.

   In short, the people who have spent the better part of a decade working with the community are now sidelined from interacting with the community absent explicit permission from the powers that be.
2. Since the current people in charge also make the decisions regarding the moderator review/removal process, I am not confident that moderators are seen as partners in community building, but rather volunteers to be tightly controlled.  The proposed Moderator Review process lacks due process, codifies the decision making in the hands of the same people who have created the mess we're now experiencing, and treats oversight of the process in a token fashion. They may as well have retained their previous statement that "community moderators can be removed at any time, for any reason", because that's what the proposed process codifies, with the illusion of impartiality. The only actions I have to go on are how Monica was removed as moderator, and until I see actual evidence that Stack Overflow understands how to administer due process and a fair resolution process, I can't trust that Stack Overflow will follow any process it sets down and that the process will be fair and equitable.
3. I have lost trust in Stack Overflow executives.  This is a highly volatile time that requires more attention than is visibly given.  The people of the community need to feel heard, and their criticisms addressed.  We are receiving none of that, and their response times are measured in days and weeks, not hours.

I fully support and agree with the Code of Conduct change to explicitly welcome members of under-served backgrounds, and I will continue to work to ensure people new to Stack Overflow feel cared for and feel like they can be a part of this great community we have built.

Thank you for allowing me to serve you.

Comment: Oh my gods. Please be well. Thank you for the countless reasonable actions you have taken over the years. Thank you so much for all you've done.

Comment: Pffff. I fully support your decision. But I hate it.

Comment: You are one of the best. Thanks, and I do  hope ALL mods follow **your** lead now, and will force SE to change their bad course, or be shut down. There's no way SE staff can moderate Stack Overflow by themselves.

Comment: Upvoting not because this is good, or because I have unconditionally supported your stance on matters, but because this post deserves to be seen, for good or ill.

Comment: This is the second biggest shock, after Monica's demodding. Maybe, this is the  one signal that will finally shake up the management. An absolutely unexpected decision, but absolutely supported. Be well.

Comment: I haven't always agreed with your style, but I have valued your commitment to the site and your stance on all this.  It's a shame it has come to this, you'll be missed.

Comment: This post instantly hit TL. We will all miss you.

Comment: I won't upvote this, because it is a monumental irrepairable loss for the network, but I thank you for your courage, the work you have done, and wish you all the best.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Don’t hold your breath. Sara Chipps pulled a classic Sara Chipps on Twitter, when reacting to George’s thread on why moderators felt like they were simply being used as unpaid labor.

Comment: Is there any public information on the moderator removal/reinstatement process? If not, will there be in the future, or is it restricted to moderators only?

Comment: I thank you for sharing your analysis and the patience you've shown with me and others as well as your stamina to keep doing, coaching and explaining the things you felt were right. I will miss your point of view "from the inside out" and try to remember that if/when I and this community move forward.

Comment: Thanks for everything. Your resignation letter is pretty much exactly how I feel, and of course, I've come to the same conclusions as you. Thanks also for your integrity.

Comment: Thank you for all your work and the time that you have given. We normal users know that mods give so much and it doesn't always seem as if we appreciate this fully. What made you absolutely special in the last months and weeks was that you were always in the middle of everything, where it's dirtiest and loudest, getting it from all sides. I actually don't know how to show how big my respect is for this. Just: thanks and be well.

Comment: We've locked horns a few times, most of them recently, and even here I can't wholly agree with you - like many of the community, I *don't* agree with the Code of Conduct change, and think the problems go beyond how it was delivered. But you were a well-meaning mod and good human being, who took on the thankless and demanding job of modship and did his best to perform it honourably. Thank you for your service to us. Be well.

Comment: @DanBron Could you expand what you mean by "Sara Chipps pulled a classic Sara Chipps"? I don't use twitter.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Sara is known for her non-response responses, her non-apology apologies. Etc.

Comment: If even you lost trust in SE, I wonder how they will get over those times...

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I'm guessing [this one](https://twitter.com/SaraJChipps/status/1180842385284239361)

Comment: @OrangeDog - Those are such vacuous responses I can't even...

Comment: George, I feel it has been said countless times, but I wanna say it too. Even if I didn't always see eye to eye with your actions, your integrity is without question. I'm less optimistic about SO's future today than I was yesterday, but I wish you all the best. And most importantly, peace of mind.

Comment: I agree Sara has said some things that are rightly criticized harshly but my goodness, folks. It is neither fair nor necessary nor productive to comment on *every damn utterance* she has ever made somewhere with the biggest possible assumption of bad faith. When you have people criticizing "I learn from coworkers X and Y every day" you know something's gone over the top. Yes maybe it's a platitude; so f-ing what? People at SO and elsewhere shower each other with these every day. It's part of modern culture in some industries and circles and at worst, really really harmless.

Comment: Has the [new CEO](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/24/announcing-stack-overflows-new-ceo-prashanth-chandrasekar/), who has already been in place for two weeks, said anything publicly about the very valid points you and other mods have raised?

Comment: @Pekka웃 you have to understand the nature of the medium. If there are enough people there will always be someone picking up the negative slant and perhaps posting a comment. But mostly it's not the same people every time.

Comment: @Sklivvz that's the dynamic, yeah. And it can make a place look a LOT more hostile than it is (see also: Stack Overflow main, Youtube comments, etc). Unfortunately. Wouldn't be surprised if a lot of misconceptions about Meta at SE, Inc. didn't spring from that

Comment: Best of luck in all your future endeavors, George. I hope SO's leadership will see this as a wake-up call, as well.

Comment: Thanks for your dedicated efforts. Hope people wake up soon. All the best.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I suspect OrangeDog means to point to the *"I'm sad people don't feel heard"* Tweet, and I think he's fair enough in doing so. The point isn't that the Tweet is objectionable in isolation, it's that the expression of goodwill in transparently insincere. She voices the platitude that she wants George to feel heard, but then declines to engage substantively with *anything* in the multiple paragraphs that he wrote; there isn't even a perfunctory effort to live up to the platitude. It's insulting in the same way as being told *"Your call is very important to us"* after an hour on hold.

Comment: @Mark that's a fair point.

Comment: You sir are a legend and I'm just sad to see you go!

Comment: @MarkAmery to the whole conversation, yes, but Twitter forces you to pick a single tweet. And I'm only assuming that's what DanBron was referring to.

Comment: Yes, George, Thank you so much for all you've done. Your answers in .net have helped me a lot :), we will miss you.

Comment: I'm sorry to see you go George. I wish I'd shown more appreciation for you. Oh and I downvoted this, as I downvoted Robert and Ed's resignations. :-[

Comment: George, you were an incredibly good, generous moderator, and oftentimes a voice of positivity and compromise when that's just what was needed. Thanks for everything you did. You'll be missed.

Comment: You are without a doubt one of the most level headed and consistent moderators this site has had.

Comment: BTW - when does your resignation 'take effect'? I assumed it was immediate, but then I saw you used your moderator-only ability on this post to edit the featured tag ~15 minutes later: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390301/would-a-note-about-preferred-pronouns-qualify-the-same-way-as-a-thank-you

Comment: @tylerh whenever the CM team is able to process it. I wish we could shut it off ourselves, but we can’t.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Oh, I totally get you can't *actually* de-mod yourselves. I was asking more of a 'when do you consider yourself to have officially stepped down', which your comment answers, I guess (when they de-mod you). It seemed a little odd before, assuming you considered yourself to have stepped down at the time of posting this, and then for you to have carried out a moderator action after that happened. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @YvetteColomb: seems the general consensus is to upvote mod resignation announcements to show support for the person and their stance (not the circumstances which led to the resignation, obviously). Anyway I also regret this one.

Comment: @smci I know, but it feels like I'm saying I'm happy that they're going and it's opposite, so downvote, which is kinda a compliment. It means I want them to stay - which means I think they did good - which means - following your logic - they deserve an upvote.. meh still sad. :\

Comment: @YvetteColomb: I know, I know, I know, it feels wrong to upvote... we don't have emotional reaction buttons on SO (thank goodness).

Comment: *"This has been a slow decline since 2014"*⁠—nice to see someone else feel the same way. Aside from myself, I've rarely seen anyone else pinpoint the beginning of the decline to around ~2014.

Comment: While we have crossed paths only briefly, during these interesting times we live in, I have quickly grown to admire the way you, standing firm amidst the confusion, used your mandate to show us vantage points which, though not always comfortable, are ultimately fruitful. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for being there mate, mad respect and all the best!

Comment: "It's better to be a lion for day than a sheep all your life."
Brave Decision

Comment: *＋1* for taking a stand and adhering to your principals. Hat tip to you.

Comment: That's a sad part if Someone of this calibre is feeling like this and took this extreme step of quitting, Hope SE Execs inner consciousness gets a hit.

Comment: After re-reading the reasons for the departure again, I fully understand the frustration about the communication style of SO, because I share it, but I think that expecting SO to give up full control over moderator removals is somewhat naive. How realistic was this ever? The proposed process is probably just some kind of red tape and the only interesting thing would be if you get a right for a detailed explanation of a dismissal. But apart from that, how could that have ever lead to anything else? Basically I wonder what George's vision of it was.

Comment: @Mehrdad "I've rarely seen anyone else pinpoint the beginning of the decline to around ~2014" No need for that. Just look at the statistics of questions, answers, scores, ... they all peaked in 2014Q1. 2014 was the end of the growth phase. 2014 to 2016 was kind of a plateau, since 2017 it's downhill. Obviously people would pinpoint the start of the end at the end of the start (2014Q1). :)

Comment: And now with this I realize I misunderstood you on many occasions. It seems you were doing your duty scrupulously to the rules, and most of the times avoided to state your inner feelings.. Good luck for all future stuff, things come and go, and hard times finally come to an end

Comment: @Trilarion I've been leaving (and will leave more feedback) privately before discussing it publicly; but after it's published publicly I'd be happy to go further into depth if my concerns still remain.  Bottom line is that the process looks like it's been reverse engineered to achieve the outcome desired (removal) instead of a fact-finding process  designed to ensure there's justice.

Comment: Calling the new CoC 'liberal' is a laugh. It is the opposite!! It is a 'holier than though' point of view and strictly digusting. And it is doing so much more damage to the lavendel community than any misplaced (or ill-received) pronouns ever could have done.

Comment: To break up all these comments discussing the CoC... George, you've been a great moderator. We've had some disagreements, but one thing I really admire is when you're sure of something, your conviction to do it even when people criticize you for it is very strong. You've never been afraid to take action, even when that action goes against the perceived majority. Good luck in your future endeavors!

Comment: If you feel like taking a political stand for some reason here, then don't hide it behind a comment which can't be downvoted. Do it in an answer (which is surely inappropriate to this question anyway). It is easier for the community to delete those. Post a question if you wish to have a separate discussion.

Comment: I can't say much about the points OP raised but the way Monica was removed - that was certainly not handled well and I am quite shocked by the miscommunication and insensitive handling of this. Even if Monica had been out of line (and I am confident that this was not the case) there would have been better ways to handle this.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker "the process looks like it's been reverse engineered to achieve the outcome desired (removal) instead of a fact-finding process designed to ensure there's justice." From an outsider's perspective, it seems like SE folks operate in an echo chamber that doesn't tolerate different views, and as such they're not interested in actual justice but rather in eliminating opposing views. That's one way to reduce push-back, but not an intellectually or morally satisfying one.

Comment: Thank you for your service! From what I've seen, you have been a good moderator, and your reasoning is absolutely sound.

Comment: It's really sad to see you go. There have been a lot of moderators who resigned but never expected you to do the same.

Comment: George, just a heads up, you're getting quoted in [a dice article](https://insights.dice.com/2019/10/17/stack-overflow-moderators-toxic-culture/?amp).

Comment: @davym thanks for the heads up. I owe you one.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker take care. The site feels insanely different from the site I took a break from. I hope you and your family are well

Comment: @JonClements I already miss you, now I just miss you more.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker you have helped me lot in my tough days..i would like to wish you best success for your future endevour...really sad to see you going..You are great person and actually told what you have in your heart and it seems Stack Exchange Inc really needs to take this serious and dont know what Stack Exchange Inc do to change your mind..

Comment: George, I hadn't commented yet because I don't know what to say. I wish I could point to someone at SE and say, "That person will make things better." But I can't. I'm not sure any one person at SE can make that kind of difference anymore.

Comment: I'm sorry to see you go, George. It was a pleasure working with you.

Comment: As a non-moderating, non-Communitybuilding „rank and file“ member I thank you for your work and your last deed as a moderator, explaining the situation in clear, precise words. Since „lex Monica“, it was nebulous to me what the root cause was. Now it is clear to me. TYVM! What really scares me about this situation is that people who put a **lot** of passion into the community feel forced to resign as either as a form of protest (kudos for the personal integrity!) or - even scarier - because they perceive any further debate as most likely futile. Hm, a **lot** of us are programmers....

Comment: thats a 1515 upvote and 115 favorites for you sir, I agree, SO needs to fix some things, this community really has died out in the social-moderation sense. I still havent had my question bans removed after a serial downvoting

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390493/what-could-stack-exchange-inc-do-to-make-moderators-whove-recently-resigned-wan/390495#390495

Comment: _They do not partake in the activities that are needed to build and grow a community. They overwork their Community Managers and force them to act as intercessors without giving them the authority to help build the community_

Can you be more specific about this? Like what issue?

Comment: Another legend is gone! All best for your future endeavors!

Comment: _Stack Overflow Inc. has forgotten how to lead, how to persuade, and how to talk with the community. This has been a slow decline since 2014 and we are now at the point where the company's actions show they no longer want to build a relationship with the community they have._

When moderators try to ridicule users for asking sometimes basic or specific questions - then the user leaves. Without an active, evolving, and loyal user base there can be no effective/profitable service, and no _community_.

Comment: Dilbert seems to now understand what is going on, see https://dilbert.com/strip/2019-10-31?utm_source=tw&utm_medium=organic-dilbert&utm_campaign=daily-engagement&utm_content=dilbert

Comment: Congrats on 2K!

Answer (score 465):

George, I've known you for as long as you've been a part of this site. You were an example to me and many others as we fumbled around trying to figure out how to make this work - your posts, your comments on the blog before meta existed, and most of all your behavior as you interacted with others *set the bar* that the rest of us strove to reach.

If a moderator's primary duty is to be [an ambassador of trust](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/) then you have fulfilled that duty, consistently, for far longer than you've actually been a moderator - and I've no doubt that you will continue to do so.

So thank you for that; thank you for making the site better not just in what you've done but in how you've done it.

It saddens me to see you stepping down in these circumstances, but I'm happy to have been able to work closely with you for the time that we have had.

Comment: You (pl) shouldn't be letting him go. He is the one moderator that never pandered to the masses.

Comment: Do something to stop the haemorrhaging!

Comment: Exactly what @Mari-LouA said. He was never afraid to say what was unpopular but correct, and was always a supporter of SE, looking at things from your perspective. The fact that he's leaving now means SE has no advocate here.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm 100% sure that if Shog was in a position to stop George from quitting (i.e. senior role in SE management), this whole recent crisis would have never happened in the first place. The main reason it sparked, the way I see it, is total lack of commutation and total lack of understanding how Stack Exchange communities work. Shog is not lacking any of those.

Comment: @Shadow Shog9 is a member of staff, a respected and paid employee. His voice is louder than mine or yours or both of ours put together.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Shog also has bosses with the power to decide things and the ability not to listen to anything he says. It's not fair to lay this at his feet.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I like to think of it this way: With the decade of public footprint Shog, Tim Post, et. al., have; if they could reach out and improve things, they would have done so. We know this because we can go through their history and see past examples of how they've done so. Something happened that we're not privy to that caused them to stop being able to help make things better. It's evident from their public answers and the shift and tenor of Stack Overflow Inc., in general.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker so true. I admire both (Shog and Tim) for trying their best even with hands tied.

Comment: Tim & Shog, and the CM team are generally awesome - that much isn't disputable.  It sucks that they have to deal with this.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker you are spot on

Comment: Shog, I owe you another beer when we meet next. You are a gentleman.

Comment: Shog, btw, bug report: your badge counts wrap in your user card

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Shog, with his usual eloquence, perfectly sums up my feelings - thank you for all you have done for this community and I am saddened to see you go.

Comment: Once associated the installation of their new CEO with the revolt ... and had the comment deleted within a few seconds (and this might tell an awful lot). Sad to see many good moderators go, simply because I don't want to end up with a Facebook for programmers, where only ad revenue counts, but not the people generating it.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker It was always a pleasure to interact with you - first as a user, then as a mod along side with you, later as a CM. You've always been level-headed during tough times and that is going to be sorely missed. I'm incredibly sad to see you go.

Comment: @Taryn it's beyond puzzling to me that all you have to say is "it's sad... bla bla bla", don't you think your company owes us some answers, it's over 2 weeks in this (completely unnecessary) saga and the company remained almost completely silent. If it's not under your responsibility, you should go to whom it is, and demand he addresses people painful concerns. We have put a lot of effort in this site *for free*, you (the company) at least owe us some answers in timely manner. (Not attacking you personally, but very much pissed with your company to be honest)

Comment: @gdoron If Tim and Shog aren't able to speak up to allay concerns (and they're community managers, and Tim was previously the director of community -- unclear what his role is now), then you can guarantee that no matter how Taryn or any other employee feels, they're not going to speak up. I don't know how they feel, or whether they support the methods used by SO Inc, but what I do know is it's impossible that 100% of all the employees agree with how these changes have been conducted. The ones that don't agree aren't speaking up because they don't feel it's safe to.

Comment: Interesting observation. There is a thing in SO, as intentional non-answers. Especially when you deal with newbs. Formally, they belong to comments but being very short and lacking most formatting comments suit for dense laconic talk with experienced developers who take any hint. Newbs can not grasp what you mean until you literally take them by hand and show them WHAT u mean. This kind of pseudo-answers recently became deleted on formal grounds in few hours. Obviously new fresh rules or meat was brought in to moderate. Well, means i will mostly disengage from talking with newbs now.

Comment: Formal rules will be enforced with much better rates, newbs will be left with laconic hints instead of explanations. New moderators would show stats they do geeat job.

Comment: Tim & Shog9 are among the few ones chatting with us in the moderator chatroom (along with Catija, Megan, and maybe some others I forgot). They've always followed mods closely and supported/helped them.

Comment: I haven't had the pleasure of knowing George for anywhere near as long as Shog or many other folks chiming in here, but I still want to wholeheartedly echo the sentiments shared. In less than a year, I've learned so much from George. Thank you. <3

Comment: Unrelated: in case you ever leave your current company, please consider writing a book about that job, this crises and whatnot. I would for sure buy it :-)

Comment: Book? Ha! I have it on good authority that programmers have [stopped reading books](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2008/04/16/stackoverflowcom/), @ghostcat - it'll be a long, confusing mess of Instagram posts or whatever the kids are reading by then.

Comment: @Shog9 *liked & subscribed*

Comment: Just compile all of his Meta posts into a book, @GhostCat, and maybe add a gloss. It worked for [Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=28793).

Comment: @shog9 Now I have an identity crisis. I read books (and yes also programming books) and until now I thought I was a programmer. But I can't be because I read books. So what the heck am I? Help me Shogi Wan Kenobi, you're my only hope...

Comment: Sad decision and good luck for your next journey :)

Comment: No longer a community manager. The haemorrhage continues...  this is a sad day for me, far far sadder than when Monica Cellio was demodded at the time I was incredulous and shocked. Today, I feel sadness,  your words and posts have nearly always  struck a chord in me, you managed to touched my soul. Just wanted you to know.

Answer (score 156):

We have not always seen eye to eye on issues here, but I have always respected your integrity, your unflinching and unwavering fairness and your absolute willingness to explain yourself and your decisions, and to be a leader in both word and thought for this community.

You embody all the qualities I expect a good moderator to have, and it has been a pleasure being active on a site that had you on it.

All the best.

Comment: I second this all. George was one of our finest moderators IMO and with so many of them gone now - for good reason -, and so few left (for how long?), I really feel quite discouraged to participate in the site anymore.

Answer (score 132):

I don't remember any specific disagreements I've had with you, but whenever I see your avatar I have this lingering sense of slight annoyance you have about someone with a different point of view that you've had to grudgingly come to agree with more than once.

It's sad to see you go - but it seems like the only correct decision at this point.

Thank you for your work and all the best.

Comment: *"...whenever I see your avatar I have this lingering sense of slight annoyance you have about someone with a different point of view that you've had to grudgingly come to agree with more than once."* That is the perfect phrasing. Thank you for putting into words precisely how I feel about George. He and I have not always agreed about the details, but we've long been in agreement about the big picture and our mission here. It is a loss that we will surely feel, and I fear it is only the beginning of the bleeding.

Comment: @CodyGray: His phrasing was definitely impekkable

Answer (score 128):

I did *not* see this coming.

George, I know the last few weeks have been rough, and we haven't always agreed, but you always seemed to have a way of dealing with what's thrown at you and turning it into something constructive.

Take it easy.

Comment: [this probably could shed some light](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334263/165773) (current bounty in there is expected to get to this answer)

Comment: @gnat Also [buried](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390301/would-a-note-about-preferred-pronouns-qualify-the-same-way-as-a-thank-you#comment734260_390306) in the comments.

Answer (score 113):

George: absolute thanks for running the show for years.

Stack Exchange Inc.: "thanks" for ruining the show, probably forever!

Comment: Especially in the light of the new "thanks" button: A **_horrible_** change to Stack Exchange Inc., and proves that they are just **_ruining_** this site.

Answer (score 110):

George, this is one of those resignations that came out of left field for me.  I wanted to respond to this earlier when I read it, but I realized I couldn't get out what I wanted to on a phone so I had to wait until I was at a keyboard.

---

I'll be honest.  There weren't times when I thought we saw eye-to-eye.  Of the moderators here, I felt like you were the closest to the company (read: furthest from the community) on how you approached things on a day-to-day basis. That's not to say I didn't at least appreciate what you did; it just led to more friction from me.  This was especially painful when you had a bit of a clunky "return" to Meta, and it was just...I mean, you were at least *trying*.

Your resignation came up as a big surprise since I wouldn't have bet that you'd go anywhere, especially since it seemed like you "got" why Stack Overflow was doing this.  I suppose I really don't know what goes on behind closed doors, and I can at least accept that I understood nothing.

It seems like your patience has finally run out, so at this point, I thank you for what you've done for the community.

Comment: This is exactly how I feel put into words.

Answer (score 86):

You already know this, but you're one of the people on Stack Overflow I've always looked up to. I remember the early days of Meta when I'd see a new question, notice you'd left an answer, and know that I wouldn't need to write anything more. Your actions helped shape opinions and processes in ways that impact the site every day.

It's fun going back and [reading the comments under your nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/3#post-10890701), because I felt sure members of the site wouldn't appreciate the hard work you did. The thankless cleanup work you did over the years started long before you were a moderator. I was shocked when both of us somehow made it through that election, and you've done an enormous amount of work since that time to make this site better.

One small silver lining to all this is looking around this post and seeing people recognize the positive impact you've had.

You exemplified the philosophy that moderators are elected because the community trusts our judgment, and we should rely on that judgment to determine how best to help and protect the people here and the site we all use. I could always count on you to defend the members and content of this site. You always made it clear why you thought an action was in the best interests of everyone, even when others disagreed.

You've done that once again. I'm really sad to read this, but I completely understand why you felt it was necessary. You should be proud of how many people your volunteer work helped over all these years. I'll really miss having you around.

Answer (score 46):

Oh no....

Sorry to see you go, I cannot believe we have lost yet another great moderator.  You have been one of the most respected Moderators here.

Best wishes, and keep an eye on us...

Answer (score 46):

I just learned the bad news and I'm not enjoying it to say the least.

During the short time we served together, I've seen you working and I always admired the kindness & fairness you were handling the flags with (even if you sometimes deleted my moderator comments that were flagged as "rude or abusive" hey I was doing my job :)).

I also enjoyed the quality of your meta posts, and of course our interactions in the moderator chatroom. I just can't believe that so many worthy people are leaving... You'll be missed as a mod.

Comment: You can now undelete those comments without it being awkward.  Although I will say that my default stance is to delete comments and I often would basically click the delete button as quickly as possible. it kinda irked me that moderator comments get flagged by that autobot, but anyway. Thank you for your kind words.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I fully understand what you've done and why and you already explained that to me in the chatroom. It's not a problem as long as I'm not suspended for doing my work ;) I just wanted to add a little fun to this sad news.

Answer (score 36):

I'd like to roughly echo Pekka's sentiments in his [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390439/419):

> I don't remember any specific disagreements I've had with you, but whenever I see your avatar I have this lingering sense of slight annoyance you have about someone with a different point of view that you've had to grudgingly come to agree with more than once.

We have knocked heads a few times back in SO's formative days but I honestly can't remember specifically what these disagreements were about. They don't matter now.

I've learned many things about dealing with new people whilst building a community and you were definitely part of that learning process...in a good way I grudgingly admit :) I did in truth sometimes think you were a wee bit of a "company man" but today you've proved me wrong.

Anyway, I'm having a wee glass of Chilean red and I'm raising a glass to you and the efforts you've put into the SO community over the past 10+ years. Here's to you.

Comment: The bit on raising a glass had me literally with a tear in the eye now. Guess I'm joining. Here's too great mods and contributors pushed away by... _by what? I can't even define._

Answer (score 33):

What!? No, not you too...

I several times suggested to you to take a break from moderation, and once you replied with this:

> @jl2210 I’d resign before shirking my duty.

I didn't expect you to go through with this, but, well, I guess I was wrong.

We didn't always agree with you, but that doesn't mean we won't miss your support.

See you around.

---

Is this my fault? I saw this discussion (that I most likely caused) under your answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390301/would-a-note-about-preferred-pronouns-qualify-the-same-way-as-a-thank-you/390306#390306):

> @GeorgeStocker I'd advise you to turn a blind eye to this until the company figures out what they want. Just do your usual duties and walk away from this controversy. – JL2210
>
> @jl2210 I’d resign before shirking my duty. – George Stocker ♦
>
> @GeorgeStocker I think it's time for you to decide whether your duty is to the company or to the community. – mason
>
> @mason I am doing all I can for my part to ensure those are aligned. Ultimately I made an agreement with SO inc to moderate SO and its meta according to their policies. At the moment I do not feel in good faith I can do that, I will resign. – George Stocker ♦

I hope not.

Comment: Not at all, JL2210. I made the decision on the spot this morning after spending a long weekend away. It had been building. There were glimmers of hope, but the people tasked with designing the policies have not shown that they are aware how destructive their methods are to the community. Their responses (when there is a response) lack any understanding or listening required to ensure the relationship between the community and company is fruitful and productive. There’s only so long any one person can fight for change before they recognize it is futile.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker You've been a bright light around here for quite awhile, and a staunch defender of "let's hear the facts first" throughout this whole mess over the past month (?). Several of your comments in this thread illuminate that you aren't the SE sock-puppet some would cast you as but a deeply thoughtful, committed person. I've watched the mess on MSE and your calming presence in it and "thought, if George goes, no one is left to calm the waters". I hope SE realizes that.

Comment: I am so sad watching SO inc set fire to its creation (and those who did the work paying the price). The software development world would not be where it is today without SO.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Woa. "Their responses (when there is a response) lack any understanding or listening required to ensure the relationship between the community and company is fruitful and productive." This... does not bode well at all.

Answer (score 30):

I know we did not agree with the new moderation policies on Meta, and that this may have made it seem like I had a problem with you specifically.

But I want to say I did see you as a good moderator for Main and found the conversation we had on Meta to be far more civil and productive than those I've had with Staff (which I appreciate). As, I think we agreed with the ultimate goal even if we disagree on the policy to get there.

So good luck and thanks for the hard work.

Answer (score 20):

George, thank you for your contributions to Stack Overflow.

What I'd like to know is...

### What could Stack Exchange Inc do to change your mind?

Clearly you don't expect the company is capable or willing to change, else you'd not be resigning.  You've done a fine job of articulating your reasons for leaving.  Yet, I'd like to suggest that you leave a final, *concrete set of specific actions* that, if taken by management, would lead you to want to continue your great work here.

I've [posted a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390493/290085) so that you (and perhaps others) might answer this question there.

Thank you.

Answer (score 19):

I don't know what Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky think of the path their creation is being dragged down, but I hope the new CEO and management team don't screw up what has become an indispensable web resource for developers and lots of other communities.

Stack Exchange is a gem.  Don't mess it up.

Comment: I put responded to Joels tweet where he announces the new CEO, linking to this very question here, and suggesting that a perfect time to come back and save his company ... would be now. Not surprisingly: no reaction. At all.

Answer (score 19):

That should be an eye-opening thing for management. If a person, who has given years to this community as a representative of Stack Overflow, got discouraged and stepping down with a heavy heart then this should be a point of concern for management.

We, as community, really thank you George for your services and stand with you.

Answer (score 18):

After the [An apology to our community, and next steps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334551/an-apology-to-our-community-and-next-steps)
 post, I thought that the tide was changing after a long time.

The resignation of such a **Colossal** moderator alerted me, and I'd like to let you know that your action strong signals towards me (just another "avg" user).

And remember:

> **In the end, all that matters is what you've done.**

And I, IMHO, strongly believe that when you go to sleep in the night and sometimes think of all the awesome things you have done for the community, then you'd feel proud, to say the least.

---

<sub>Phrase from Mega Alexander movie</sub>

Answer (score 12):

As I mentioned in a comment, in my view you were one of the finest mods on this site.

For years - since discovering this thing called Meta - I have silently appreciated how well you justify your actions, with clear, solid reasoning.

This post is no different.

I'm saddened - as I was after reading each and every other moderator resignation notice. Actually, more sad, since after reading the [update from the CTO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334551/251162) I had some expectation that things were indeed going to end up being alright.

*(Meanwhile, [the resignation notice(s) I was hoping for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334436/251162) have not surfaced and I don't think they ever will at this point.)*

Thank you and good luck moving forward.

Answer (score 11):

This is really sad. Of course, there are times when I have openly disagreed with George but this does not invalidate his first reason for tendering a resignation. George is right!

If there's one thing that is obvious in this community, it is the fact that the company has a masked disregard for the meta-community and her representatives. I hate to be too direct but if the truth is not represented this way, who are we kidding? We are going to have this same discussion over and over again.

On a side note, when Prashanth Chandrasekar became CEO, I highlighted this:

[image]

This isn't healthy. If things continue this way, the dream (as described by the last CEO) might not be attained, or at best, not be attained anytime soon. Something needs to be done.

Answer (score 9):

Sorry to see you go, George! I remember in particular [your stance against deleting good content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286970/1269037):

> We do not delete good content. We do not delete good content.

Also sorry to be asking this, but I've been out of the loop with the recent events, and only see general references to them in this thread. Can someone point/link to some of the examples that have driven resignations? Thank you.

Comment: The Meta SE post at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper and the links within it is a good place to start.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know George. But I want to be a part of this (seems something important). Stack Overflow is important to me. It helped me with a lot of my coding problems and more importantly I am happy to have helped others in their problems.

Hearing the site's problems from someone inside is always never good. I hope the top management take heed of the points outlined and improve.

Answer (score 7):

George, you are one of our finest moderators here. After hearing the news of your resignation, I really feel quite discouraged to participate on the site any more.

Answer (score 6):

George who? JK. Seriously, may the wind be at your back...

Answer (score -100):

I'm really sorry to see you go. It's difficult for me to envision the office without you.

I'm also sorry that you feel the way you do about the proposed procedures. They're still open for feedback, we've got the condensed text versions to clear up some ambiguities in the charts ready to go out *today*, and more feedback is being incorporated to add clarity.

There will ***always*** have to be a system where we, in an emergency, can pull a lever to remove a moderator's access immediately. If they violate their moderator agreement, get into public "brawls" with other moderators, have their accounts compromised or a running script go haywire - we have to revoke access immediately. Our privacy policy mandates it.

But, the new policy automatically kicks in the discovery phase where 2 CMs are assigned to look into everything going on and render a decision. There's a phase where we, if we have *very* confidential information that was communicated in trust by a user to senior management (and this has happened, where someone wasn't comfortable with the CMs knowing their sexual orientation, gender, religion, or other personal things) can step in and halt the process, or require a precondition to be met prior to reinstatement, but it would *always* be communicated to the mod, and would be extremely rare. There are some former moderators that just can not, under ***any*** circumstances receive access again. We can't build a policy for the next 10 years in a vacuum.

I hate how everything happened too. I've been literally sick about it for the last few weeks, ***but it is also a very rare anomaly*** when it comes to moderation here. It is *very* rare that a moderator is asked to step down for reasons other than vanishing.

I wish you luck in everything you do and we really need to make time to get that burger and beer - but I didn't want you leaving thinking we were done with things, and I need to get our side of why things are written the way they are out there.

Thanks for your service George. We're going to miss you.

Comment: "There will ***always*** have to be a system where we, in an emergency, can pull a lever to remove a moderator's access immediately." Has there been such an emergency in the last couple of weeks?

Comment: I hope management at the company treats this as the loud wake up call that it is.

Comment: You have always been a beacon of kindness and understanding in the community, and I thank you for publicly reaching out even though it hurts to do so.  I would love to talk more about my concerns about the proposed process offline, but honestly if we're able to get that burger and beer I'd rather just listen to your life story and learn more about you.  I've respected you for as long as I've known you, and you continue to be one of the bright spots of being a member of this community.

Comment: "There are some former moderators that just can not, under ***any*** circumstances receive access again." Does this include Monica Cellio?

Comment: "asked to step down" in a paragraph directly relating to the last few weeks. Please mind your words there.

Comment: @JeanneDark If a moderator was found leaking your personal information, what would you want us to do, in accordance with our moderator agreement and privacy policy? What about if they doxxed an employee and made credible threats? Or another user?

Comment: @TimPost I would in that case expect SE to substantiate at least exactly what that moderator did and why they can not be reinstated. Including evidence, redacted where need be.

Comment: @Magisch And that is _exactly_ what the new procedures are going to require. In every single case.

Comment: @TimPost: I think we can all _understand_ a emergency clause like that, but the problem here is that in recent events that clause _appears_ to have been used to get rid of Monica while that wasn't warranted (to the public eye). The core problem here being a lack of communication from higher up the chain, a lack of clarification, and a lack of promised action. That results in broken trust... When there's no trust, focus on an emergency clause like that seems misplaced...

Comment: @Cerbrus George focused on it, so I (as someone directly involved in creating that policy) wanted to add color from my side of it, and note that it's still *in draft stages*.

Comment: @TimPost then it seems like you have a credibility problem that runs deeper then what a policy and going forward can resolve, and seems like it'll require a lot of reflection. If George quits, you know you have lost the trust of most of your userbase, perhaps without recourse. Best of luck.

Comment: Magisch and Cerbrus put it quite well, but just to repeat it: I'm not talking about what to do in hypothetical cases, but whether there was an actual case or not.

Comment: @TimPost: Imo, SE should focus on fixing the situation with Monica, first. A set of rules and procedures can wait. (I don't blame you, by the way, you're also just a messenger in this...)

Comment: I also want to make it clear that I don't blame you. Top brass has put you into an untenable position that I don't envy, and most of us harbor no ill towards you or the rest of the community team.

Comment: Tim, I say this with all the good will I have. The problem SE is for some reason not seeing is that the last... year and an half now? have basically been a chain of "very rare anomaly" events to use your words. And while I get you folk are tired and hurt.. so we are.

Comment: @TimPost Thanks for taking the time to engage and share some (albeit limited) information about what the staff are thinking. If more had done the same, I'm sure we wouldn't be in this mess.

Comment: A process for emergency removal, while of course necessary, is unrelated to recent events.  (I don't blame you personally either; SE upper management is pulling the strings here.  But I am profoundly disappointed in their hurtful, damaging, unjust actions against me.  Companies don't have to follow anything like due process and are allowed to act capriciously (though libel is still a problem).  I'm just disappointed that SE is going that route.)

Comment: I support that Monica was removed -- I understand the reasons behind it and with the evidence I saw it made sense.  However, and this is the crux of my issue: The manner in which Monica was removed (not adhering to existing process; not following any semblance of due process; not clearly articulating the problematic behavior and the consequences of the problematic behavior; not being very clear about the next steps to all, and publicly saying thing that shouldn't have been said) forms the basis for me being quite concerned about any proposed process. SO Inc hasn't fixed existing issues.

Comment: Though I appreciate you responding and trying, I had to downvote this because of the use of **rarely**. The firing may have been a "rare" event but I have posts on Main Meta & here spanning a year that point to the same problems we are still having - **the communication problems are not rare anymore they're the norm**

Comment: I understand your concerns Tim, but unless the monumental mistake of dismissing Monica merely because she disagrees with SE is corrected, you have to understand that *moderators do not trust you*. Your answer is myopic because it only addresses extreme cases (we know whom), but does not address the elephant in the room: abuse by Stack Exchange towards volunteer mods.

Comment: I am just witnessing the events from the past weeks from the sideline. Granted, there have been many major problems with SO lately. Yet I am somewhat annoyed with the use of "_a very rare anomaly_" and "_...It is very rare that a moderator is asked to step down for reasons other than vanishing..._" because it gives me a feeling that you are in a sorta "[ivory tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivory_tower)" ...

Comment: The "system" is currently broken. Badly. And it doesn't appear that the people in charge see it as such.

Comment: I've upvoted this because I appreciate a staff member coming in and communicating like this.  Although the content in this answer bugs me in the sense that it implies untrue, or unsubstantiated, things about Monica's situation (the examples given for immediately revoking access clearly don't apply, and she was not "*asked to step down*").

Comment: @JoshDarnell - I'd have been a lot more impressed if it were David Fullerton, Sara Chipps or Prashanth Chandrasekar responding here. Glad as I am that Tim responded, unfortunately it doesn't mean much in the current climate.

Comment: @JoshDarnell those examples are for older cases. I know of specific events matching each of them, nothing there is about Monica. I expect Tim was trying to avoid touching on the Monica Issue, for very understandable reasons. Mods have been removed in the past (rarely) and every time that occurred and I happened to know a bit of the background (I am a mod on 3 sites and active on many), SE were right to demod. And the mod community was in agreement, very unlike the current fiasco.

Comment: Hi, @terdon.  Yes, I know what the examples were about.  I also understand why Tim might avoid directly referencing Monica's situation.  But George's post, and much of this whole situation, is about the mis-handling of a moderator's removal.  Which is why my comment said "implies."

Comment: @TimPost Maybe the whole problem in "having two CM deciding that someone has to lose moderator status" is not in that part, but the part where currently nobody actually trusts current CMs or people above them are capable of handling such situations fairly.

Comment: @Oded I'm not sure I would be impressed with Sara or David answering. They are burnt. They posted something that turned out to be just hollow word patterns (although one way better concealed than the other), how would anybody trust their next post? I would rather have Tim post something than see another PR desaster from the two.

Comment: While I applaud that there's a new process, according to [David Fullerton](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334551) `We made a decision to act quickly, which I personally approved`. So multiple CMs approved of the Monica firing. It's not clear how the new process differs from the old.

Comment: Arguing about why you had to place that final straw that broke the camel's back isn't helping. Even without it there would have been the next straw (CoC), and then after that whatever straw you plan to release unanimously this week. Realize that mods aren't resigning just because of the Monica issue.

Comment: Look at the votes on the answers, (including this one)! You guy's have a problem here. Fix it!

Comment: Tim, I respect you a lot and I'm sorry you are having a bad time. But you ask in a comment what to do when a mod leaks someone information and makes threats?...what about when an SE employee leaks info, and to the press no less, and without exaggerating endangers the well being of a user?...what then?

Comment: `but it is also a very rare anomaly`. Well, it will only take a single nuclear missile to end humanity, disregarding how rare and how abnormal it is. And IMO "corporate decision that fires a community elected and well regarded moderator" is quite equivalent to nuclear weapon in the whole stack exchange network. Yet it seems like the people, CM, or the mysterious "director" in the incident don't take it as serious as it should be, and only realized it after it created the havoc and started to merely doing some damage control. [1/2]

Comment: I appreciate your long lasting effort and contribution to the community, but the fact that even you taking this case as **just** a "rare anomaly" indicates a clear fact that **SE corporate did not learn the lesson at all**, and probably won't have any problem waving the same nuclear weapon in same manner in the future. [2/2]

Comment: I've upvoted because you posted a reply (that takes courage) and despite everything that has been happened in the last month or so, I know you are a good man. And I know you are not in an easy situation.  You are doing your best but, I really hope this bit is true, your hands are tied.

Comment: "Rare anomaly" is redundant. I always twitch a little when something has to be said twice--too reminiscent of doublespeak. It seems like SO/SE is jumping the shark a bit.

Comment: @TimPost *"There will always have to be a system where we, in an emergency, can pull a lever to remove a moderator's access immediately."* Understood. But are you implying that Monica's dismissal fell into that category? A lot of comments in this thread seem to be from people who are  reading your answer that way. Please clarify!

Comment: Didn't DV the post itself (no pun intended), but hey you work for them so... Yeah. That's why you had it coming. My DV constitutes my disapproval for the company as a whole and the direction it's being taken to. This Post (pun intended) is simply the proxy for that.

Comment: Oh come on, votes are meant to express agreement or disagreement with the post. If you downvote a post because it was written by someone from a company you don't like you start to take things onto a personal level, and that's exaclty what SO and SE in general should *never be*. (@K.Dᴀᴠɪs & others)

Comment: You're right @JonasWilms. Yes, SO should never be personal, but they made it that way. I am just following their lead.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs That makes little sense. On the one hand, you criticize SO for violating the rules, on the other hand you "follow their lead"? Decide for one. If you want to disagree to the CoC, Monica's demodding or some other action, go to Meta SE, there are enough places to discuss these. This is the resignation notice of George.

Comment: Sure. I have to follow the CoC if I want to continue to participate here, doesn't mean I have to be happy about it and I am welcome to criticize in my own capacity. And this is the __response to__ the resignation notice of George - which comes from the an employee of the company that is responsible for this resignation to start with, something I am very displeased with and I am simply expressing such in the response.

Comment: *It is very rare that a moderator is asked to step down* Not to be argumentative, and I'm not implying that this was your fault at all (I don't think that it was), but Monica *wasn't* asked to step down - she was abruptly fired with no explanation. Sorry to harp on that point, but I respected Monica a lot as a moderator and community member.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Upvotes/downvotes shouldn't be about the individual (or the company) posting it, they should be about whether you think that the content itself is useful. Personally, I downvoted because I don't agree with the statements about the process for moderator dismissal, not out of disapproval of the company.

Comment: @EJoshuaS you’re correct. But still missing my point. Mods shouldn’t be fired without explanation, _but one was_. SE should be listening to their community, _but they aren’t_. People shouldn’t be punished for emitting a pronoun, _but we are_. I shouldn’t be DV’ing from something other than the merit of the post, _but I did_.  Nothing on this site makes sense anymore. And I’m just showing it in my own creative way. If we don’t like it, my attitude towards it is the same as SE’s - too bad.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs piling downvotes on Tim because he is staff is just rude. Shog (the top answer) is also staff.

Comment: I can't up or downvote this post, my opinion on its content hovers at "yes, but..." Yes, emergency measures are fine, yes its fine to use them. But the emergency doesn't seem to have existed and proceedures were bypassed over a what seems like a cry of wolf and not an actual wolf. Thanks for saying what you have, Tim, even if I remain highly skeptical.

Comment: This is not an emergency measure. The community is telling the owners "Change your ways."

Comment: @OrangeDog As you point out, Shog9 is also staff. People aren't piling on downvotes because Tim is staff. It's because of the content, I suspect.

Comment: Why so many downvotes?????????