# Letting go of SO

Tags: discussion, moderators, code-of-conduct, licensing

Stack Overflow has been a major part of my Internet and professional life for the last six years.  Over the last two months, my visits to SO have increasingly made me wonder "what unpleasant surprise will I receive this time?"  The licensing and CoC issues<sup>†</sup> have drained the joy I once felt helping people with their programming problems.

Therefore, I have gone inactive.  For the last week, I have not posted to SO or — believe it or not — visited SO or other SE sites for answers to my questions!  I wish the community and SE, Inc., the best, and sincerely hope that I will someday feel comfortable participating again.

My parting request to my fellow contributors is: please license your code contributions under a permissive license (e.g., CC-BY, MIT, or *n*-clause BSD).  My contributions are CC-BY, for example.  That way the worldwide community of programmers will be able to continue to benefit from our answers regardless of what licensing decisions SE, Inc. makes in the future.

Best wishes for the journey!

<sup>†</sup> See, e.g., George Stocker's concerns expressed in his [mod resignation letter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390427/2877364).

<sup>Addendum: SO/SE has actually done an excellent job solving the problems [Joel originally identified](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2018/04/06/the-stack-overflow-age/)! 
 The last week has shown me that SO/SE really are the go-to resources.  For me, though, spending longer to find an answer still takes less time than reading Meta for the latest news. ;)</sup>

Comment: Well, good luck. I would just skip visiting meta myself, but whatever makes you happy.

Comment: I don't feel strongly about this issue, other than I hope that SO Inc can resolve it to the satisfaction of the community. I think they still might. Nevertheless, the interesting philosophical takeaway from this post is the sense of loss and grieving one can experience when leaving a community, even a virtual one. It is an ambivalence between the sunk cost of volunteer time already spent and the future satisfaction of many small collaboration/janitorial actions, versus the untenable frustration of feeling at odds with the actions/values of the leadership.

Comment: "It is easy to quit smoking - I did it 20 times already" (someone's possibly misattributed quote). See you back soon.

Comment: Closely related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386639/why-do-you-stay

Comment: Going inactive for a week isn't a long time and still visiting the site when being redirected from search engines should be harmless, but otherwise I can understand the sentiment. How should I go about licensing my contributions as CC-BY or similar? A statement on the user profile or something else?

Comment: @Trilarion Thanks for asking!  I put a statement in my user profile, and I am sticking to it! :)  I don't know for sure if that would have legal effect in your jurisdiction, so unfortunately I can't give you a definitive answer.