# Warlords of Documentation: How do we unregister?

Tags: support, documentation

There is an obvious link and series of steps for [registering](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/13ynCK-DEy0osod8VIENajnbFJNZxXm1jyeupBrl5v44/viewform). However I can't seem to track down any means of unregistering.

Comment: I'm sure OP won't be the only one who's registered and doesn't participate in the Beta. Often times Present-Me thinks Future-Me will absolutely enjoy activity X, and Past-Me turns out to be a liar.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Participating in [the private beta of Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306213/426671) is completely voluntary just like everything else on Stack Overflow.  If you registered and you no longer want to participate, then you can just not do anything once the private beta opens, that'd be the easiest way to "unregister".

If you want to "unregister" in a more complicated manner, then you could send an email to the team via the "contact us" link at the bottom of any page on the site requesting to be removed from private beta and they'll drop your details.

Comment: Ok I'll give that a go.

Comment: It worked. Just got the email confirmation. Details removed.

Comment: "requesting to be removed from _private_ beta" So any common user can partecipate in private beta?? If so I want to take the place of ouflak!!!! Anyway, i asked this question http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/305376 but I have not received an answer, is there some kind of confirmation? I filled the "register" form and submited it twice, but I have not received any confirmation, is it normal??

Comment: @CliffBurton, Based on my experience from Area 51, when the private beta starts, you should receive a notification and invitation to participate, with a link pointing you to the new site.

Comment: @CliffBurton The form submission went to a highly sophisticated spreadsheet, so yes it's normal to not get anything but the "thanks for your submission..." You'll get contacted once we actually move to private beta.