# Are questions asking whether a product is maintained on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions about whether a particular library or software package (e.g., a compiler) is still maintained, under active development, etc., on topic for Stack Overflow?  While these certainly are tools used by programmers, and the wording doesn't match exactly, I'd have thought that these would probably fall under the recommendations/off-site resource close reason:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

It seems like such questions are really only answerable by the developers or company behind such software, and not a great fit for Stack Overflow, but perhaps that would depend on whether the organization or individuals behind  the software have better channels for communication (mailing lists, support email, etc.)  Answers would seem to be easily outdated, as well, since activity on an active product could cease, or someone could revive a dead product.

Comment: I do have a particular case at hand, [Current status of MOCL Lisp compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33660415/1281433), but this question applies more generally.

Comment: _"It seems like such questions are really only answerable by the developers or company behind such software, and not a great fit for Stack Overflow"_ This. The only answers to those questions are _"Yes"_ and _"No"_.

Comment: OUCH!   THAT HURTS!

Comment: @Cerbrus: No, there is more nuance to a 'No' answer. Sometimes it's because a) there is general agreement that something else better has appeared, where 'better' could be one or more of capability, performance, compatibility, portability, simplicity, standards compliance b) there is/are only one or few maintainers and they stopped (became busy/ lost funding/ lost interest/ walked under a bus)

Comment: Also, can ask something more objective than "Is X being maintained?" like "Has X had a feature release in the last Y months?"

Comment: *"It seems like such questions are really only answerable by the developers or company behind such software..."* That's assuming the software is proprietary and closed-source. If it is open-source, you can view the repo, commits, releases, issues/mailing-list.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think that questions asking if a product is being maintained are off-topic since they're extremely time dependent. The answer can change very quickly. A correct answer now might very well be invalid in six months, after nothing technical has changed at all. These questions are better directed at project maintainers.

Comment: Or (shameless plug) their team page (if exist).

Comment: Not where the answer is "No it's not".

Answer (score 7):

No, they are not on-topic because there is not much to gain once you know that trivia.

But there can be a lot of knowledge be released if asked correctly.

For example, instead of:

- Does it work on Xcode 7.1?

ask

> I ran `mocl -c main.lo --xcode` but it stops with an error `E05: unknown error`. How do I diagnose or fix the root cause?

Another example:

- It supports just a subset of Common Lisp, which parts of the standard were left out ?

could be rewritten to:

> I tried this line `(setf (elt *x* 0) 10)` but I get an error *not supported*. I assumed MOCL supported the common lisp standard. I tried an alternative `assign` but that didn't work either.

If you can wait a bit the upcoming [documentation feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306213/warlords-of-documentation-your-questions-answered) might be a better place to get that kind of info collected and maintained.

Comment: You are assuming a LOT.

1) There are precious few LISP compilers which (on paper) claim to produce objects, sources, or anything remotely compatible with the iOS toolchain. 
2) Knowing "not which is the best", but one which barely works, for sure, would have been BLISS.

Comment: If you think I'm a subject matter expert then I have to disappoint you, because I'm not, I only lisp when I'm drunk. I used examples that are clearly wrong for those that know but do convey the difference in style of asking.

Comment: @user4839438 By the way, regarding the "which parts of Common Lisp are supported", the [bugtracker](https://wukix.com/support/) has a *lot* of items about parts of CL that aren't implemented, e.g., [RENAME-FILE and ENSURE-DIRECTORIES-EXIST are not implemented.](https://wukix.com/support/ticket/86), [CL operators not implemented.](https://wukix.com/support/ticket/84), [ignore-errors doesn't IGNORE ERRORS!](https://wukix.com/support/ticket/70).

Comment: @Rene I made my mind because of your argument, not because of your code. However, you are assuming a lot. 

In practice, there is not an answer to the question I posed on SO, nowhere on the internet indexed by Google either, and the similar ones that exist on SO are outdated/invalid not relevant anymore. 

What is worse you can't tell whether current answers are reliable without trying yourself, which is what I am doing right now.

Comment: @Joshua Taylor: yes, I also noticed that most of these bug tracker items are dated some 256 days ago and still open. They are not "closed" with the status "known limitation" or "subset implementation" only.

Unfortunately the bug tracker provides ZERO information about link process with current projects and current toolchain.

Comment: _"there is not much to gain once you know that trivia"_ I don't follow why this is a condition for on-topicness, and why it's even true.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I used that wording because I expect the OP was experiencing issues with that toolset or that platform. Having strict answers to the questions would probably not help much and lead to follow-up questions, with the risk of it becoming a chameleon question. I already explained in a comment that I'm not a SME and I might have overlooked or misunderstood things but I have not been corrected so far.

Answer (score 2):

As the consensus seems to verge on the "It's off topic", with convincing arguments, especially Rene's, I removed the question.