# Are questions asking for a release date on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

There are plenty questions asking about release dates: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Arelease+title%3Adate

Are those on topic? If yes:

- shall we make those community wiki (as there is most likely only going to be one valid date given as answer)?
- shall we regularly update the question to only reflect concern for an unreleased version? (if question asks for Java 10 release date, we now change it to ask about Java 11 release date instead, to avoid obsolescence)

Or are those off-topic? In that case, what are the adequate closing reasons:

- "asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource"? (finding the release date)
- "primarily opinion-based"? (date estimations)
- "problem that can no longer be reproduced"? (after a release, people want to know about the subsequent release, etc.)

Related:

- [Is questions asking a product's End of Life on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347700/is-questions-asking-a-products-end-of-life-on-topic)
- [Are questions asking whether a product is maintained on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310051/are-questions-asking-whether-a-product-is-maintained-on-topic)

Comment: Questions like these where the perfect example of too localized. Questions that once a certain condition is met it loses all importance for everyone. Also, Half Life 3 was confirmed!

Comment: Off-Topic/Other/"I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a release date" should be enough.

Comment: @Duplode there's no reason to raise a custom moderator flag when community users can close this with their votes without needing to bother diamond mods. The point of this question would just be to establish which close reason to use.

Comment: @DavyM Off-topic/Other doesn't raise a custom mod flag -- it is a normal close vote, only with a custom justification that gets posted as a comment.

Comment: My bad I didn't know that close votes had that difference from flags, learn something new every day :)

Comment: @DavyM Unlike other flags, flags for closure don't eventually go to moderators. Close-flags place the question in the Close-Vote (CV) Review Queue. Regular users with > 3k reputation can then review the questions in the queue. If enough of them (5) vote to close, then the question is placed on hold/closed. Unfortunately, the CV queue is huge (typically 10k questions) and many questions age out of the queue without being reviewed. All other flags eventually get to moderators, unless handled by the community first. Only "In need of moderator attention" (i.e. custom) flags go only to moderators.

Comment: Can also be related to [Customer Service Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company), see example.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Questions asking for a release date are off-topic, for at least *three* reasons:

- [As Enzokie notes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365795/are-questions-asking-for-a-release-date-on-topic#comment572650_365795), they can be regarded as customer service questions. They are explicitly mentioned in [this FAQ Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/2751851) -- as Robert Harvey puts it over there, "we don't know the answer".
- [As Braiam alludes to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365795/are-questions-asking-for-a-release-date-on-topic#comment572618_365795), they are time-sensitive enough to be a poor fit in a site where questions are expected to hold long-term value. See also [Bill the Lizard's answer to *Are questions asking whether a product is maintained on topic?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310053/2751851)
- They don't concern writing code, nor even thinking about code, but merely the potential availability of a tool one might use for writing code. That strays too far from the [general scope guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for them to be acceptable.

As for which close reason to pick, I would go with Off-Topic/Other/"because it is asking for a release date". Off-Topic/Other is meant for clearly off-topic questions that don't necessarily fit the standard close reasons (cf. [*Can we have the “blatantly off topic” close vote back?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274774/2751851)), so it fits the bill perfectly.