# Adding School Projects as Resource for Students

Tags: discussion

I'm a Computer Science student. I asked a few questions around here and somewhat got a hold of how things work around. While I am not StackExchange master, I've noticed two things:

- We, the newbies get dinged up asking, oftentimes simple, stupid questions.
- Most of the resources are designated for far more advanced developers

For that reason, I would like to post code to some of the school projects I've done over the semester. I think by doing so, it would help fellow novice coders to find a possible solution without annoying others. What do you think of this idea?

Also, what would be the best place to post said code?

Comment: I think answering their questions will help beginning programmers a lot more than just posting code for them to copy&paste. (Also, people aren't dinged up for asking simple or stupid questions, but for asking lazy or vague questions.)

Comment: @m69 - but this isn't about copy&paste. If someone wants to do that, it's certainly their choice; they will not learn a thing. However, sometimes just looking at the code, a light bulb goes off. That's just my opinion however.

Comment: There's something in the works that may cover some of this... See: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306213/warlords-of-documentation-your-questions-answered

Answer (score 11, accepted):

...No.  I don't think that there's going to be much value in doing this.

Now, don't get me wrong at all:  I joined here in my senior semester of college, and I learned much the same as you did (although I answered more questions than asked back then...).  I've also been a tutor for CS, and more often than not I know that students won't hesitate to look at some code and copy it wholesale, thinking that it will solve their problem.

Not that this problem doesn't occur enough with professionals also lifting code found here verbatim and placing it into their software...

To add on to that, there's no actual *question* being asked in posting a whole project.  Any question that could be answered by an entire project would easily be too broad for the site.

With that, I don't think that this is a good idea at all.  It's definitely not something you'd put on the network as a question, but if you decide to throw them up on your personal GitHub account and put a link to them in your profile, I don't see the harm.  Just don't blatantly advertise it.

Comment: I completely forgot about GitHub. My head's not working clearly. Useless question I guess. Thanks though!