# Documentation: Support for lack of 1:1 correspondence of SO tags to Docs.SO tags

Tags: feature-request, documentation

Many times, we create tags in SO for different versions of a language/library/etc. This is fine for SO, since we use tags for categorization and finding the right audience for a question.

But in Docs.SO, we have built-in versioning on a tag. We don't need a tag for C++14; we just use the C++ tag. So... what happens to the SO C++14 tag? It looks like it has no documentation, even though it effectively does.

And sometimes, it isn't for versioning. Sometimes, there are SO tags for concepts that are intimately related, but are separate from the perspective of SO categorization. For example, you cannot use OpenGL ES without GLSL anymore, yet we have two separate SO tags for them. Which is fine for SO, but unhelpful for Docs.SO.

What we need is some way to link multiple related SO tags to a single Docs.SO tag. Which means we need to decide who gets to choose which SO tags map to which Docs.SO tags.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem you are trying to solve. The vast majority of tags will lack Documentation either because the tag lacks sufficient questions or nobody cares to create it. So if you look for [c++14] and nothing is created, you'll probably know to look at the [c++] Documentation. Same thing with OpenGL ES, I'd imagine.

Comment: @JonEricson: Well, every time I go to a tag's page, I keep seeing this box on the right imploring people to "Be the first to commit to building the ** Documentation." So if the intent is that most tags won't see documentation... why do you keep asking people to commit to building it? I can understand having a box for tags that actually *have* documentation, but you shouldn't waste precious screen space on a box that will never be filled. We should be able to hook multiple SO tags to a Docs.SO tag, so that users of one of the subsidiary tags get an instant link to the documentation.

Comment: For the moment, Documentation is still a beta feature. There's a chance it won't work or will need serious changes to be made to work. So for the moment, we're going to be a bit pushy about it. (Not that the sidebar thing is very obnoxious; it's using the general real estate we always use for advertisement.) Once Documentation is part of the core of Stack Overflow, we may need to revisit that sidebar and consider making connections between tags. This feature request seems like a premature optimization.

Comment: Folks this is beta..yes beta.  Things take time and testing to be perfect.  If this "annoying" is coming up in the same place ads come up I would say that is not annoying.

Comment: @JonH this post isn't about an invitation to contribute being "annoying", it's about the invitation creating a potential for informational fragmentation. it doesn't make sense to maintain separate documentation for C++14 in two places (the C++ tag and the C++14 tag) . that invites unnecessary extra work to keep them in sync and discrepancies between them will cause confusion... so inviting users to "contribute" to the documentation for a tag like C++14 could be counter-productive.

Comment: @Woo ah there, that same argument you can use for SO... "doesn't make sense to maintain separate communities for C++ in two places (the C++ tag and the C++14 tag)"

Comment: @Braiam SO tags are pretty different from documentation tags. Documentation tags create silos; SO tags don't. Creating C++ and C++14 tags creates two different distinct silos within documentation. Doing the same for SO tags really doesn't create the same level of enforced fragmentation.

Comment: @NathanArthur uh? I have to follow a host of tags if I want all the questions about a particular language instead of one tag, the so called "main language" tag, same occurs with some libraries. How is that not en*forced* fragmentation? But that's another and not the main point of this post. Although, I'm more inclined to fix this on the SO side than on Documentation.

Comment: @Braiam All I meant was a question can have multiple tags, whereas a documentation topic can only be in one documentation tag. But you're right, we're getting sucked down a rabbit hole.

Comment: @JonEricson: Since this is actually being done now, could we switch this from declined to approved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are [working on](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329557/1438) something that should cover the same need:

> **Tag merges and aliases** for Documentation.  We will be adding a mapping from related tags to “master” tags (like [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python-2.7/topics) and [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python-3.x/topics) are related to the “master” [python](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/topics)).  Such a mapping will migrate existing topics to the master tag and prevent re-opening the aliased tag for Documentation.  Initially we (Stack Overflow employees) will be doing these by hand; it may be opened to moderators and high rep users up in the future.

For what it's worth, this was an easier decision to make after a few days of public beta than when the problems were abstract.

Comment: It would also be nice to eventually have a "master" tag that doesn't entail a merge, for packages/libraries to inherit syntax highlighting from their master lang. (That would make sense for R packages, at least.)