# Let me vote on remarks and sort them in with the examples

Tags: feature-request, documentation

Documentation prioritizes examples<sup>1</sup>.  The [official Jsoup cookbook](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/) already has the examples/recipes a user needs to use Jsoup effectively; there's no point in replicating them in Documentation.

Instead, the part of the Jsoup Documentation that I most want users to read -- the part that will save us the most poor Stack Overflow questions -- is [this remarks section about JavaScript support](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jsoup/297/introduction-to-jsoup#t=201607190150572519447&a=remarks-javascript-support-0).  Stack Overflow works on the principle that useful content gets upvoted and displayed at the top.  Yet the most valuable part of the Jsoup Documentation is buried at the bottom of a page and I can't upvote it.

I suppose I could create a new topic titled "JavaScript support", and add a pinned "example" that's just that prose text.  And maybe that's the right thing to do, in terms of making the current design useful, but a prose-only example also seems to deliberately be working against the design.  (Creating another example in that topic wouldn't make sense, for example.)

I think remarks should be votable and sorted along with the examples according to their score.  If the votes indicate the remarks are the most valuable thing on the page, they should be at the top (or maybe under the pinned example).

Either the remarks are a place for valuable content (and SO measures value in votes and rep and reflects it in sorting), or it's a place for not-valuable content, and why do we want to accumulate not-valuable content?

---

<sup>1</sup> *(This is an aside. I'll move it into a new discussion question if it's a distraction.)* Less charitably, it's "give me teh codez" given form.  That may work out, because Documentation was deliberately designed that way.

It doesn't seem useful for Jsoup, because the official cookbook already fills that role.  The Java Language topic seems like an incomplete, poorly-organized version of the [official Java Tutorial topic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) -- and there are [many more official tutorials overall](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html).  Of course the topic will fill out in public beta, but I can't see it ever being *better*.  cppreference.com seems to cover a lot of what the C++ Documentation is aiming at -- compare the just-created [Value categories (Documentation)](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/6343) with [Value categories (cppreference.com)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)].

I can see Documentation being useful for languages/libraries that don't have any official documentation, but so far we seem most excited about duplicating things that exist, either because there are more people who can contribute, or because they're likely to give the most rep.

And when we do add something actually useful, it ends up being not very prominent.  That's frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if I'd call a prominent section in an intro topic "buried". Even having the same text as a highly voted example in another topic wouldn't necessarily give it more prominence as you envision coming from Q&A.

Looking at that remarks and with the caveat that I've never used Jsoup... It looks like exactly what remarks were designed for. There is only one Remarks section per topic. If it's badly written, voting isn't really the right approach there. "Remove them" also seems like a harsh request based on *one* specific use case. The section is optional. If it doesn't make sense for a particular Documentation tag or topic, it doesn't need to be added.

<sub>(As a side note, if Jsoup already has excellent examples elsewhere, that's great! We don't necessarily need to replicate them on SO. :) The goal here is to fix *bad* documentation, not to move good documentation for the sake of moving it. It may well be that Jsoup remains a small section, primarily written/designed to point to the existing official docs. Having said that, we'll be monitoring how Documentation is used, and fundamental model changes aren't *entirely* out of the question... but they are rather unlikely in the short term.)</sub>

Comment: My point was that it's _well-written_ and I want to vote it _up_ so more people will see it.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Yeah, I just realized I phrased that paragraph badly. Sorry about that. My point is that sections of a topic are more or less equal... with examples being at the top. Voting makes sense for answers because there are multiple answers. This is also why there's voting on examples - to surface the more useful ones to the top within that list. What would upvotes on Remarks do, exactly, when there's only one section and there's nothing else in its category that has votes?

Comment: I want it to sort in with the examples, so if the votes indicate the remarks are the most useful thing on the page, they end up at the top (or maybe under the pinned example).  (Also, voting would reward the authors of the remarks with rep.)

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting idea. I unfortunately don't think it's feasible with the way things are currently designed... but it's definitely interesting.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I can't promise any implementation, but I promise we'll at least discuss this internally, especially if there's more support here on meta.

Comment: Thanks, of course that's the most I can ask you for.  (I edited the question to focus more on making remarks first-class citizens of the page.)

Answer (score 1):

One potential use case of SO Documentation will be simply pointing to better documentation elsewhere. That's more or less what I had in mind when I contributed [Perl's Hello World topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/perl/341/hello-world#t=201607191744023710886). Even back in the Usenet days, I felt the biggest problem with the Perl documentation was that people didn't know where to find it. So having more features allowing users to point to existing documentation from Stack Overflow is a win. Not as much of a win as allowing people to create *better* documentation, of course, but that's easier for some technologies than others.

Not knowing anything about Jsoup at all, I actually really appreciate having an example up front. I can tell at a glance what it does and why I might want to use it. A Java programmer would instantly be able to picture how Jsoup could be used to replace or extend existing code. Think of it as good advertising. Instead of a list of features, most ads [show the product](https://youtu.be/NQhwNtY3N2k) being used. For the introductory topic, I think the same principle applies.