# Documentation should have an initial section

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, documentation

The new documentation feature should have an initial area to explain the topic. Take "Dependency Injection" as an example. There's "Constructor Injection", "Setter Injection", "Injection Containers", but where should dependency injection itself be explained? I'm really missing an initial section above the examples.

Comment: I believe the Remarks section is where that information is supposed to go. Being at the very bottom of the page *is* quite annoying, IMHO.

Comment: It being the very last thing, I don't think it's supposed for that purpose.

Comment: You can “pin” an example to make it show up above the other ones.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan yeah normally the remarks has all the weird part of a particular topic and usually is an eye-opener even for some of the even well versed on the topic. Keeping this last maybe is not the best idea indeed. Maybe the better approach is to show only the best example and collapsing the others.

Comment: There should be an initial section that's an overview, and the Remarks section should be more of a "stuff to keep in mind" section.

Comment: Remarks are meant for pitfalls and tips for the topic.. there should be a separate `Overview` section..

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328431/add-optional-synopsis-for-a-topic

Comment: Related: [Let me vote on remarks and sort them in with the examples](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328218/let-me-vote-on-remarks-and-sort-them-in-with-the-examples)

Answer (score 11):

[Per the latest update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329557/80572), we will be adding a "Focus" section to each topic.

This section will be optional, and will be intended to indicate the sorts of examples (and by extension, the content of other sections) one should expect on the topic.

Comment: This is apparently _not_ an answer. As the [doc update announcement](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329557/2373138) states: _"It is **explicitly not a summary** of the topic"_ :-(

Comment: @kelunik my concern with summarizing is that a summary will be immediately out of sync with the following content _and large_.  Once you're a little familiar with something, you'll have to scroll past a bunch of (now useless to you) commentary to get to the examples - and I'm pretty confident you'll need the examples many more times than you needed a summary.

Comment: Then restrict it to 500 or 1000 characters and that's no longer an issue? If it's a general intro to the topic, it won't go out of sync with the examples.

Answer (score 9):

**Generally speaking, I'd say the "Remarks" section is where that sort of general explanation belongs.**

Now, that still leaves the question of where on the page it belongs. The decision to emphasize examples was deliberate. That said, I can totally see the argument for remarks (and possibly syntax, etc.) coming first.

I think the key question is which of the following use cases is more common once most of Docs visitors are Googling their way here:

1. Someone looking to learn a function or concept for the first time, with little to no prior experience in it?
2. Someone who knows of, or has some recollection of the function/concept, but can't quite work out how to use it in a given scenario, or to address a new need?

In case case #1, it makes more sense to lead with the basic explanation, while in case #2, I think having the examples first will be a lot more useful. Right now, I think we're overweighting how often we'll tend to be in case #1, since we're *browsing* Docs itself.  (Plus we're more used to that from other sites.)  But down the line, I suspect a lot more visitors in need will be searching for a thing they know the basics of, but can't remember quite how to apply it.

But I'm on the fence a bit myself - as someone who's *rarely* in code, I personally am often scrolling down to the remarks.

Comment: Even if you put it at the top of the page, it would still be called "Remarks". At least with the pinned example idea, you can give it a more descriptive title.

Comment: I agree with Daniel M's comment in the question. "remarks" sounds more like stuff to keep in mind, exception to some rules, etc. Maybe an overview section on top of the examples, collapsed by default so it doesn't bother people in case #2, but is still useful for people in case #1?

Comment: Sounds to me like perhaps some A/B testing should be done once this is more popular

Comment: Even in case #2, it is not that hard to scroll down a few clicks. The introductory material should be *easy to find*, while still being easy to skip. Burying it at the bottom of the page violates that first rule. And if the search feature worked properly, it would be even less of a problem.

Comment: In my brief glance at Docs.SO, I didn't even notice we *had* a remarks section because of its placement. The name is making my brain skip a beat too -- the word "remarks" is one step away from "comments" and two steps away from "trivia". Hardly a label for something I'd expect to be titled something like "overview".

Comment: I think you got this wrong, examples should be the LAST thing on the page.  Believe it or not and although I hate the wording, Remarks, should be the first section if this is your recommendation (I hate the word remarks but it is what it is).

Answer (score 7):

Maybe in the spirit of @Jaydles answer above, the big explanation for describing the item would be in the Remarks section (which was deliberately placed on the bottom).

However, I could definitely see value in having an tldr for the remarks at the top, (on both the overall tag screen as well as for each topic), which is intended to be 500 chars or less of a summary on what the topic is about (and a link to the longer remarks on the bottom that would go into more depth).

That way a new user can at least get the context of what all of the examples are about in a less intimidating way.

Answer (score 5):

I have been using the pinned example for introduction material on a topic. I don't know if that was the intent, but it is a functional solution for the time being.

Comment: Pinned examples have yet another headline. They can work for this purpose, but something dedicated really is missing.