# Order of examples within a topic

Tags: discussion, documentation

Examples are currently shown in the order they were created. What happens when later examples are providing more basic information about the topic than earlier examples? Should a mechanism for reordering examples within a topic be implemented?

This issue is related to [hierarchical structure for topics](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315160/more-hierarchical-structure-needed-for-documentation-topics).