# Allow nested topics

Tags: feature-request, documentation

Some tags are accumulating hundreds of topics, and many topics are accumulating a lot of examples covering various aspects of the topic.

We should be able to create hierarchies of topics so people can find things more easily.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't realize this had already been suggested: [More hierarchical structure needed for documentation topics](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315160/more-hierarchical-structure-needed-for-documentation-topics)