# Documentation wikis to prevent duplicated content between tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation

#### Can we have a 'Documentation Tag Wiki' that sits within the dashboard page of a tag and gives a brief explanation of what should be documented under that tag?

---

I've just [made a change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/777/introduction-to-excel-vba#t=201607252327554226985&a=remarks) to the remarks section of an intro topic for a tag in order to try and reduce the amount of duplicated and unnecessary topics being produced.

The problems I see already are:

- The 'Introduction to [language]' topic isn't very obvious and probably doesn't get much attention
- The 'Remarks' section appears *after* the examples which again, probably doesn't get much attention

---

**The *real* problem here is that Documentation is driven from SO tags - tags that don't necessarily represent a language and have tag-wikis that explain what is on-topic for Q&A but not for Documentation.**

---

In order to try and combat this kind of behaviour ***before*** it becomes a massive clean-up operation I would like to propose this simple addition to the dashboard page.

Comment: What good is a page that nobody will read? After all, Docs.SO was supposedly made to be a better, more visible Tag Wiki. So what good will giving a Docs tag a tag wiki page do?

Comment: It wouldn't be a page, just an additional section on the dashboard tab. The idea being that at the moment there is no real direction as to what people should document and where - this will at least offer some guidance in the same way that SO tag wikis suggest what may not be on-topic for a certain tag.

Comment: Now you are asking for structure! Grand plan didn't include that! http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315160/more-hierarchical-structure-needed-for-documentation-topics/328351#328351