# Add stackoverflow-style tags to topics

Tags: feature-request, tags, documentation

There's been [a post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315160/more-hierarchical-structure-needed-for-documentation-topics) requesting a hierarcheral to documentation, but I think it's not very user friendly. Instead, I propose Stack Overflow tags. They take longer to access and are more complex

Take a look at [The Django topic](http://take%20a%20look%20at%20stackoverflow.com/%E2%80%A6%20and%20all%20the%20PostgreSQL%20added%20fields%20documented%20in%20separate%20examples%20-%20too%20large%20to%20be%20in%20one%20topic,%20all%20extremely%20related) and all the PostgreSQL-related fields documented in separate examples - too large to be in one topic but all extremely related. This would be more easily searchable with tags without trading off user friendliness. If someone wanted to learn about the fields added by PostgreSQL, he/she could just search with a tag.

Note that the current dupe target is a discussion. No conclusion was reached on that one.

**I'm not proposing 19th century tag clouds** - I want Stack Overflow style tags.

Comment: @k3b that was discussion, this is feature-request. No conclusion was reached on that one.

Comment: "Note that the current dupe target is feature-request." Typo: you mean discussion, not FR.