# When is Documentation coming out of private beta?

Tags: discussion, support, documentation

When will Documentation be ready for us to see, use, and edit? I tried signing up for the private beta a few days ago at the link [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306213/5644794), but I never got anything in my email or on my Stack Overflow account (clearly, because private beta has already started, but it was worth a shot).

Comment: I'd guess "not very soon", because Kevin Montrose, who did a lot of work on Docs, [is focused on other things right now](https://twitter.com/aalear/status/701173488074280965).

Comment: I signed up for the beta when it was first announced, but haven't gotten an invite yet.  Several waves of invites have gone out, and [everyone who signed up is supposed to eventually get in to the beta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow#comment292041_303865), repeated again [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow#comment296418_303865).

Comment: IIRC what the devs said: "Public beta will begin in a few months". There's an [chatroom for it](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31310/documentation-beta), open to everyone, where you can ask them though. It's being actively worked on.

Comment: @Sally - I got married last year. That only eats up 2-3 weeks.

Comment: @PetahChristian Alright, I still may have a chance for the private beta. Your second comment link mentions that the waves are gated by tags, and [this](https://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/users/login?ssrc=beta&returnurl=%2f) is giving me the general idea that iOS nor Swift (tags I signed up for) are ready yet.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: You got a full 2-3 weeks off? You're _lucky_! Many people are fortunate to be able to get just a week off for a honeymoon. So, like you, I don't really see the relevance to Docs, unless the notion of getting married has had Kevin slacking off in daydream land for the past few months! Or maybe SE has a particularly lenient policy when it comes to vacations.

Comment: @PreferenceBean - It's not just the honeymoon. I had a lot of people fly in for the wedding - I had to help all of them get around and find stuff. There was a lot of last minute stuff I had to do at the venue. There's the bachelor party. The honeymoon itself ate 6 business days. The other stuff ate an additional 3 business days.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Congratulations by the way

Comment: My personal universal answer is 6-8 weeks.

Comment: @all I'm in the private beta, have to confess to being mildly underwhelmed...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[According to Adam Lear](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27669760#27669760), current plan is to **end of March/early April**.
Then the public beta will begin, and [it will take place on Stack Overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIiet.png).

Comment: Okay, so definitely not in a "few more days" like the beta website says if you don't have private beta access.

Comment: It says "at least a few more days".