# When will everyone who signed up for Documentation Beta get an invite?

Tags: discussion, support, documentation

When will all users who requested for an invite to Documentation be selected for the beta?

**Everyone who signed up was supposed to get into the beta as stated:**

- [Comment 1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow#comment292041_303865)

> @ivarni the beta is underway, but we're letting people in in waves. Documentation is big and new, I don't want to burn everyone out on v0.1. At time of writing, a little less than 1/3 of all the people who signed up have been invited. Another wave will be invited Soon™, and everyone who signed up will be invited before the beta ends.

- [Comment 2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow#comment296418_303865)

> @HunterStevens Documentation will be whatever the license on SO is, which I'd kind of hoped would be attribution-optional MIT but currently still is CC-BY-SA. The next wave will be when we're ready for one :) They tend to come every week or two, but are gated by which tags you signed up for. You haven't been invited yet, but you will be (everyone who signed up will get in eventually).

**However, it was also stated that the private beta will end in around March / April:**

- [Chat 1](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27669760#27669760)

> Current plan is to "end of March/early April"

- [When is Documentation coming out of private beta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317806/when-is-documentation-coming-out-of-private-beta)

Currently, it is already mid-March. How soon will all those who requested an invitation be invited?

---

Also, even though it was stated that most popular tags can be picked, most people invited are only active in [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) or [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23). [Source (Last Paragraph)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow)

> Please pick tags from the first two pages of popular tags that have an especially active community. Things like c#, r, or ios so we can test our system out against the real things that lots of developers are using in the private beta.

Thus, are all those invited to the private beta required to have tags such as [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) or [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)?

---

P.S. I've signed up for Documentation for [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) and [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) but haven't got an invite.

---

**UPDATE:**

As of mid-Mar, around 500 of 3k signups have gotten an invite. Creating of new tags will be ready to test soon. [Chat 2](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28233785#28233785)

> @luweiqi 500-odd of the (approximately) 3k signups; I'm hoping to ramp up to basically 100% invited in the near future.

> I think we'll be ready to test out "community opens" of new doc tags, so we probably won't invite just folks who signed up for a single tag - though we'll have to fake some top tags from SO, since they don't exist on docs-beta atm.

> So [php], [mysql], and [node.js] are "coming soon" @styfle @luweiqi

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FAFyh.png

Comment: This is not really an answer to your question, but "soon", and "everyone will eventually get an invite". From my reading of things said in chat, that could be next week. A bit of background: the docs site currently _only_ supports android, java, c#, and the others you mentioned, and there is _no_ support for other tags like PHP yet. I read that new tag creation could be going live next week, at which point you might get an invite. (I'm in the private beta, I got an invite 3 weeks ago).

Comment: @JonasCz Noted, thanks for your quick response :)

Comment: ..And, since you asked in the docs-beta chatroom, you're pretty much guaranteed to get an answer from the devs tomorrow.

Comment: In about 6-8 weeks

Comment: See: [Documentation: The Update-en-ing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319319)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We haven't invited [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) or [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) users yet. It's going to be at least another month before launch and one of the features that Documentation still lacks is a method to open up new tags. We are testing a minimal system on our development environment which will be available soon in the private beta. At that point, we should be able to invite people on the list who are interested in tags that have not yet been opened up.

The plan is to invite everyone who signed up for the private beta before we launch Documentation. We've been trickling in new testers so that we get fresh feedback for new and altered features. Letting everyone in at once makes for a [poor beta test](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/BetaTest.html). As long as there are new features that need testing, we're going to want to hold some beta testers in reserve. Once Documentation is ready for launch, it will help to have everyone who signed up in the private beta hammer on it to find any last minute bugs. My guess is that there will be at least a week more of private beta once everyone has been invited.

Short answer: hang tight.

Comment: Thanks for the update, looking forward to receiving an invite :)

Comment: What about Ruby users? I believe I signed up with that tag

Comment: @onebree: Same story. You ought to see an invitation before launch, which is at least a month off.

Comment: I swear I put [tag:android] as a tag of mine -- according to [JonasCz](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318894/when-will-everyone-who-signed-up-for-documentation-beta-get-an-invite#comment321464_3188940) Android is already a part of docs. Did you invite everyone interested in the current tags already or was that a staged invite system too?

Comment: @hichris123: Invitations were sent to a subset of the people interested in the tags. The goal was to get a cross section of veteran and newer users. There was an element of chance too.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is just a coincidence, but yesterday - several month after I've registered myself for the private beta - I've got my "Welcome to the Stack Overflow Documentation Beta!" email right after:

1. I've tried the first time to actually access

   http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/

   > Warning: this site is currently in private beta for at least a few more days.
   >   To log in, you must have commited to the [Area 51 site proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/lookup/docs-beta.stackexchange.com) and received the invitation email. Click the invitation link in the email to log in!

   Even the shown link is not working - see [Documentation beta broken link to Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277321/documentation-beta-broken-link-to-area51) - I anyway gave it a try and
2. I did sign-up and log-in to Area 51.

So I'm not sure - I obviously can't try it again - but one of the two actions seems to have triggered the last step for my invitation.

Comment: I think you'll still need to request an invite first using the Google Form before the deadline

Comment: @luweiqi Thanks for the hint. Yes, I had registered earlier this year. I've updated my answer accordingly. Just out of curiosity: How did you know that you had to join Area 51?

Comment: I don't think that it's required join Area 51. Documentation Beta isn't created using the Area 51 proposal route. For me, I clicked on the link in the invitation email I received and got into the beta. Maybe it's a coincidence that you received the email right after you joined Area 51.

Comment: @luweiqi Probably this is the standard text for all private betas. But after waiting for several month, I don't believe in coincidences here. If you have not signed-up to Area 51, then I'm a little lost and everything is back to speculations. Maybe trying to access "Docs-Beta" did trigger the invitation email?

Comment: Not sure, anyway thanks for your detailed answer :-)