# Documentation: The Update-en-ing

Tags: discussion, documentation

<strike>Six-to-eight weeks</strike> [Several](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303865/80572) [months](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306213/80572) ago we proposed an expansion to Stack Overflow: **Documentation**. People have been asking for an update for a while, and we’re finally ready to give one.

The beta has been underway since mid-November, and at time of writing about one thousand invites have gone out. If you signed up but haven’t been invited yet, don’t worry - **everyone who signs up will eventually get an invite**.

We’ve learned a lot in the beta and now have a decent idea for what a V1 looks like for Documentation. Accordingly we also now have a good idea for about when the beta will end: sometime in April.

#### This means beta *signups* will be closed on March 31st

The beta itself will continue for a bit after so those last few signups can get invited. Documentation won’t be going live on Stack Overflow on April 1st or anything like that.

### What’s new?

There are a bunch of features that either weren’t ready when the last post went out, or that the beta showed us we needed.

In no particular order, here are some of the more notable additions:

#### Pinned Examples

[image: Pinned examples]

Each Topic can have its most important Example pinned to the top; the rest follow in vote order. We believe a Topic having more than one "this is the most important" Example is a sign that the Topic needs to be broken up.

#### Reputation System

There are lots of little details, but the TL;DR is:

[image: Reputation tour]

Naturally you can't give yourself reputation, and [deletions snatch back reputation in a similar manner to Q&A](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/). Reputation will be shared with your Stack Overflow Q&A account once Documentation is [out of beta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow).

*NOTE:* +5 reputation on cited documentation can be gained for a (Topic|Example)+Answer pair.

#### Search For Documentation from Q&A Editor

[image: New link insertion]

This make it easier to find Documentation to link to while answering questions. The current "Insert Hyperlink" is still the default naturally.

#### Links Can’t Break

I think everyone can agree that broken documentation links (be they in code comments, blog posts, tweets, or whatever) are super frustrating. Of course, you still want Documentation (and the search results that point to it) to improve over time.

The design we’ve settled on is:

- We always serve the latest versions (including 404s for deleted Topics) by default

  - this means Google only serves up the latest stuff
- But if you have an old link, we offer to show you the "when that link was created" version

For **old versions of non-deleted Topics**, this looks like:

[image: Topic has since been edited]

**Deleted Topics** look like:

[image: Topic is currently deleted]

**Deleted Examples** look like:

[image: example is currently deleted]

Viewing an older version includes a little notice at the top, disables editing, and doesn’t allow voting:

[image: Viewing an old version]

#### Lots of notification options

The obvious ones are done:

- My change was approved/rejected
- A change to fix an issue I raised was proposed
- Someone commented on my issue or change
- Someone replied to one of my comments

Sections on Documentation Dashboards can also be subscribed to:

[image: Notification eyes]

When subscribed to a section you get *at most one* notification per time period. If there are multiple things to notify about, we make sure each item is sent to about the same number of people. If the notified item is handled before someone views their inbox, we delete the item to prevent pointless noise in their inbox (there’s a natural race here, so we can’t be *perfect* but we do what we can).

#### Deciding which tags get Documentation

We’ve landed on an [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com)-lite approach. To avoid creating ghost towns, we require a minimum number of users who are already active in the tag to commit to working on Documentation.

In beta this looks like:
[image: what commitments looks like]

On Stack Overflow we’ll raise the bar to:

- 10 users
- with 150+ reputation
- with at least one positively scored answer in [tag]

Committers get auto-subscribed when a tag's Documentation opens up, so there'll be people around to handle any improvement requests or changes right from the start.

#### And a bunch more!

This post is getting pretty long, but there is more! We’ve been doing semi-regular announcements in the beta. I've cut them down and put them all (in reverse order of release) [into a public document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nvUumvME1Q9upeD4T9cNpYv6bDSBXSXy3hQGLgxkUZI/edit?usp=sharing).

<strike>Of course if you want firsthand experience...</strike>

## Sign up for the Documentation Beta

...by March 31st 2016.

Comment: *Documentation won’t be going live on Stack Overflow on April 1st or anything like that* - is that because no-one would believe you anyway? :p "Hey Guys, Documentation is going live on April Fool's Day"... "yeah yeah - we believe you SE..."

Comment: Looks like we still can't propose/commit to new tag docs (like iOS) on the beta site?

Comment: @undo correct - waiting until the next wave of invites goes out to create a few dozen _Q&A_ tags to try it out with.  Couple folks on the team were out this week, makes timing tricky.

Comment: @JonClements The value in keeping people guessing there is almost _too_ much to pass up; _almost_ ... maybe we'll do something else with stuff just as out of date as dinosaurs? And there's also blueberry muffins, who hates those? I'm so glad I managed to get a live duck that happily sits on my desk, it has been enlightening.

Comment: On behalf of the remaining preservationist contingent, I'd like to thank you for considering the accessibility of deleted content from the beginning. :) The solution you've implemented is very sensible. Ensuring that all links include a reference to a specific version, while still showing the latest by default, is a great way to balance concerns around link rot and stale content.

Comment: @TimPost it's funny you should mention that - come round mine two weeks today and I'll introduce you to "Nick Che" - he's 65 million years old and made of blueberries - it sounds like you two will get on great!

Comment: We want $0.01 per view.

Comment: If we've already signed up for the beta in the earlier run, should we do so again here?

Comment: @Makoto nope - it's the same form, if you've already signed up you're still on the list.

Comment: @KevinMontrose: If I wanted to ask for clarification about what the Google Docs document you pointed us to means, would that be better stated as a question on MSO, or as an answer to this question?

Comment: @NicolBolas answers to this question, though I will stress that the Google Doc is a log of announcements presented because I know folks are curious - it doesn't document every little change, or every little feature in Documentation.

Comment: I think everyone can agree that broken documentation links ... are super frustrating. Especially when they are links to deleted SO questions :-)

Comment: Since links can't be broken, will link-only Q&A answers linking to Documentation eventually be considered "okay"?

Comment: "To avoid creating ghost towns, we require a minimum number of users who are already active in the tag to commit to working on Documentation" can we do the same for tag creation on the main site, pretty please?

Comment: Will a tag like [tag:ios] require examples to use both (Swift and Objective-C) languages?

Comment: @PetahChristian For iOS, I would hope something like NSHipster's codeblocks would be implemented, where you can choose between Swift and Objective-C right next to the code.

Comment: The initial announcement for Documentation was met with a whole lot of negative/critical feedback. Have any of those concerns been addressed? It looks like this update is focused on polish and features, with no mention of fundamental issues like whether it's a good idea.

Comment: @Braiam: "*can we do the same for tag creation on the main site, pretty please?*" That would make no sense. How could you have a minimum number of users using a tag if the tag *does not exist yet*? Docs.SO is linked to the tags on SO.

Comment: Is the documentation reputation shared with the Stack Overflow rep?

Comment: @poke, It will be, once Documentation is out of beta, see the FAQ section of [the first announcement](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow).

Comment: @TimPost I guess it's too late for this to be non-excusivley stack overflow? I have 61 in bash on [ubuntu.se] but none here - it feels a shame that I wouldn't be able to participate there.

Comment: Honestly I am a bit unclear what this documentation thing is about? Why is it needed? What problem does it solve???

Comment: Mark my words this and teams is a complete disaster. There is no purpose in either.  This is why nothing has come out of teams yet...it's a useless feature.

Comment: I've also never really understood what teams was supposed to be, but I am excited to see what documentation could become, because we all have an opinion on what documentation should be, we've all cursed rubbish documentation (and in some cases even written it!) The problem with this at present is that it is something we all have a (strong) opinion on, and we kind of, maybe, perhaps get what is being offered, but until we can get in and kick it around the block a few times, we're left with curiosity, misinformation and an occasional scream and ominous thud from the other side of the wall.

Comment: @KyleStrand there are no plans to change Q&A rules based on the mere existence of Documentation.  I also think we'll always want Answers to standalone (ie. not require someone click another link to get the "real answer"), so I doubt that particular rule will ever go away.

Comment: @MichaelB There's a balancing act.  We could have just built and launched Documentation, no warning.  I think we can all agree that would have been a disaster.  We could have done a soft-launch with a system that didn't work, and try to let the community help us iterate to one that does. I suspect that would also have been a disaster, based on cadence and fatigue in the beta.  Our middle path (a pre-beta dialog, private beta, pre-launch dialog) is, in my opinion, the best option but there is plenty of room for misunderstanding.

Comment: @KevinMontrose I understand, and agree with the reasoning, I couldn't see a better way to do that part. It is good that we've had time to consider it before we launch a million complaints on Documentation.Meta, and that you've had chance to (I presume - still waiting for my beta ;) ) figure out the glaring kinks in the whole thing. My point was that the reason for the balancing act, is that everyone does have an opinion about documentation, and that will make it an interesting site.

Comment: @KevinMontrose obsolesense => obsolescence (in screenshot) :)

Comment: how do you document for different versions of the same tech? If this cannot be done in a sane and sustainable manner, reverting to official docs still seem like the way to go

Comment: @Benjol It's their proprietary algorithm for sensing obsolete content :-D

Comment: @KevinMontrose In that case, what about closing questions as "duplicates" of Documentation examples? Otherwise it seems like there will still be lots of redundancy.

Comment: I still don't understand why SE is trying to compete with http://devdocs.io/. DevDocs is great and continues to improve. Why not just try to contribute to that effort?

Comment: @SteveBennett While devdocs does look nice, it just happens to be missing every language that is so far in SO documentation (Java, C#, .Net, Android)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I don't think your statement that "The initial announcement for Documentation was met with a whole lot of negative/critical feedback." is completely true. It's the most upvoted post on Meta SO of all time, and was met by even more positive feedback than negative feedback.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers - It does have a lot of upvotes, and it does have some positive feedback. However, that doesn't affect the accuracy of the statement I made. There was a lot of negative/critical feedback. Last time I checked that question, there were a couple answers that said "this is a good idea" and over a dozen that said "please no." As far as I can see, the latter are being ignored.

Comment: @TotZam Perfect. So this whole project could have been "Let's add Java, C#, .Net and Android to DevDocs".

Comment: +1 for placing the picture of Kitty cat at the right place ! I will up-vote twice if that kitty will be animated

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: "*there were a couple answers that said "this is a good idea" and over a dozen that said "please no."*" Well, what would you expect? There are only one or two ways to agree with somebody, but there are dozens of ways to disagree. So naturally, there are dozens of people with disagreeing answers. And there are plenty of "cautiously optimistic" answers too. So let's not pretend that the response to the initial idea was strongly negative.

Comment: @NicolBolas - I'm not pretending anything. This idea is being railroaded through with no regard to criticisms, it won't solve underlying problems, and it will turn into yet another band-aid fix that ends up with one of its adhesive pads losing its adhesion and flopping around uselessly while the wound gets dirty.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: You're not really listening to what people are responding to here. We're saying that your characterization of the reaction to the idea as being "*met with a whole lot of negative/critical feedback*" is not true. There has certainly been criticism of the idea, but calling it "a whole lot" is simply not true. And let's face facts: the only way to respond to your *particular* criticism on that thread that you would consider satisfactory would be for them to simply not bother to try anything at all to resolve the problem.

Comment: @NicolBolas - Okay, I'll imagine that there wasn't a lot of negative feedback. How much of it was addressed here? Apparently none. And please note that my suggestion in the original Documentation question was to actually care about documentation to a greater extent than "I guess I'll throw something together myself." I don't know why I'm still trying to make a difference here; it's obvious that SE is ignoring negative feedback so that they can push this through as a great idea.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: "*How much of it was addressed here? Apparently none.*" Only if the only way you consider criticism "addressed" would be to stop doing Docs.SO. The issue of versioning was a common criticism. There were plenty of concerns about outdated pages or other such things. Some people had concerns about whether examples would be present/encouraged/whatever. They've addressed those potential problems. They haven't addressed every criticism. Or most of them. Or probably more than half. But again, saying "none" is wrong.

Comment: And I thought the Sith Lord had arrived on SO. sickening

Comment: People who think and say that existing documentation of computer technology "sucks" scaring me.

Comment: Hmm...when are the remaining people going to get invited? I signed up and still have not received an invitation email.

Comment: @TroyT I signed up on Day 1 and only got my invite yesterday. They send them out in waves.

Comment: @TylerH I know they send them out in waves, I was just curious since this post says the beta is going to end this month.

Comment: @TroyT They initially said some time in April but it's looking like June the way things are going. Besides, most of what's going on now is actually bug-fixing of Documentation, not actual Docs being written (though there's that, too).

Answer (score 159):

Looking at the Google Docs list of announcements and description of the site, I have to say that I find myself... rather disappointed and confused as to the whole purpose of this endeavor.

The part that I'm concerned about is found in The Tour section:

> The most important, and only mandatory, set of pieces are **Examples**. Examples demonstrate how to use whatever is being documented and need to be self-contained (ideally copy/paste-able) and succinct.
>
> Examples embody **Show, Don’t Tell**. A Topic will live and die by its Examples - a good Topic is one where most people don’t need to do anything beyond scan one of the Examples to find what they need to know.

So... what exactly is Documentation.SE? Is it intended to be some kind of code dump of examples? I don't understand what a "topic" is, if a topic must be a thing that's small enough to have a code example associated with it.

Maybe my field of expertise, in terms of documentation, is somewhat narrow. My primary experience in this field is writing the [OpenGL Wiki](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Main_Page), which tries to describe the functionality and behavior of various parts of the OpenGL API.

I cannot imagine how I would structure that information in the "code-as-topic" style that you seem to want. Or, more to the point, I have no idea how to present information as complicated as things get in OpenGL in such a style.

Let me put it this way. This is the OpenGL Wiki article on "[Vertex Shaders](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Shader)". How do you break this down into "topics"?

If we're doing "code-as-topic", then you can't have a topic called "Vertex Shader". Why? Because Vertex Shaders are huge, complex beasts. They're written in an entirely different language, interact with vertex specification and rendering commands, feed data to later rendering pipeline stages, and so forth.

Oh sure, you could write an example of a Vertex Shader. But I *guarantee* that any user who has no idea what a VS is, will have no more idea of what it is after reading an example of one. Or five examples.

So maybe you could break down the bits of a VS into several topics. Could Vertex Shader Inputs be a topic? I don't think so; it's going to involve two separate things: the in-shader declarations, and the corresponding vertex array code that feeds them. It's also going to have to involve the rendering command, since instancing can adjust the meaning of a VS input.

Is there a way to make a topic around even one small aspect of a VS? Take the built-in input `gl_InstanceID`. How can you make that a topic?

You can't. Again, you can write an example that shows it being used. But because of the complex interactions between `gl_InstanceID` and the rendering command that touches it off, you will need a large number of examples to cover the important information. And even then, you won't actually cover that information meaningfully until you *explain what's happening* in the code examples, which is a section at the *bottom* of the page.

Even documenting a single OpenGL API entrypoint with "code-as-topic" seems insane. There is no one example of a function like `glTexImage2D` that can *possibly* capture the sheer scope of what that thing does. You could have *dozens* of examples and still not cover everything. None of those examples could be "copy/paste-able".

And quite frankly, we have enough copy/pasting going on in the OpenGL community; we really don't need to encourage more.

Even if you change the topic from "document `glTexImage2D`" to "create a 2D texture"... well, how do you do that? Even ignoring the versioning issue, the number of options for creating textures is *legion*, and it's not restricted to the parameters of a single function. Does this texture have mipmaps? What image format do you want to use? Are you creating a compressed texture?

Are you uploading pixel data? If so, what's the format of that data? What about the pixel alignment, or uploading sub-rectangles?

Should the example apply sampling parameters to the texture, or should it be assumed that users will use explicit sampler objects? If you want to apply sampling parameters, that's a [whole other mess of options](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_Object#Sampling_parameters).

Oh, and none of that will ever explain the most important part of creating a texture: *[what a texture is](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture)*. An example cannot convey important information like the fact that a texture is composed of 3 parts (storage, texture parameters, and sampler parameters). It can only show the code; it cannot show the *meaning* behind the code.

Just as your example for `Query` can only show the code calling it; it cannot show what that particular query actually *does* with the database.

And be aware that this is just OpenGL. AKA: the *easy-to-use* graphics API. God help you if you try to apply this style to ***Vulkan***! "Ideally copy/paste-able"?

Yeah, good luck with *that*.

I simply do not understand how this "code-as-topic" style will accomplish anything useful for any system of real complexity. It's like telling someone to write a tutorial that is short, *self-explanatory*, comprehensive enough to be useful documentation, and somehow "copy/past-able" for user consumption.

So exactly what [kind of documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow/313489#313489) is this site for? If this site is for reference documentation, for documenting function calls, then why are they called "topics" and not "functions"? And why put the example first? Must functions that are complex enough to deserve reference documentation are too complex for one example to explain its full meaning. And having to sift through a half-dozen pieces of code before finding one that actually explain *what it does* is rather silly.

---

(Collation of commentary information)

> The rough philosophy here (and I'm probably butchering Kevin's vision, but...) boils down to, "a practical example is worth 1000 words of explanation".

This is a documentation style that does not work for anything but the most basic of systems.

In any system, there will be many things which cannot effectively be conveyed by examples. For example, let us consider the OpenGL Wiki article on the [Incoherent Memory Accesses](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Memory_Model#Incoherent_memory_access).

You could take the "guidelines and use cases" section at the bottom and construct examples of them. And in that way, you would indeed have code that someone could use in their application.

But do not fool yourself into thinking that anyone who reads such examples actually understands what they're doing. Such people will still have no idea of the complex interrelationships between such operations. The concepts of asynchronous memory access, synchronization, and visibility are highly in-depth, and code examples are not an effective way of conveying such information.

If Docs.SO's example-focused topics are not designed to be able to fully convey the behavior of a system, then I would say that it has a poor design. You can't replace something that doesn't work with something else that *also* doesn't work.

---

> There are a couple misunderstandings here, which is understandable since few people can actually see Documentation yet. Topics have Examples, Topics are not necessarily small enough to be covered by one example; your OpenGL link is already logically a Topic best I can tell (I'm not an OpenGL expert).

OK, let's investigate that.

First, your own documentation seems to argue against the idea of multiple examples of importance. And I quote:

> If a Topic feels like it needs more than one Pinned Example, that's probably a sign that is should be broken up into multiple Topics.

So clearly there is intended to be a single, canonical example that exemplifies a topic. There can be subsidiary examples that perhaps fill in a few blanks. But there is clearly an intent for a "Topic" to be a thing that is small enough to be mostly encapsulated by a single, canonical, pinned example.

So there seems to be some disagreement between you and... you. Should a topic contain multiple examples of more-or-less equal standing that explain a topic? Or should it contain one major example, with a few minor ones to flesh out a couple of details?

If it's the former case, then pinning (and voting in general) seems like a misfeature.

But there's more to than that.

Regardless of the kind of documentation, the order in which information is presented is *absolutely crucial* in writing effective docs. Reference documentation will generally put the function signature first, because seeing parameter names/types will answer about 80% of questions that users would seek out reference documentation for.

If a topic is sufficiently large that it needs to have multiple examples in order to fully explore the breadth of it, then which ones come first is very important. But the problem is this:

There's no one right answer to that. Which ought to come first depends on the *audience*.

A beginner who found reference documentation will see a signature and be put off. Why? Because they have *no idea* what to do with that function. Whereas someone who's looking for syntax will see the signature and get what they need. Reference documentation is optimized for the latter, not the former.

So who is Docs.SO optimized for? And most importantly, who *decides* what it is optimized for?

Docs.SO has two means of controlling the order of examples: pinning of examples and voting on them.

Pinning is, according to your document, something that the creator of the topic has complete control over. Nobody can override such a person's judgment.

Which means that the person who has overriding control over who the audience for a topic is will be the creator of the topic. That seems... wrongheaded.

Non-pinned examples will be shown in order of their vote totals. Which means that the decision of who a topic serves best will be decided by voting. Except that people won't vote in that way. They will vote based on whether they like an example, not whether it serves some expected audience.

This means that Docs.SO has no means of deciding how to best present information for a particular intended audience.

That's bad.

Comment: "most important ... ideally copy/paste-able"  Yuck.  I kind of regret requesting an invite now.

Comment: Hate to state the obvious, but... This is why it's still in beta. *Private* beta. Until enough folks with different needs get a crack at using it, we're really not gonna have a solid idea of what's needed or missing. The OpenGL example (kudos, btw) would hardly be better served by MSDN / JavaDoc style docs, and yet I've *seen* and *suffered* through such a thing; this is a different approach, and only time - and use - will tell if it's viable.

Comment: @Shog9: OK, but... what *is* the approach? I don't understand the approach. Even the example given for `Query` was so thin it was transparent. It offered *nothing* over MSDN/JavaDoc/Doxygen. To put it another way, what is the mission statement? SO had clear guidance from the beginning: use Q&A to build a knowledge base. What's the guidance for Documentation.SE?

Comment: If the goal is to make documentation that is better than MSDN/JavaDoc/Doxygen, then it seems the focus on examples is just the wrong way to fix the problem. The problems with such documentation is typically that they lack some information, that they're not comprehensive enough. It has never been "there weren't enough examples".

Comment: The goal is very much *not* to make a better JavaDoc than JavaDoc; there are already plenty of efforts toward that end. The rough philosophy here (and I'm probably butchering Kevin's vision, but...) boils down to, "a *practical* example is worth 1000 words of explanation". IOW, MSDN and such are typically *full* of examples... of things that no one would ever actually do, or at least, do in the way being illustrated. They're the Monty Python Dirty Hungarian Phrasebooks of documentation. SODocs is attempting to approach this from the other direction.

Comment: @Shog9: "*a practical example is worth 1000 words of explanation*" OK, but what about APIs that, as I just explained, do not lend themselves to "practical examples"? And what about the `Query` example, where the "practical example" was garbage and basically told you nothing about the complexities of a database query? At the end of the day, I simply do not buy into this philosophy of documentation. I've seen *far* too many programmers who think they know something about a function call thanks to copy-and-pasting "practical examples". It's like giving a child a shotgun.

Comment: The truth of the matter is, those programmers aren't reading good documentation today, @Nicol. They're reading Stack Overflow. So what's the solution to that?

Comment: @Shog9: "*those programmers aren't reading good documentation today*" So you're saying that every tutorial on the Internet sucks, but that *your* tutorial will be fine? That's what we're talking about. Example-based documentation is *tutorial* documentation. I don't buy that Stack Overflow is some salve that magically turns bad ideas into good ones. If people are failing to learn properly from tutorials, and have been doing so consistently for years, then the problem is with *tutorials* as a concept. And the form of Docs.SO you are describing is simply tutorials minus the explanation.

Comment: @Shog9: Also, if examples are so good at explaining things, then show a *good* example of Docs.SO working.

Comment: @NicolBolas Well said. Copy/paste is never a good way to transit knowledge. Technologies similar to [jQuery] would fit there; however, a framework like [jQuery-Mobile] wouldn't fit. It will require endless lines of explanation, that is in case it is used alone. Integrating it with another technology, e.g. [PHP] or rails, is completely a different story. Having a _wiki_ for each tag and maintain it by experts of that tag could be an alternative for SO docs.

Comment: Another point, will docs cover current and previous versions? When a new version is released, which deprecates some function in successor version, what would happen? Remove "old docs/examples"?

Comment: @Omar: Versioning are actually something the Google Docs document talks quite a bit about. It's reasonably well supported.

Comment: Very nice answer. I always imagined code examples would be purely optional for documentation and only be at places where people actually wish for one. It seems SO-Documentation goes another way. Well, we'll see soon.

Comment: I refuse to believe that SO Documentation boils down to "monkey see, monkey paste." That's not documentation, that's [ActiveState](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/). This can't possibly be so ill-conceived.

Comment: Exactly this is why I stopped contributing after writing a couple of examples. I wanted to create HTTP documentation. I can show examples for all C# HTTP clients and servers from the Base Class Library, but if you know which function to call, you can look at MSDN for syntax and examples. I wanted to translate the various RFCs and (un)documented caveats of HTTP into human-readable form; but "HTTP headers" is not a "topic" in the C# section within the scope of the site. It is a cross-language, cross-platform endeavour which currently has no place there. Same for "files", "databases" and so on.

Comment: There are a couple misunderstandings here, which is understandable since few people can actually see Documentation yet.  Topics have Examples, Topics are _not_ necessarily small enough to be covered by _one example_; your OpenGL link is already logically a Topic best I can tell (I'm not an OpenGL expert).

Comment: Examples aren't just code (they're full-markdown blocks, like Answers), and the "succinct, self-contained, copy/paste-able"-guideline is roughly inline with Q&A; code should "work," though that doesn't necessarily mean "compile and run without modification".  It is just a guideline (and one I think ought to be rephrased now, based on this discussion), for some topics or examples it won't be necessary.

Comment: @CodeCaster There's no place for those on the beta site, because those tags don't exist (it'd be a bit nuts to try and test 1,000+ tags w/ only a few hundred beta participants after all).  They _do_ exist on Stack Overflow though, so there'll be a place for them eventually.

Comment: @Kevin there's more to it than just tags. Hierarchies, cross-subject linking and inclusion, example-less wikis that do link to language-specific examples, and so on. This needs to be built into the system and enforced to not let the documentation grow wild. I've been meaning to write more about this, but haven't gotten around to doing it yet. And maybe "topics" now are already more like that as well, then you can ignore what I wrote. :P

Comment: @CodeCaster: Hierarchies are unnecessary, but cross-subject linking/inclusion is absolutely critical.

Comment: @KevinMontrose: I don't understand. You claim that "it is just a guideline", but it's literally the ***first thing*** you learn in "The Tour" section of the document. It's the first time that document actually tries to explain how Docs.SO *works*. If "examples are worth a thousand words", then I would say that you have disproven that by horribly miscommunicating the meaning of the site through your example *and* your description of it. So how does the site work?

Comment: @KevinMontrose: "*Topics have Examples, Topics are not necessarily small enough to be covered by one example*" Let's pretend that's reasonable. What about topics which cannot be explained by example? For instance, the very first section of the Vertex Shader page on the wiki talks about invocation frequency. That cannot be explained by an example because it varies from implementation to implementation. That is in fact *the whole point* of that section: it varies. How do you deal with that?

Comment: @NicolBolas why are you trying to copy/paste that section?  What purpose would that serve?  The very first section on the Vertex Shader page probably isn't a whole Topic unto itself (it's not a page onto itself on that wiki either) - but what does that matter, nothing says it should be?  At this point, I think you're just going to have to wait and see it in action - as you've latched onto a particular vision that doesn't quite match reality I think.

Comment: @KevinMontrose: "*why are you trying to copy/paste that section?*" I'm trying to see how that section would be incorporated into Docs.SO. And my point is that you can't just say "here's some code, figure out what it means" the way Docs.SO seems to want to work. You cannot write code that demonstrates the information in that section. You cannot provide an example for it. So how do you document that ***very important*** information in Docs.SO?

Comment: @KevinMontrose: "*as you've latched onto a particular vision that doesn't quite match reality I think.*" I've latched onto nothing. I'm simply using *your description* of the site to try to understand it. It's not my fault if your description of the site doesn't match reality. It is a poor teacher who blames the student for not understanding. And a very bad trait for someone who wants to write a documentation site.

Comment: Nicol, I *am* in the beta, and your remarks match my concerns. I posted a question (that you can't see) entitled "What about 'why'?", where the only (non-official) answer I got was pretty much "we should just focus on the 'how'". I find this frustrating because I would like documentation to communicate *understanding*, not just *information*. Code examples are the first class citizens for the moment. It all seems to be based on the premise that most users will read code, but not prose. Unfortunately, this is probably true.

Comment: So @Kevin, I think what I'm asking for is [here](http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/documentation), where you can currently choose between for example C#, Java and .NET, we need a few cross-cutting root-level categories, such as "Networking", "Files", "Databases", "Graphics", and so on. Those are platform- and language-independent, and _are_ needed to link to (and include from) from language-specific docs, in order to not repeat oneself and collaboratively improve it. I see such topics become more Wiki-like, with less code (or pseudo) but more explanation of principles - aimed at developers.

Comment: "_Pinning is, according to your document, something that the creator of the topic has complete control over. Nobody can override such a person's judgment._". This is not really correct. Anyone can change which example is pinned through an edit.

Comment: @JonasCz: No, they can change the *content* of a pinned example, not "which example is pinned". Like modifying the object by pointer; that doesn't change the actual pointer value itself.

Comment: No, anyone can change which example is pinned - it's _not_ just the initial creator of the topic who can decide. I'm not sure where you got that, but it isn't true. I'm in the beta BTW.

Comment: I'm not sure about others, but the versioning issue for me is stuff like mysql-5.5 vs mysql-5.6. The non-version-specific documentation will be useless at the point when you **need** to know the exact version to determine whether something will work.

Comment: @NicolBolas you should give docs more of a chance. So far I feel you've contributed nothing but negative comments for something that is **at least a solid attempt** at unifying sparse documentation laid out in various formats everywhere throughout the web.

Comment: @DerreckDean: So we should accept a bad idea (tutorials-as-documentation) just because it's "at least a solid attempt" to improve things? It's not that I didn't give Docs.SO a chance. I reserved judgement until they actually explained what kind of documentation they were trying to build. Now that they have explained it, it's clear to me that, for many kinds of subjects, it simply will not be effective.

Comment: @NicolBolas it may not be perfect but so far it sounds better than what similar tools that are already available, not to mention that you complained about what was wrong without giving a solid foundation on how to make it work. My $0.02. They're at least trying, what are you doing?

Comment: @DerreckDean: "*it may not be perfect but so far it sounds better than what similar tools that are already available*" Really? A random bunch of tutorials, with neither explanation nor proper ordering of information, sounds better than what already exists? Quite frankly, you could learn more about OpenGL from the horribly outdated NeHe tutorials than what Docs.SO would provide. "*without giving a solid foundation on how to make it work*" ... so? You may not know the right way to get from New York to Los Angeles, but you can know that taking a flight to England isn't it.

Comment: @Shog9 and NicolBolas: "Also, if examples are so good at explaining things, then show a good example of Docs.SO working." - [Found a great one!  You can even search for the particular example you want!](http://stackoverflow.com/) =D

Comment: I get the feeling that Docs.SO is more aimed at beginners than beginners and professionals like SO. You're right that just giving an example never explains the full complexity of the topic, but for a beginner that may not always be needed. I started programming by hacking together things from code snippets I found all over the internet, understanding more and more about the language and programming in general step by step.

Comment: Some people may argue that this is a rather bad way of programming, which is true for professionals, but less important for hobbyists. It's the thrill of making something, letting my computer do a cool thing, that got me into computer science, which I'm studying now. There are already lots of beginners asking \*insert non-offending word for stupid\* questions here. A place with good examples the whole community agrees on can contribute a lot to SO as a whole by providing one place to redirect basic questions to.

Comment: Besides that it also provides easy to find examples you kind of know are good. 
While writing this comment I realised that what I'm describing isn't a full documentation, but more an "one stop find all" website for beginners.. Which may not be the original intention of docs

Comment: @NicolBolas Since I've seen you contributing to Docs, has your stance changed?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: No. I have yet to see how the example-focused documentation can be applied to topics that don't lend themselves to examples. Now, we can *pretend* to do so by just writing text. But that just means you're stuck with the topic&example nature of the system which doesn't really help make that kind of documentation better. I can still do better on MediaWiki than I can here, since it's more freeform and a lot less rigid.

Answer (score 67):

> ### Reputation System
>
> There are lots of little details, but the TL;DR is:
>
> [image]

The Google Doc expands on this:

> - Upvotes on Answer that cite Documentation you have contributed to **(+5)**

I don't like this. This will cause two large problems:

1. Users who only care about reputation will only contribute to the popular Documentation pages and ignore the rest.
2. Users who don't need a reputation incentive (who are probably the ones you want contributing to the Documentation site) will lose out because compared to those users they'll be the ones writing the less-popular Documentation pages which are barely ever linked to.

I'm looking forward to having the opportunity to contribute to the Documentation site, but I don't need any reputation incentive to do so. I'd also much rather know that the people who have contributed have done so out of a passion for whatever it is they've written about, not because they can get a pretty green +5 every so often.

Comment: Alas - but the same can be said on vampire-feeders on SO. This has been discussed over and over, but there is no good solution. I think the same goes for your (admittedly, slightly worrying) argument. Unless there is some max on how much rep can be gained from a single topic, maybe?

Comment: How is that a problem, exactly? Users in group (1) will be disinclined to mess up less popular documentation (while any harm they do to more popular docs is sure to be noticed), and users in group (2) by definition *don't care*. (For the record, I was in group (1) for a while --- and I *think* I did more good than harm.... --- but then I saw the light.)

Comment: How about changing the reputation awards to some badges award, and add some ranking system like the `Review` page.

Comment: One nuance loss here, you can only get Reputation _once_ for a (Topic|Example)+Answer pair.  The "optimum" behavior if you're chasing rep is to contriubte to often-cited docs... which is pretty OK I think.  There are "minimum substantive changes"-checks, and all changes go through a review process, so it's a pretty high bar to get into those docs.

Comment: Total reputation potential in a [tag] is proportional to activity in that [tag], by design.  That's true on Q&A and will be true in Documentation.  The idea being that you get rep for helping people with real problems, so naturally the most rep will be available from the places people are experiencing the most issues.

Comment: I'm confused, is point 2 really that "High rep users don't care about rep but will miss out on not getting rep"?

Comment: @KevinMontrose I don't think that theory will hold in the long run. After a point a topic will be pretty much as completely explained as it will ever be. There's only so much you can say about `Hello World` before you're just repeating yourself. Newer topics will always be the ones getting the most edit activity because they're new.

Comment: On the bright side, Doc.se can act as a honeypot for both vampires and feeders. Just not very useful for the rest of us.

Comment: It's not reputation which is the incentive, it's validation from other programmers which is the incentive. If you're able to validate your own actions without input from others, then that's a blessing. There's no need to ruin other peoples' incentive though. There's no need to be jealous.

Answer (score 31):

My personal hope for SO Documentation is that SO is giving us a bag of spanners, and letting us have the say of how we use them to build a documentation site. So while example based documentation is clearly important in the beta version of documentation, once it actually goes public and the community can start having a say about what it does / doesn't like then we start figuring out what to do with it.

Just to continue the example conversation a little, I think that example based documentation is very important, and will very likely be the first page that most people arrive at from a search engine.

But behind that example, there needs to be solid documentation about the theory and concept of what is going on in the examples. Someone picking up an example needs to be able to go deeper with it. Otherwise it is just another box full of examples with a complete lack of depth, and the internet has got plenty of those already.

I think this will be the part that the community will begin to shape once it is launched. It should become a very interesting conversation about what good documentation really is, and how we can achieve it as a community.

and for as much as I'm looking forward to what SO Documentation might become, I'm looking forward to that conversation a lot more, because I don't think it has ever been had before. I think a lot of people have made a career out of saying what good documentation is.  I'm not sure that ever made it so though...

Comment: Couldn't agree more. Code examples are great for syntax/usage of a method, algorithms, etc... But that's dealing with the minutiae and implementation. We should also try to document the concepts / philosophy behind the system/framework/language's design. That's where an awful lot of the valuable knowledge lies. Finally, I don't believe someone who already struggles to find a code snippet via Google is likely to find SO Docs any more easily, so question the value of prioritising snippets.

Comment: @Basic One of the first programming books I ever read (It might have been kernighan and ritchie c book - or not!) but it had a lot of anecdotes of 'we implemented it this way because doing it that way broke something else' I understood that language far better than any other I've learnt because I understood the reasons for the language choices and not just x keyword comes after y keyword. While we might not be able to add that sort of insight, giving the language some depth would make SO Docs standout, and be the place that is sought out when doing something new.

Answer (score 15):

**Why I support documentation**

I'm still supportive of Documentation. Explanation and examples are hugely important for understanding an API. As Stack Overflow currently stands, asking for a basic example for some task or API is likely to be closed or at least downvoted, even though these kind of examples would be helpful to many people. Documentation fills that void.

**Complex topics**

@NicolBolas talked about a kind of documentation that does not fit well into the current structure. I'm sure there are a number of complex topics that would be difficult to provide simple examples for. And maybe there needs to be some adjustment of the structure to accommodate these topics. However, I would say that for the vast majority of documentation topics, it is possible to provide several basic examples that illustrate how to do the topic in question.

**The +5 Reputation for upvoted answers citing the documentation**

I tend to agree with @JamesDonnelly that the +5 is not good, but not because I think people should just do it for free. Awarding reputation is helpful for soliciting more examples. This fits with the general structure of Stack Exchange. However, giving everyone who contributed a documentation topic +5 every time an answer linking to it gets upvoted is excessive. I can easily imagine 50 or 100 answers linking to a major documentation topic. If those answers are themselves high traffic, then that would translate to a huge reputation points gain every day just for contributing to a single topic. This seems a little disproportionate compared to the Stack Overflow method of gaining reputation points.

I recommend dropping the +5 and keeping the +10 for upvoted examples.

**Organizational structure**

I'd like to see more organizational (hierarchical) structure to the documentation, similar to how most official API documentation is laid out. This would provide an intuitive and logical way to find the topic you need. It would also naturally prevent a lot of duplicate topics.

[I've written about this before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315160/more-hierarchical-structure-needed-for-documentation-topics), but I didn't get much response.

Comment: Let's take [this answer of yours from SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29797229/734069) for an example of the problem here. That answer would actually be multiple independent examples. And yet, the introductory paragraph (which is prose text, not an example) needs to be the *very first thing* that a user sees when searching for the topic of "prepared statements". But your answer is not the accepted one. So most people will see the code-dump answer first, denying them vital information about prepared statements. Docs.SO seems to *promote* this kind of thing, not prevent it.

Comment: "asking for a basic example for some task or API is likely to be closed or at least downvoted, even though these kind of examples would be helpful to many people. Documentation fills that void."  This is nonsense, SO documentation can never be _the_ manual. If someone is asking questions about the Windows API, you would give the canonical page on MSDN. If someone is asking questions about the Linux API, you refer to the relevant "man page". And so on. This is the problem, the SO documentation can never be canonical, it can't be the manual. Unless you suggest copy/paste whole API docs into SO..