# Educated badge?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, badge-progress

I recently see this badge **'educated' : 'Read the documentation tour'**

Can someone explain me what is it?

It  seems to be **similar to the 'informed' badge**, but I didn't found information about this new one.

I just see it in my stackoverflow profile when I decided to choose which badge to track....

[image]

Comment: Probably for the docs: https://docs-beta.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hmmm... Have to be invited to see what is it or wait the end of tests.... Thank you Mr !

Comment: If I click on "go get it" it shows me this link: http://stackoverflow.com/tour/documentation

Comment: @Rizier123 'Page not found' for me....

Comment: As I said it has probably something to do with the docs. If I click on the badge and then on "go get it" I just get redirect to that page. I also get "not found"

Comment: I'm retagging this as a bug because I doubt it's supposed to be showing in that list right now, and it's not listed on any other badge pages.

Comment: @animuson *Maybe it's a feature and not a bug?*

Comment: On Meta StackExchange: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277958/what-is-the-educated-badge

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a forthcoming badge for [Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319319/documentation-the-update-en-ing) - it wasn't meant to be enabled just yet.

A build will soon disable this badge until Documentation is live on a given site.  However, if you've chosen to track this badge, you'll need to choose a different one manually, because I'm too lazy* to remove your choice :P

Good eyes finding it, though!

<sup>* or too scared to run updates on production databases.</sup>