# Update on when Documentation is launching

Tags: discussion, support, documentation

According to Adam Lear, it was initially planned to launch in end of March or early April. However, it is already mid-April. 
*Source: [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27669760#27669760)*

> Current plan is to "end of March/early April"

Also, in [Documentation: The Update-en-ing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319319/documentation-the-update-en-ing), it's stated that it will continue for a bit.

> The beta itself will continue for a bit after so those last few signups can get invited. Documentation won’t be going live on Stack Overflow on April 1st or anything like that.

Any updates on **when Documentation is launching**?

---

Also, I've signed up for Documentation for [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) and [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) in January but haven't got invited.

I know that everyone who signed up will eventually get an invite, but it's already past the planned launch date. 
*Source: [Documentation: The Update-en-ing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319319/documentation-the-update-en-ing)*

> If you signed up but haven’t been invited yet, don’t worry - everyone who signs up will eventually get an invite.

## Update: I'm invited!

What's the **percentage of users invited already**?

Comment: The post you link to explicitly states *"The beta itself will continue for a bit after so those last few signups can get invited. Documentation won’t be going live on Stack Overflow on April 1st or anything like that."*

Comment: Give it 6-8 weeks. ;)

Comment: They're still sending out invites. I just got mine today. Hang in there!

Comment: @jkdev Just checked my inbox and found out that I was invited 3h ago, thanks :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Adam sure was optimistic! There are still a few moving parts that need to be locked into place before launch—not the least of which is inviting the remaining users into the private beta. I do see you're on the list (um, several times, actually), so you will get an invitation soon.

I'm not going to get your hopes up about a launch date, but I will say the smart money is on an April date. To paraphrase the [old proverb](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/April_showers_bring_May_flowers):

> April beta launches
>     Bring May bug fixes.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Hope to get an invite soon :)

Comment: "Adam sure was optimistic!" -- a moment of weakness, nothing more, I assure you.