# Stack Overflow tutorials?

Tags: discussion

I've recently been trying to learn some [Scala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_%28programming_language%29). When I went to the [Scala tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info), I noticed that some very nice person had made an entire tutorial based on Stack Overflow questions.

So far, this has been immensely helpful toward me. Answers are much more concise and quicker to access than looking through a book or website. To my dismay, all the other language tags such as Java, C++, Python, etc. don't have something like this, mostly just links to other tutorials and books.

Could we make a tutorial like this for all language tags?

Comment: Stack Overflow Documentation is currently in private beta. It's not exactly the same thing as that tag wiki, but will hopefully fill a similar role. It should be available to the public within the next couple months. See [this announcement in August](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303865/1114), [this update in September](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306213/1114), and [this update last month](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319319/1114) for info.