# How can I register to the private beta of Documentation?

Tags: discussion, support, documentation

I searched/read many posts regarding the Documentation.

I found out that is still on private beta. Does anyone knows how can I join the private beta of Documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly confident that [you've missed the window on this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319319/1079354).

> Of course if you want firsthand experience...
>
> ## Sign up for the Documentation Beta
>
> ...by March 31st 2016.

Comment: I guess you are right. I am updating my question.

Comment: I'm a bit confused @jsurf...what do you intend to gain from updating the question?

Comment: Well if its not necessary, I won't update it.

Comment: You could probably just wait and see if someone from SE weighs in.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @RobertHarvey

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you can't join Documentation Beta now as you've missed the deadline:

> Of course if you want firsthand experience...
>
> ## Sign up for the Documentation Beta
>
> ...by March 31st 2016.

---

Also, there was a similar question asked in Documentation Beta, http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/is-it-still-possible-to-join-the-private-beta:

[image: Screenshot]

(Screenshot for those not in Documentation Beta)