# Difference between Python Virtualenv and Python embeddable considered off-topic

Tags: discussion, scope

There are two similar (and partly overlapping) Python libraries/technologies: Python [Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/) and Python embeddable. So I am asking for the technical differences between the two and for a link to the official documentation of the latter (which is not readily available on the Python.org).

Can you please, help me understand how/where this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37633550/1851270) asks

> to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic?

Nowhere I ask to recommend  a library, a tool or the likes.

You might argue that I can only ask differences about commands and code patterns and not *differences about libraries, tools, or technologies*.
So I wrote "What is the difference" in the search box and, just in the first page, I get a number of questions, considered legitimate, asking what is the difference between:

- Bower/npm;
- Mercurial/Git;
- URI/URL/URN;
- JDK/JRE;
- Cygwin/MinGW.

So, why not Python Virtualenv/Embeddable?

P.S.
Only this difference between [sed and awk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1632113/1851270) has been discarded and for a good reason: not because off-topic, but since it is "too broad", in fact the tools are too different to attempt a comparison.

To make me even more clueless is the fact that off-topic questions normally have  "this question belongs to..." comments, which in this case are missing and which let me think that the question  was dismissed a bit in hurry by moderators.

### Edit

Given your feedback I am going to *remove the documentation* request and give some evidences that mentioned differences are everything but broad.

Let me me note, anyway, that I thought a little, before my request for documentation and, since nothing is said on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), I applied what is said on [unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> [R]equests for learning materials (tutorials, how-tos etc.) are off topic. The only exception is questions about where to find official documentation (e.g. POSIX specifications).

I think this rule makes a lot of sense, of course when the docs/specs are somehow missing or their location is not self-evident.
In this particular case the [zipped distro](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.1/python-3.5.1-embed-amd64.zip) comes with not even a readme (!) and the [download page](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows) on Python.org just lists it among the downloads.

Comment: There's a request for an off-site resource: `where is the official documentation concerning scope and usage for this distribution?` It doesn't get much more off-site than that. The second question might be too broad, but I don't have any knowledge of that tech so I can't tell. Often, asking "what is the difference between library foo and library bar" can be too broad as there's many differences and it's unclear which ones the question is interested about.

Comment: I vtc'd the question as too broad, As it was too broad (More than one concrete question). (Unfortunately 4 others closed it as a resource request, My [name's not there in the last list](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KgW1G.png)). The question was well framed, So I did upvote it. That said, I guess the other reviewers went for the resource-request because of the statement - ***where is the official documentation** concerning scope and usage for this distribution?*. IMO, it is *not* a resource req. If the  question is narrowed down to a single good question, Then I certainly will vote to reopen it.

Comment: @BhargavRao Followed your advice. Removed the doc part (but see the new meta here) and focused on differences between Python Virtualenv and embeddable with code examples.

Comment: @Kyll: For the docs see the new meta. As for the "too broad differences", I  edited the question, posting some code which generates the same functional output  both using Python Virtualenv and embeddable.

Answer (score 4):

That close reason was intended for ["Shopping Questions".](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) If you look at the list of examples in that blog post, the first one is:

> - Macbook Air vs. Macbook Pro?

That's very similar to what you were asking:

> - how does it compare with the isolated Python environments generated by virtualenv package, if it makes sense to compare them at all?

I don't know if it should qualify as a shopping question, but it definitely may appear that way to some people.

---

The other part is you asked specifically for us to find you an external resource, the documentation:

> - where is the official documentation concerning scope and usage for this distribution?

The reason we want to prevent this type of question is because it promotes answers like this:

> You can find your answer [HERE!!!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370)

Comment: You're taking a very strict reading of the guidelines and comparing it with slivers of the entire context.

Comment: @Makoto I have clarified my answer. I was merely mentioning the similarity for the first part. The second part about link only answers is not a "strict interpretation", it's well defined between the LQRQ and the close reasons.

Comment: @Makoto: I think that the  official documentation is a very different case from other off-site resources. Please, see my edit meta for policy used by unix.stackexchange. Apart from this, I added some code examples which generate the same functional output starting first from Virtualenv and then Python embeddable. This is not strictly necessary for a fluent Python user, but might convince others about the strict similiraties of the two approach an the interests in the differences  (and some moderators seem to have more of a Java background). so, if proper effort has been done, please reopen.

Comment: @antonio:  Did you mean to direct that at Laurel?  (They've been pinged, by the way.)

Comment: @antonio If you feel that you have a case for that, you should make a separate meta post.

Comment: @Laurel:  I am realising there is perhaps a documentation problem. There should not be, because  official docs missing is different from a generic request for a tutorial, but people might be very strict and so, yes, it can be the case for a spec for the missing specs.

Comment: @antonio [Is there now?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319319)

Comment: @yes, Makamoto, but thought that you might be interested too.

Comment: @Laurel: thanks, I didn't know about this project. It is a huge project and still in private beta.

Comment: @antonio I wish I could tell you when it was getting out of private beta, but I don't know.