# What is the scope of a topic?

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-topics

I recently [reviewed a proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/20246?draftId=18600) for a new topic. In this case, the user wanted to make a topic dedicated to the singleton pattern under the JavaScript section.

I suggested that the user create a single topic for design patterns and showcase the singleton pattern there. My thinking is that all of the design patterns should be in one place. If the user is looking for a specific pattern, it would show up there but if a user wanted to understand more about how design patterns are implemented in JavaScript they could review the whole topic. Perhaps that's just my opinion and not the opinion of the community at large.

Since Documentation is still very new, I'm not aware of an official stance on this sort of thing. So what's the scope of a given topic? Should individual aspects of a concept get their own "topic" or should the concept act as an umbrella for the individual aspects of that concept?

Comment: [Related, although this is really asking the same kind of thing...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306224/1079354)

Comment: For the record (on this specific issue), there's a http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/design-patterns/topics dedicated tag for that. Move it there.

Comment: @bwoebi Awesome, I didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: I saw an 85K rep user propose a topic for HTML `<label>` element, so someone created it. Seems like you have to consider Documentation as being like the *"wild wild west"* of SO

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We're still figuring this out, so take my statements with a grain of salt.

I'd approach the problem from the perspective of how big the resulting topics will be.  It's reasonable for there to be one "Design Patterns" topic if it'll have about 6 examples.  Six is somewhat arbitrary, but I think it's reasonable guess for how many examples a individual could consume in one "sitting".  If there are (or you strongly believe there will be) more than that, I'd suggest breaking up the topic and cross linking (the remarks section is great for cross linking related topics).

I suspect we'll grow more rules of thumb as beta proceeds, but for now I think best one available is "would a reasonable person be motivated to read the whole Topic, with this structure."  Design for consumers, not exhaustion.

Comment: What happened here is that the topics about design patterns got grouped by a new tag. While this worked well to create a hierachy, it lost a bit the connection to a specific language like Java. The question is then if the examples in the design pattern tag should be multi-lingual or language agnostic and if additionally there should be examples of design patterns in the Java tag or not and how much linking between the two should be then? I wonder what is the best in this case here?

Comment: Would it be reasonable to have a top-level topic called "Design Patterns", with minimal examples of different design patterns, and then individual topics for design patterns that merit further examples/information?