# Add export features to Documentation

Tags: feature-request, documentation

Stack Overflow Documentation (beta) is a great step towards a future programmers' wiki. So, for an offline reference, is there a way to export the documentation on a specific topics/tags and save it locally?

If not, please add this feature.

Comment: File -> Print -> PDF Printer?

Comment: @codecaster Something similer to LinkedIn Profile Export.

Comment: You say that like everyone should know what that is.

Comment: Presumably some form of API will come in time.

Comment: @AndyHayden Thanks for the Positive reply.

Comment: Can you clarify what LinkedIn Profile Export does?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Actually it exports user's bio data (say C.V) in well structured manner as a pdf file.

Comment: FYI  [Downloading Documentation dump](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332366/395857)

Comment: @CodeCaster currently the PDF printer would not expand the subsections in documentation page, e.g. exasmples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kevin mentioned [way back when](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306213/1438):

> #### What about offline reference?
>
> It came up a couple of times, but this one’s easy to answer: we’ll have print stylesheets, and Documentation will make its way into data dumps and the API eventually.

That's still coming, but we need to be sure that we are comfortable with the system first.