# Can we download docs from Stack Overflow documentation?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation

Is there any way we can download docs from Stack Overflow documentation? It would be helpful if we can download them either as .pdf or as .docx file. What do you think?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329108/2675154

Comment: In the future, yes (search "offline reference"): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306213

Comment: Once available, you will be able to obtain it as part of the data dumps : https://archive.org/details/stackexchange  . From that, you can rebuild it into whatever form you desire.  Consider the magnitude of a `pdf` file which would include documentation of syntax, etc for all languages included.  I don't for-see this as being a viable way to distribute big data. You are better off storing as a collection of objects and retrieving by relevance in some form of NoSQL object storage solution.

Comment: I think I would probably prefer the documentation in a [`.doc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doc_(computing)) file instead a [`.docx`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) ;-)

Comment: I would prefer not using any dox* format, if at all...

Comment: Did you find anything on Documentation worth downloading? :-P

Comment: @Squidward I feel it's difficult for someone to go through entire page. If Stack Overflow doesn't allow us to download, At least it should look like a blog post and that would be nice in readability perspective.

Comment: @RajKarri You can switch to single-pane mode and expand all examples. It takes two clicks, but the topic starts looking like a blog post.

Comment: @Squidward will take a look..thx!