# How do moderators fit into documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation, moderators, moderator-tools

<sup>*(they get folded in half until they fit?)*</sup>

---

In Q&A, moderators have active participation in the content of the site - whether it be locking posts, admonishing those that refuse to follow the community rules and being general human exception handlers.

In Documentation <sup>Beta<sup>TM</sup></sup> I can forsee things like edit wars and things being approved for updating examples that probably shouldn't be etc... In these kind of scenarios, do moderators have the same tools available?

For example, we see posts locked because of their historic value on the main site - in 12 months if people start updating examples to get rid of depreciated methods - should/can they be locked by a moderator until an outcome is agreed on meta as to whether the depreciated methods hold historic value?

I think the *community* aspect of docs has naturally been talked about a lot, but I'm not 100% sure where the moderators fit into the picture in terms of the content.

Comment: SE employees like animuson and adamlear appear to make an effort.  Beta and all, that's not a bad idea.  I suspect they'll eventually call upon the SO mods to volunteer.  Just give it time to get sorted out.

Comment: @HansPassant I hope my question hasn't come across as a rant - I'm not for one minute suggesting that there is a lack of mod presence or anything of the kind. It's purely out of curiousity as the moderator role has been moulded around the Q&A model, but I'm not sure how that looks in Docs which isn't the same kind of model so I'm wondering if it will be moderated in the same way that SO is. Does that make sense? Perhaps I could re-word?

Comment: I asked something similar here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306219/19679

Comment: @BradLarson I'd say it's the same except you seem to have asked it far more succinctly than I have/ever could! I'd normally close my post but I'm even more curious now to see if it's the same kind of answer after the public beta.

Comment: *opens the question, reads the pun, laughs out loud*... ok +1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The story remains the same from [the original Docs announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306213/warlords-of-documentation-your-questions-answered/306219#comment248103_306219)

> [E]xisting Stack Overflow moderators will also be moderators for Documentation purposes. I'm hoping (Documentation's version of) review can be tuned to keep diamond-mod work pretty rare. We aren't planning to make drastic changes to the existing mod tools (which are Q&A focused), but rather to build new ones focused on Documentation as they are needed.

Now that we're on Stack Overflow, we're seeing actual moderation issues (the private beta had very few) - so we're buckling down on moderation tweaks and tooling.

Comment: Coolio - I shall wait and see what comes out of it then. I imagine docs is going to cause a lot of work for you guys anyway initially...

Answer (score 4):

Just as during the Q&A beta, moderation is being done by employees during Documentation's beta. Since moderators are [human exception handlers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/), moderator duties don't really exist while the system is in a state of flux. Our plan has always been [observe problems before solving them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306213/warlords-of-documentation-your-questions-answered/306219#comment248104_306219) and only then build the tools we need. As you might imagine, this is quickly becoming a priority as this thing doesn't seem to be dying on the vine.

That said, most of what people think of a moderation (such as the edit war scenario, perhaps) will eventually be put into the hands of high reputation users. There's a lot we can borrow from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Dispute_resolution) and, of course, the [existing system](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) of moderation. The first layer of that system was built in from the start: [proposed changes must through review](https://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-proposed-changes). It's had a rough start, but once the engine is well tuned, we can start considering how to handle routine maintenance and how to train mechanics.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Jon. It's good to see that there is a more flexible approach to the moderation side of docs rather than wedging the 'round' Q&A tools in the 'square' docs hole.