# Allow Documentation Topics to be Protected

Tags: feature-request, documentation

As @Knu suggested in chat, we should have a way to protect or lock a documentation topic such that it can only be edited by users with significant reputation. This will prevent people from making superficial edits to high-volume tags/topics just to get easy reputation.

This will help us maintain quality and reduce superficial edits. 2,500 reputation was suggested, and I support it!

Here's an example of a [superficial edit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/49485).

Comment: possibly related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329342/how-do-moderators-fit-into-documentation

Comment: In the meantime we could have a new reason to reject: **superficial**.

Comment: Yes! I like that. With a message like "Please review the rest of the document and see if other, more substantial improvements can be made."

Comment: Why would 2500 make a difference? Someone with 2500 may want to be at 100K and do same thing

Comment: Sure, but it shows that someone is fairly invested in the community.

Comment: MEanwhile, that superficial edit completely broke the markdown for that paragraph, due to incorrect use of `\``, instead of `'`. So I had to submit a superficial edit just to fix that.

Comment: Frankly, a mod should have a good word with the approver of that linked superficial edit. It's not only too minor, it's simply breaking the page.

Comment: @Cerbrus you don't immediately notice this in raw markdown view though. But I agree, too minor and not helping anything.

Comment: The fact he used that `\`` character (what's it even called?) should've been enough reason to reject it.

Comment: @Cerbrus backtick / accent grave

Comment: I am very concerned that if a "superficial edit" reject reason is added, it will be abused. The SE team did away with the "too minor" reasons for a reason.

Comment: Perhaps if edits < X characters didn't count toward rep...

Comment: @Will It also needs to include upvotes to the topic which was edited for that user unless he/she made more substantial edits to that topic.

Comment: The system already only rewards reputation for substantial edits.

Comment: @Will a one character edit in documentation could mean *a lot* in terms of if it's correct or not

Comment: @Lamak absolutely. I don't think we should base anything on character count alone.

Comment: I quite like the idea of starting to solidify topics as they mature. However, maybe a more appropriate threshold to edit a protected topic is to have a bronze or silver badge in the respective tag?

Answer (score 8):

I see four types of edits on Documentation:

1. Substantial edits which are constructive, and deserve upvotes and reputation gain.
   They mostly happen while the topic is new, and then get rarer over time.
2. Substantial edits which are destructive, and deserve downvotes, and [removal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329388/5743988).
   These can happen at any time in a topic's lifetime.
3. Superficial edits which improve the comprehension of the topic.
   These can happen at any time in a topic's lifetime.
4. Superficial edits which are made because they want a piece of the "reputation" pie.
   These mostly happen when the topic has lots of upvotes.

The system we have right now with reviewing edits is the best way to deal with the quality issues. One possible improvement though is to give highly upvoted posts an increased number of approval-votes to go through. This wouldn't "lock" the post, it would just have to endure higher-quality tests in order to be put through. This would discourage edits in group #2 & #4.

This won't stop people from trying to make superficial edits. We want those if they actually improve the post. What we don't want is for people to see superficial edits as the easiest way to earn reputation. **Currently, the system only gives reputation from upvotes to substantial edits**. This needs to be common knowledge if we're going to reduce the number of unnecessary superficial edits. It would be nice though to have [a way to manually remove an edit from the rep flow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329388/5743988).

Comment: My "4 types of edits" are generalizations of course. There are gray areas where substantial edits should be considered superficial. There doesn't currently seem to be an effective way of handling those.

Answer (score 1):

I keep hearing about reputation limits. Cannot understand the logic behind it:

1. Writing documentation is a bit different from answering questions. Documentation is a lot about structuring content and selecting simple enough examples that can still demonstrate the point. It's a different set of skills from answering user-specific questions.
2. Let's face it, answering questions on SO does not have strict correlation even with user's knowledge of the topic. There are guys who happened to answer some essential questions and now they're constantly upvoted. There are even more guys who just keep sitting here on SO and massively answer simple/duplicate/easily googled questions.
3. There are tons of people out there who know a lot about a topic **and** have an appropriate set of skills for creating it, who have very little rating on SO...

I don't think the problem you're seeing is because of many people with low rating. By now I saw several completely incorrect change proposals from people with "significant" rating. Including removing really useful material from the existing post, etc.

If you see a superficial edit, it's a flag for this particular user, but not a reason to close the topic from big part of the community. Also it is probably a signal to SO team to implement an automatic tip saying that your edit is not significant and it is not recommended etc.