# Why can't I commit to this documentation proposal?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, documentation

[castle-windsor Documentation Proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/castle-windsor/commit)

> Who can commit:
>
> Must have 150 reputation With at least 1 positively scored answer in
>   castle-windsor

I meet both the reputation requirement and the positively scored answer requirement (I have [4 such answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcastle-windsor%5D%20user%3A5101046%20is%3Aa%20score%3A1..)).

But when I press the Commit button the page refreshes and nothing else happens. The number of committed users remains at 2/5 instead of 3/5. (Although at this rate it's going to take approximately forever to reach 5/5.)

So how do I commit to this documentation proposal?

The same problem occurs when trying to commit on other tags. For example [coded-ui-tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coded-ui-tests). A comment against this question says the *"The tag itself also has to meet certain popularity restrictions at present (number of questions, not sure what else) and needs to have had a question asked in it within the last three days"*. Fair enough, don't allow commits under some conditions. However the bug is that the web page does not explain that the commit is disallowed or being ignored, the web page just refreshes. The web page should provide some message in response to the attempted commit

Comment: ["The tag itself also has to meet certain popularity restrictions at present (number of questions, not sure what else) and __needs to have had a question asked in it within the last three days__."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330419/can-i-document-my-own-library-on-stack-overflow-documentation/330441#comment377092_330420)

Comment: I can see the intent - the linked question involves whether people can document their own libraries. But there are over 2400 questions on Castle Windsor. A lot of questions are about DI in general and having docs to link to would be helpful. But in many cases the question has nothing to do with Castle Windsor - the *answer* does. That answer is the wrong place to post all the documentation on how to set up their project to use DI.

Comment: Great, finally someone asked a castle windsor question and I was able to commit.

Comment: This is seriously a problem. The things we're able to document right now are arguably not the things that Docs *is needed for most*. Why re-document C#, Java, or [insert well documented language here] when we could be *filling the void* that Docs is *supposed to be filling*?! The restrictions on which tags documentation can be created for needs to be seriously rethought.

Comment: Workaround - I'm just putting this under .NET/Dependency Injection. If there's ever a more specific category it can be moved.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying error here was a bit subtle.

Basically, you should have been able to commit because someone had successfully committed before.  The clientside check got that, but the serverside check was incorrect and failed in a way that didn't report much.

The fix will roll out in the next build.