# Would this question on optional typing be on-topic for SO?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have been going through the Julia docs; and found that it has a feature called optional typing.

But, as I am not from a CS background, I had to google and search on Quora, but haven't found any resources which I can really learn what it is.

So, would a question like "**What is optional typing**" (along with some details) be on-topic here?

Comment: This would be a good use case for [the new proposed Documentation feature](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow).

Comment: However, a quick search turned up [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078089/is-julia-dynamically-typed/28096079#28096079). Does that answer your question?

Comment: @TinyGiant Thank you for the link. So, if I understood correctly, optional typing is, as the word suggests, is a possibility of assigning types to the values in a dynamic programming language (but doing so is optional).

Am I right?

Comment: I'd imagine so. I have no experience with Julia specifically.

Comment: Hmm, Google has 17 million hits when you query "What is optional typing".  Hard to imagine you need one more.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm sorry, but there aren't any clear explanations in the top 2 search pages, so I had to post this question. Wikipedia gives me this: **In programming languages (especially functional programming languages) and type theory, an option type or maybe type is a polymorphic type that represents encapsulation of an optional value; e.g. it is used as the return type of functions which may or may not return a meaningful value when they are applied.** But, I'm not sure whether this answers my question.

Comment: @Dawny33 Of course a search for **What is julia "optional typing"** produces hits that are more relevant ...