# Are profile views on Stack Overflow positively correlated to the level of reputation points?

Tags: discussion, reputation, profile-page, statistics

As my reputation keeps increasing, I notice that more and more users come to see my profile (`538` users have seen my SO profile as of now).

So I was wondering: is there any way to demonstrate a possible correlation between the reputation points level and profile views and if so, which would this relationship be?

My first shot would be to give [SE Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) a try but I'm totally unfamiliar with it.

As I'm writing this question, I realize that the subscription date (and therefore the amount of time one has been on SO for) should also be taken into consideration.

Comment: Well Rep correlates with time as well, so are you sure it's not just linear growth of your views as you have more and more stuff on the website?

Comment: @Patrice so 3rd variable problem?

Comment: Also the variable of "Participates on SO Meta (Y/N)"

Comment: [I have no idea](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/369807#graph)...

Comment: I've always assumed it was more connected to activity. For instance, I am very active on Meta and have over 1k views on my meta profile. I'm not as active on SO, and only have 249 views over there. (I'm sure a number of them have come from Meta, to be honest.) Since my rep has grown very slowly, I've never so much as assumed that was the case. But consider: In general, the more active you are on SO, the more rep you're likely to get. If activity is in fact what drives profile views, it would be logical to think that rep drives this since rep is driven by activity. (Generally.)

Comment: Now I'm only interested in seeing the least-active user with the most profile views.

Comment: @rene [a slightly more readable version of your query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/369810#graph)  (I manually removed Jon Skeet and Eric Lippert as outliers).

Comment: I have noticed that women are likely to get more profile views, regardless of their rep. But in order for people to notice users by seeing their name/pic or something, said users need to be active, or have posted on high traffic questions

Comment: Keep in mind that there is often a sort of "Meta effect" that may create outliers. As in when someone posts something on meta along the lines of "Hey everyone, this user is doing something awful..."

Comment: The question should be: "is the _rate_ of increase of profile views (say profiles views gained per week) correlated with rep"?

Comment: @LuisMendo: I guess a number can be positively correlated with another number and it should implies that when one increases, the other increases as well, shouldn't it?

Comment: @D4V1D Yes, but that's a different question. My point is, it's more interesting to see if the _rate_ of increase of profile views is correlated with rep. Even if those two quantities were totally uncorrelated, there would be a correlation between total profile views an rep, caused simply by the passing of time and the fact that both profiles views and rep are _accumulated_ quantities (see Patrice's first comment)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[The Pearson coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient) of a series of (x,y) pairs can be represented as
`E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)) / (Stdev(X) * Stdev(Y))`. This formula can be easily represented in TSQL, and since the `users` table already contains the reputation and view counts, it's a [pretty straight forward query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/369882/reputation-views-pearson-coefficient).

As of today (September 30th, 2015), there's a pretty decent correlation between reputation and profile view - a Pearson coefficient of ~0.5671.

Comment: :( no graph? Just a boring number... Can you refresh my memory on stats: What would a lower / higher number mean over time?

Comment: Thanks for this nice answer! @rene: IIRC, `>0.5` means positive correlation and `<0.5` is negative correlation. But I might be wrong.

Comment: @rene `1` means there's a perfect positive correlation - an increase of x% in reputation should also see an increase of x% in views, and vise-versa. `-1` means there's a perfect negative correlation - an increase in reputation should see a decrease in views, and vise versa. 0 means there's absolutely no linear correlation. Anything in-between is an imperfect correlation. With real-world samples, a Pearson correlation with an absolute value of `>0.5` is pretty impressive.

Comment: it probably says that the older the profile the more reputation the account has (i.e., the older the profile the more views).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian probably so. It's important to note the the Pearson coefficient does not say anything about causation - just correlation (i.e., when one measure is observed to change, so is the other). I assume that both are caused by activity, more than profile age, but here too, you'd see a strong correlation between the two.

Comment: Maybe not really related but by reading this answer along with the Wikipedia page ,I just wonder why there is almost never a section that translates mathematical formulas to programming languages example (like in this case, SQL) that would be really helpful for programmers who are not proficient in reading math formulas but can understand code.you should add this implementation to the relevant wiki page. or better yet - Maybe it should be added to the [SE Documentation initiative](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow).

Comment: @ObmerkKronen - Until such things are available here, [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code) has a lot of algorithms/formulas in multiple languages.

Comment: I always wondered what the expected value of `abs(Pearson)` for random data is. Maybe with the standard deviation one can calculate the % chance that this is just a fluke.

Comment: @nwp: Maybe, I'm missing something but if X, Y are independent then `E(XY) == E(X)E(Y)` and therefore the coefficient is zero.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian `E(XY) == E(X)E(Y)` means that X and Y are uncorrolated, which by definition implies that they are independent. The opposite is not necessarily true - e.g., height and weight in infants are strongly correlated, but they aren't dependent - they are both products of age and nutrition.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian [These statistics](https://curiousmatic.com/9-curious-spurious-correlations-close-coincidence/) disagree. I think [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient#Use_the_exact_distribution) answers my question, not sure how exactly to apply it though.

Comment: @Mureinik: Are we talking about the same [definition of independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory))? (`P(AB) = P(A)P(B)`). See [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#Properties)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian thinking in the wrong language, apologies. If X and Y are independent, then, indeed, their Pearson coefficient will be 0.

Answer (score 33):

Because I like pretty pictures:

---

[image: Views By Creation Date]

<strike>If I cleaned out all the outliers, it would probably be better, but</strike>(*ed: see next graph*) clearly older profiles tend to have more views.

---

[image: Views by date outliers trimmed]

This graph removes those users who's profile views are outside a 2 sample standard deviation range of the ten users before and after them. The black line is a 255 sample moving average.

---

[image: Views By Reputation]

The black line is a 255 sample moving average.

---

[image: Views by Reputation Outliers Trimmed]

This chart is filtered similarly to the second chart above, but outlier detection is based on the 10 users immediately preceding.

---

Some notes about the data:

1. The datasets were acquired using SEDE, and the following users were manually removed from the dataset to reduce the number of outliers:

   - [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood)
   - [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)
   - [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert)
   - [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell)
   - [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant)
   - [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc)
   - [Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov)
   - [Bill the Lizard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard)
2. This is not exactly mathematically rigorous.
3. The outlier filtering in charts 2 & 4 is also not mathematically or statistically rigorous. A better filter would show the trends more effectively.
4. I didn't use log scale because it [makes a mess of things](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwV8p.png).

Comment: Nice graphs indeed. Thanks for answering!

Comment: "_Because I like pretty pictures_" --- well i happen to hate them-i like the ugly ones, they make me look good, now i look good :)

Comment: @Elltz because they have so much more reputation (or status, due to their function at so) the axis has to be adjusted for them, making it hard to see the data for the other 99.9999% of the users

Comment: @elltz To expand on what Tim said, Jon Skeet has so many more profile views than anyone else, that the graphs just look like a horizontal line with a spike.  I suppose I could have made the y-axis log scale, which would compress the vertical component, but that would also make it visually more difficult to see the correlation.

Comment: This should be a logarithmic plot.

Comment: @J... I added a link to the end to show why I didn't log plot.  The Views/Reputation is better, but I still prefer to avoid log scales among non-math or non-scientific crowds. Here's the [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/369881) I used to generate the data for the blue charts. Enjoy :)

Comment: Reading Elltz's comment, I thought they was asking why some people don't deserve to have a full name but others do?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It's not a sign of disrespect, as much as it's an acknowledgement that the graphs took most of my lunch break, and I was typing quickly. Anyone who's cruising around meta has been on the site for at least a couple minutes, and should know who the first three are. That said, I'll update the answer to add in their first names.

Answer (score 9):

I have done some analysis for this at: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/376361/how-to-find-the-sample-points-that-have-statistically-meaningful-large-outlier-r

Here is a plot that clearly shows that there is a positive correlation between both.

I have also looked into the selected apparent outliers to try and understand why they are outliers in that post.

[image].

Comment: Thanks. Very convincing chart.

Comment: How you checked to see if it corrates with number of posts better?

Comment: @IanRingrose nope!