# Where / how to ask broad / “trivial” questions?

Tags: discussion

I really like the professionalism of Stack Overflow, but don’t understand some points here. For me, SO should support both users that have many experiences with some development environments and have specific detail problems, but also users that e.g. have experiences with development (e.g. Windows, C/S) and want to find an entry to web-development.

If a question is posted like e.g.: *"Which JS framework is the best to use with VS2015 and ASP.NET 5?"*, (regarding SEO, Speed, Future support security, ...) or *"How to start development with ASP.NET 5 and ReactJS?"* I am sure, it would get downvoted and/or marked it for deletion. The same happens if a self-answered question is posted.

For example, I have created a starter guide for Xamarin Forms and posted it in the Xamarin forums to help other users (and it *has* helped various users). I then thought I could also post it on Stack Overflow. Therefore, I have posted a question: *"How to start developing with Xamarin.Forms?"* and self-answered with: *"You can find information here: (link to my .pdf)"*.

This post was down voted and marked for deletion in no time. I then tried to talk about with the down voters and posted messages like: *"Why do you down vote this question / mark it for deletion?"* The answer was that there already is a similar base documentation available by Xamarin, which is **simply not true** (as my documentation contains practical things like “how to set up the environment”, “overview to the Xamarin universe”, “how to use the forum” and a lot more).

I took the time to write it as **I didn't find such information** when I started with Xamarin (to help other users to find an easier entry as I had). After posting a few messages, I gave up and have deleted the question (which is a real shame for every Xamarin beginner that searches for information on how to start in Stack Overflow).

This practice is a deterrent for any new Stack Overflow user, that makes this experience (like me) and a pity for every user that searches for basic information here.

Am I the only one who thinks so, or is there another place in the Stack Exchange network to ask/post such things?

Comment: Did you already read through [these articles](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)?

Comment: Ask Google? They're designed around finding resources like tutorials, etc.

Comment: There is no place for that kind of information here. Stack Overflow is not the only resource available to programmers and it doesn't want to be, or have to be. Tag Wikis occasionally contain links to these kinds of resources; also there is this being discussed / developed: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow

Comment: I find that a lot of people believe that SO is a place to "learn" or "What is the best way to do this" - And that's not what SO is for, even if you provide a answer to your own question (or another for that matter), it's still off-topic.

Comment: Your question was definitively off-topic, but not for the reason you were told; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: Would [Warlords of documentation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow/303885#303885) a good place for this kind of information?

Answer (score 10):

> "How to start developing with Xamarin.Forms?" and self-answered with: "You can find information here: (link to my .pdf)".

Yeah that's called self-promotion (and a link-only answer at that) and one of the main reasons such questions aren't allowed on the SE network. Everyone who writes a tutorial finds their tutorial the best and wants to promote that, but this site is not the place for that.

Post it to the relevant communities so you will be found through search engines by people looking for tutorials, and that is that.

As for "which is the best X to do Y" questions: there is no "best" for anything, there are only differences. You know what you want to do, so you can find Xes that do Y, and you can compare them yourself and select the one that best fits your requirements. You cannot outsource that to Stack Overflow. There do exist some sites that have already done this comparison for you, for various libraries and frameworks.

But both these questions have been answered before, try searching.