# Clueless questions -> unfriendly treatment?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This concerns with questions I sometimes encounter (and even experienced myself). Usually the situation is that someone ('novice') asks a question, which is immediately labelled as vague, even duplicate or "too little effort shown".

For example, some time ago I asked about how to understand certain syntactical construction on Java and how to deal with it (I deleted the question due to to "community pressure" and after getting valuable terminology hint). I am very casual programmer in Java, so I had no idea how it was called (now I know, it was an "anonymous class"). My question labelled "duplicate" and down-voted, because some other question elsewhere asked how anonymous classes work. I could understand, if I was mentioning the term by name, but part of the problem was I need to know before asking, and I need to extensively study some Java textbook before asking to "show effort"! It is not fair, as many legitimate questions can be answered by reading textbook from cover to cover.

Similar situation arises when someone started to learn something new, and not yet strong with the terms of the domain, or maybe there are no good introductions or even common terminology. These kinds of questions rarely get answered, maybe because of the fear of being down-voted or I don't know why - it is not difficult to answer by knowledgeable folks.

Still, pointing some direction is very useful for novices. For example, some very targeted source could be recommended (like, "What you describe is an anonymous class. RTFM or see this answer here.") You know, those who are experienced in something see almost immediately where to point clueless novice.

**Suggestion**. I think, some banner, similar to "Possible duplicate of", can be used for pointers like that. Or maybe short answer should be ok with more focused referenced on what chapter to RTFM, if the extended answer does not make sense here.

I know, there are those novices who think their problems will be solved by someone else. I do not consider those cases. It is usually easy to distinguish whether novice lacks terminology or sincerely lacks relevant key issues, and when it's some kind of homework. As a positive example, Python folks here usually do not have this attitude, and try to help (usually in a matter of minutes!) even to very vague questions.

Comment: Basicly the Professionals on SO expect people to be able to read documentation and do some of the legwork on their own. Most situations you describe are people asking about the very basic concepts of programming, so basic that you can find them in any programming related book easily. There are alot of newcomers who get good questions. To do that all you have to do is ask a non-trivial, well researched, complete and verifiable and exact question.

Comment: `My question labelled "duplicate" and down-voted, because some other question elsewhere asked how anonymous classes work.` Well, you learned the term by asking, and the duplicate question shows you the concept. That's enough to get you started. There is no point in leaving yet another duplicated question open to attract garbage answer.

Comment: @nhahtdh Ok. This is rational argument. But still, sometimes those questions are landing pages, because people search for same things independently... That is why I propose "banner".

Comment: So you want something like a duplicate banner, but for external resources?

Comment: @RomanSusi and that's **exactly *why*** they're closed as dupes, so someone searching for the term you used can now find the canonical source of the information (or, rather, now they can't, because you deleted it. Good job). See https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Comment: @nhahtdh Something, which gives a clue. It may be pointer to another stackexchange resource at least, or Documentation, or external (maybe), or just words with hints.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ok, but calling it "duplicate question" may be misleading. I am speaking about "related", which serve as hints.

Comment: Read the banner: **This question already has an answer here**. That's what matters; getting people to the content that solves their problem. It's not really clear what you're suggesting is changed, or why you think it would be beneficial (and as one of the *"Python folks"*, I can assure you I try to close as many duplicates as I can).

Comment: IMO this request comes too soon. It might go somewhere when the warlords of documentation have had time to go rampant. Then at least there is an internal resource to link to. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow

Comment: Ok. "put on hold as unclear what you're asking" - one more miscommunicating message? I can't see it is unclear what I am asking (see comments below), but only that I suggested bad idea. No? And downvotes indicate "bad idea" for me clearly.

Comment: Guarantee you (OP) are speaking with the full support of the vast majority of users. These people just want to protect their reputation snowballs.

Comment: I fully agree Stack Overflow is a very unfriendly sometimes even hostile site. Yes, you can always find arguments why somebody should have studied more, and no this is not a learning site, but still. Some people seem to get a huge kick out of talking novice people down here! I also know I had this discussion many times before and it is useless to complain about it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I think, some banner, similar to "Possible duplicate of", can be used for pointers like that. Or maybe short answer should be ok with more focused referenced on what chapter to RTFM, if the extended answer does not make sense here.

How is this banner to be generated? What FM (from your RTFM) should be chosen? How should the system know what chapter to pick?

The community here sees many, many, many questions that don't show any effort. It is also generally accepted by the people active here that Stack Overflow is not a tutorial. Combined, people don't have patience for such questions and yes, they downvote and close them.

It is unclear to me (assuming I even understood your feature request), how it solved anything.

Comment: How is this banner to be generated? - the same way "Possible duplicate of" is.

Comment: @RomanSusi isn't there already one thats generated if your question has recieved some duplicate votes but not enough to close it yet?

Comment: Feature would allow to add hints and links without risk of downvoted answer. This is more useful for novices than unfriendly reaction of community. If you aren't patient, why are you here?

Comment: @RomanSusi to help solve problems, obvisouly not those which can already have an answer by googling the title of a question...

Comment: @RomanSusi on the flipside, if you aren't willing to read already answered questions or use google, why are you here?

Comment: @Magisch My point is "Duplicate" is a wrong signal. There should be a mechanism for hint / reference semantic. In my case the ques was NOT duplicate, but there were no better way to hint me.

Comment: @RomanSusi no, its not. Duplicate means this question has an Answer somewhere else. For other pointers to similar questions that don't meet that standart, comments exist.

Comment: @Magisch To "read" means "to find". How, without asking I could understand the syntax is "anonymous class"? If I only knew it is, there were no problem to find. This is the whole point - terminology mismatch, when the novice is not able to search before asking!

Comment: @RomanSusi What I mean is: a question showing a real research effort and what have been tried rarely end up downvoted. the close as duplicate and downvote are not related, if the question is downvoted, the question itself has a problem (unrelated to be a duplicate or not)

Comment: @RomanSusi "Anonymous class" @ Google: 12.5m hits (0.5s) second hit is a highly upvoted SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java  Now tell me again why exactly you would need to ask another question about what that is on here, and how it would be unfair or "wrong signal" to close such a question as duplicate.

Comment: @Magisch Try to search by inserting concrete construction into google, without mentioning anonymous class.

Comment: @RomanSusi - I  still don't know how a banner pointing one to an FM and to a specific chapter there is supposed to be generated. Is the system supposed to read the mind of the OP?

Comment: @Oded Those who would otherwise answer and know the matter will add that.

Comment: @RomanSusi - You are assuming that there is an agreement on what the right FM and chapter are. That these even exist or that people who close have any interest in putting the effort to find the correct FM and chapter in the first place (in particular given OPs that have shown no effort).

Comment: @Oded Additionally, this would literally just be OP offloading the work to find a tutorial onto the SO users. Why would people do that? And in what way would that in any way be conducive to site growth? All I see in that is an easier mechanism for help vampires to offload research work onto SO.

Comment: @Oded The effort is highly asymmetrical. Java pro sees in a second that my question is about "anonymous class". For me to know I need to study Java extensively to recognize it. For those who want to help, it's a matter of seconds to hint. And they do in comments.

Comment: @RomanSusi Thats still behaviour overall harmful to the site by encouraging people to offload their research onto site users. It should not be encouraged or made easier in any means.

Comment: @RomanSusi - and it still goes against the goals of Stack Overflow. To be a repository of *good* questions and answers. Those that can help as many people as possible. The question you had and the answer to it can really only help one person.

Comment: @Oded Ok. I see. This explains it.

Comment: @Oded However, in some situations, for example, when terminology is compared, it may be useful to leave the question open so those who search for some combination still find it. And I mean this kind of questions: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/77902/what-is-this-part-called or their analogy on SO. NB. Those aren't downvoted there.

Comment: @RomanSusi no, it's not helpful to leave them open, it's helpful to *close them as duplicates*. Then all of the relevant answers are in one place and nobody is wasting time rehashing constant that already exists. If the question is a useful signpost (e.g. uses slightly different terminology) it should stay *undeleted* but closed, but in many cases it's an obvious dupe and only sheer laziness on the part of the OP led to them asking in the first place.

Comment: @jonrsharpe While I somewhat disagree about laziness, as more or less frequent on SO I understand your point, it still feels unfriendly to those not versed in SO ways. That is why I suggested more indicative banner. But the idea seems to be harmful according to much more experienced people here.

Comment: @RomanSusi when I say laziness I mean the dupes where searching for *those exact words* would have found the answer. Such questions are not useful signposts. It's still not clear why you think that **This question already has an answer here** isn't the right content for the banner, or why questions should be left open to acquire more answers when they already have them.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I agree with "those exact words", of course. As for This question already has an answer here, remember it happens simultaneously or after heavy down-voting, not just counter for close. Yes, maybe, I do not have enough understanding of SO myself. I am not thinking, I remember I felt it unfriendly to get downvoting, close and dup instead of hints and clues... each time I step out of "comfort zone", where I have enough knowledge to ask.

Comment: I accepted this answer, I hope the signal "from the trenches" went through, even though not gathered sympathy.

Comment: @RomanSusi - remember. Downvotes are not personal. You are not your question. What got downvoted was the question, not the person who asked it.

Comment: I am ok, I can pay with my reputation points on SO for making bad question. I was concerned with those whose first / second question is encountered with unexplained downvotes and threats instead of just having clear and cheep hint / clue / link... While I understand signal-to-noise concerns, the first echelon is important. IMHO.

Comment: Threats? I hope no one is getting actual threats, @RomanSusi

Comment: Well, not directly. "Threats" of the question (which may be poster's best effort) being closed, deleted, suspected duplication, downvoted and all that. Poster itself feels helpless. After that someone maybe comes to comment why the ques is that bad.

Comment: @Oded Ok. Actually Wikipedia does the same. Maybe, when crowd-sourcing project dealing with a lot of people keeping high SNR has more priority than being friendlier to clueless newcomers.

Comment: @RomanSusi - this isn't about priority. People just get fed up seeing the same thing over and over and over. See [Eternal September](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September) and [A Group Is Its Own Worst Enemy](http://www.shirky.com/writings/herecomeseverybody/group_enemy.html).

Comment: Indeed, I'm sick and tired of posting 'Googling the exact title of your question results in : About 36,000,000 results, with four SO Q&A at the top with answers to your question'.  SO is riddled with ignorant, selfish, bone-idle deadbeats whose sole aim is is get SO contributors to write complete copypasta homework answers.  It is incumbent on newcomers to not write questions that SEEM to fall into that category, else they will get treated harshly.  "I only took a toy pistol into the schoolyard, so why am I in hospital with bullet wounds from cop guns?"

Comment: @RomanSusi how on earth could you construe *"here are some answers to your question, already neatly written out and ranked by other users"* as a *threat*?! **Duplication is not necessarily a bad thing.** Even if it gets put on-hold for other reasons that's not the end of the line - you can (and should) edit with a view to getting it reopened, following the guidance provided in the banner. Without seeing the question in question we can't say whether the downvotes on top of the closure were fair, though.

Comment: My example question is from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055751/how-to-understand-these-java-declarations  I do not tell it is unfairly treated (after you guys explained some fine mechanics here), but downvoting onslaught was somewhat unusual, left me wondering.

Comment: 3 downvotes is not an onslaught - it is just 3 people. And it is normal to see downvotes on questions that don't follow the guidelines.