# Error reference collections - Bane or Boon?

Tags: discussion, questions, community-wiki

2 weeks ago, this was posted on [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34516880/javascript-errors-reference-what-does-this-error-mean

This is basically a collection of explanations of common error messages.

This post is inspired by a [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) variant:
[Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)
This one has proven to be quite successful, even though some answers haven't been updated in a long time.

I see some issues with collections like these, but there are also a couple of reasons posts like these can be of use:

- They provide a centralized place to bookmark for reference.
- Newly posted questions can quickly be closed as a dupe of the reference collection.

On the other side:

- Collections like these reduce traffic on existing answers for these errors.
  This results in reduced rep for the original answer.
- Answers are duplicated in order to explain the error in an answer on the collection.
- These collections can grow quite large. One could argue that the collection is a textbook example of **"too broad"**. This doesn't help users trying to find one specific error.
- When a question is closed as dupe of the collection, you can't link to a specific answer. This means the user has to search again.
- Individual questions allow for different answers for each error. Adding multiple answers in such a collection will quickly become a mess.
- Individual questions practically allow for much longer, in-depth answers.
- As it is right now, the answers on the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) collection are incomplete summaries of multiple **existing answers**.

The [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) post is a community wiki. In my opinion, this should be applied to the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) version too, at very least.

However, there are also plenty of arguments to close it altogether.

What do you think?

Should collections like these exist? What would then become of the existing answers?
If there's enough reason to close the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) post, what about the [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) one?

Comment: A big problem is the maintenance. A QA should be small and focused so that it can be determined if it's (still) valid or not. A QA should not be a book.

Comment: Another problem is that answers are supposed to be *alternatives*. When each answer focuses on a different topic, the whole SO logic fails and the only solution becomes to *change* an answer when it's invalid. This is totally the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Updating this 'collection' will become a problem. That is SO's system: Users gets help as soon as they need it. If a user reads a whole 'book' and misunderstand / read outdated informations, he probably will 'Ask a question'. In this case the collection was useless.

Comment: I see at least 3 different variations on "Unexpected token [token]".  If that's not unmaintainablely broad I don't know what would be.

Comment: The JS one _probably_ should be a community wiki, if it's determined that it should remain open.

Comment: @KevinBrown: Absolutely. At very least that.

Comment: [Relevant Meta SE question about the PHP errors question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149743/159034)

Comment: One question for every possible error?  Nahbrah.  One question per error?  Yobro.

Comment: Sounds like a good fit for [Documentation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303865/215552), but not for SO.

Comment: This dupe isn't correct. This isn't about canonical questions. This is about collections of canonicals. About whether or not they're on topic.

Comment: Just search Meta for "one question per question" and you'll see that, indeed, there should only be one question per question, for various reasons.

Comment: A user who doesn't search before asking a question isn't going to read a long multi-question "reference" to find the answer that applies to them.

Comment: Stack Overflow does not have "threads". We're a Q&A site, not a forum.

Comment: @mason: You know what I mean.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Actually it took me a while to figure out what you were referring to! I've edited your question to clarify that it's about questions.

Comment: The problem is that these collections aren't questions.

Comment: I do know what you mean, but that doesn't mean everyone will. We have a hard enough time convincing new users that this isn't a forum without high rep users calling things "threads".

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**Bane.**

It is too broad. It basically asks and answers multiple questions in one. Each JavaScript error should be treated as separate one.

While it may look like having such single reference is a a good thing, it goes against Stack Overflow policy of asking single specific question.

All your points against are valid ones. There is not much else to be said.

Comment: What do you think about the [tag:php] one? Do you think that one should be closed too, then?

Comment: @Cerbrus Probably. I believe that main point here is we should not allow such new questions to gain roots. Or soon enough we'll be swamped with similar.

Comment: @Cerbrus Basically we are dealing with two separate issues here. One is fighting against new Q/A like this, and other is how to deal with similar old Q/A like this.

Comment: Good point. Removing the existing one should be a thread on it's own then.

Comment: Agreed, plus compound error collections, as opposed to individual questions per error message, frustrate the powerful technique of hitting a search engine with an error message and finding an excellent SO question as a top, often first, result.

Comment: Upvote from me because it states bane in bold, but for a different reason: the list is going to lie to a lot of people, and those people are going to cry "it doesn't work! Help me!" It is also going to exclude a lot of people - those with an error not on the list or those who have errors caused by syntax faults, who are going to cry "My error isn't on the list, help me!". There is too much suffering attached to lists, and suffering leads to the dark side.

Comment: The post has been closed as "Too broad", now.

Answer (score 4):

When implemented in the way that the [PHP error reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php) is, they're a bane. The generic titles prevent them from ever coming up in Google for any specific problem, so the only way to discover them is when a veteran in [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) closes a *real* question as a duplicate of the reference. I'm speculating a little here, but I expect this leads to several nasty effects:

- No competition on answers is possible; common debugging questions that would benefit from multiple answers with different approaches, or from competition driving the creation of a really strong canonical answer, instead get *one* answer, and thereafter any occurrence of the same question gets closed as a dupe
- Answers are less likely to be reachable from the first page or two of Google *at all*. The reference questions don't show up in Google searches for their content, and duplicates that otherwise *would* be Googleable get closed and either end up deleted or simply not getting polished to the level that they otherwise would, keeping them off Google results
- Even when there *is* a path to the answer via a "duplicate" question that shows up on Google, it's more time and effort for no good reason; searchers with common problems get needlessly forced to click through a duplicate banner, scroll through the contents of a reference question, find their issue, and click down to it
- Effort gets duplicated for no good reason as askers and answerers fail to hunt down a duplicate Q&A tucked into an answer in an unGoogleable reference question

I've experienced this nuisance first-hand when [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30365346/1709587) about the Spaceship Operator that I answered got closed as a duplicate of a reference question I never knew existed. The experience for people Googling for information about the Spaceship Operator would be *strictly better* if the reference question didn't exist and the answer there were on the real question instead; the reference does nothing but harm in this case.

I would like to burn away all the unrelated Q&A pairs sitting in their own answers on reference questions. They actively harm Googleability and competition in the areas that they're answering; Stack Overflow would be more useful if most of those "answers" were deleted, the answerers messaged encouraging them to create canonical Q&A pairs *as questions* if they think their existing content had value, and the reference "questions" they're on locked to prevent more answers.

On the other hand, when a reference limits itself to being an index of other *actual questions* on the site, they're a boon. [What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) is surely the best example of this on the site; it's an incredible resource and my first stop for all regex-comprehension questions, and is certainly not doing harm in the way that the PHP references are. Whatever we do, let's not throw the baby out with the bathwater.

Comment: @Cerbrus, I've rolled back your edit that converted references to "Googleability" to be references to "Findability". Google (or other, practically very similar search engines like Bing) is what matters, and I want to be clear in my answer that, really, that's all I'm talking about when I talk about people finding posts.

Comment: Even with my edit, you mention "Google" 6 times. But okay, it's your answer :-)

Comment: I totally agree, specially with the last paragraph. Maybe my answer was misunderstood, considering the negative reception it had, when compared to yours.

Answer (score -10):

I like the idea of an index/list of related QAs, provided the links pointed to existing canonical content. The problem is that it doesn't quite fit anywhere in the site. Let's see:

1. As a question, it should allow no answers, and probably marked CW. I'm just not sure if that could still be called "a question".
2. It could be in the tag wiki. But nobody reads tag wikis, and the idea of multiple long lists in language tag wikis feels wrong.
3. It could be somewhere else, somewhere new. Probably the Documentation site, but nobody knows how that is supposed to be yet (if someone does, please enlighten me).

My opinion is that indexes can be good, but there's no proper place for them yet. So the real question is how to make them fit into the site smoothly.

Comment: A reference list of links can be done using a single-answer community wiki question. [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/1048572) is a good example

Comment: @Bergi Indeed, but nothing prevents other answers from being added. That could be accomplished by locking the question, but that also prevents the post from being voted, which would be awful.

Comment: I don't think that's a problem. Extra answers can be commented, voted and vote-to-delete'd on, just like we keep other canonical questions clean.

Answer (score -16):

All good points. Here is my contrasting opinions on some of them:

> These collections can grow quite large. One could argue that the collection is a textbook example of "too broad". This doesn't help users trying to find one specific error.

Whilst it may considered too broad, I think it *does* help users to find their specific error, as if all of the errors are centralized and are properly and neatly linked in the wiki question, it will be easy to find the question and click the link to the answer you need.

This is in contrast to having a question (or potentially multiple questions) which most likely contain user-specific cases which don't necessarily apply to the user who is searching.

> Individual threads allow for different answers for each error. Adding multiple answers in such a collection will quickly become a mess.

If there are multiple explanations for an error, they should be encapsulated into the one answer.

> As it is right now, the answers on the javascript collection are incomplete summaries of multiple existing answers.

This is an issue with the content of the answers, not the value of the question/wiki.

> Individual threads practically allow for much longer, in-depth answers.

I don't see any impracticality of having longer, in-depth answers on the wiki.

> As it is right now, the answers on the javascript collection are incomplete summaries of multiple existing answers.

Again, this is an issue with the content of the post, *not* the value (or potential value) of the post.

---

Additionally, I think it's worth noting the response to the PHP version; with over 500 upvotes, I think it's clear that the post has been helpful to many users.

Comment: The php "wiki" has 31 answers. If each of the answers is as long as the original answer(s), you'll be completely losing overview of the question and it's answers. It'll be harder to maintain a combined answer than individual answers on their dedicated questions. Also, combined answers remove the option to vote for separate solutions, so that's not an option. Regarding the content problem with the answers: Questions that invite bad answers aren't very welcome on SO.

Comment: Furthermore, I don't agree that this collection will help users find their answers. Users that _do_ search will find the original Q/A. They don't need the collection.

Comment: There are lots of old questions with historical locks and lots of upvotes that were later deemed unfit for Stack Overflow (the community changes over time). so saying "I think it's clear that the post has been helpful to many users" doesn't mean much if the question is 3 years old.