# What should we do with "How to solve common errors in Google Apps Script development"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, self-answer, canonical, instant-self-answer

Recently *[How to solve common errors in Google Apps Script development](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62336082/1595451)* was posted and had several upvotes, but it was also closed.

> NOTE: This is not a duplicate of [What to do about hundreds of the same basic question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319930/1595451) because this about an specific question which discussion through comments is becoming lengthy

The question has several problems.

1. It's not a question
2. It's too broad (it's about "common error"s, not about a specific error)
3. It's primarily opinion-based (while there is a list of "examples" there aren’t explicit criteria to qualify which errors are common, i.e., the minimum pages that searching an error should be returned)
4. It's a "listing" question type
5. The conversation in the comments is lengthy (the question was posted June 12th, 2020, and it had 18 comments the next day, at the time that this post was created, as Oct 7th, 2022 it has +20 comments still shown)
6. It's not a good "original" to close as duplicate good questions as each answer is about a different error that might not have common causes / solutions.

Regarding the answers (so far it has 2)

1. They are a list of errors. While they are using headings, because their length and the SO lack of inner-links (i.e., TOC linking to each header) it's "hard" to jump directly to the section of interest (if you have the error text using the web browser "find" command will do the job).

---

As of Oct 2022, the question is open. 
<s>So what should we do to keep the question open as there are similar questions for other languages (they are mentioned in the question)?</s>

> **Preface**
>
> This Q&A strives to become a collection and a reference target for
> common errors encountered during development in Google Apps Script
> language in hopes to improve long-term maintainability of
> [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) tag.
>
> There are several similar and successful undergoings in other
> languages and general-purpose tags (see [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix), [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441049/common-errors-while-writing-android-project),
> [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them), [php again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php?rq=1)), and this one follows suit.
>
> ---
>
> **Why it exists?**
>
> The amount of questions from both new and experienced developers
> regarding the meaning and solutions to errors encountered during
> development and production that can be effectively reduced to a single
> answer is substantial. At the time of writing, even running a query
> only by language tag yields:
>
> - "Cannot find method" [8 pages](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=Relevance&pagesize=50&q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%20cannot%20find%20method)
> - "Cannot read property" [9 pages](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%20Cannot%20read%20property%20%27)
> - "Cannot call ... in this context" [5 pages](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%20from%20this%20context)
> - "You do not have permission" [11 pages](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%20You%20do%20not%20have%20permission)
>
> Linking to a most relevant duplicate is hard and time-consuming for
> volunteers due to the need to consider nuances and often poorly-worded
> titles.
>
> ---
>
> **What it consists of?**
>
> Entries in this Q&A contain are designed as to provide info on how to:
>
> - parse the error message structure
> - understand what the error entails
> - consistently reproduce (where applicable)
> - resolve the issue
> - provide a link to canonical Q&A (where possible)
>
> ---
>
> **What this is not?**
>
> The scope of the Q&A is limited to *common* (not trivial). This is
> not:
>
> - a catch-all guide or "best practices" collection
> - a reference for general ECMAScript errors
> - GAS documentation
> - a resources list (we have a [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for that)
>
> ---
>
> **What to add?**
>
> When adding an entry, please, consider the following:
>
> - is the error common enough (see "why" section for examples)?
> - can the solution be described concisely and be applicable for most cases?
>
> ---
>
> > ! The initial answer is a community wiki already and the question is intended to become one as well as soon as the status of the Q&A itself
> > is resolved. You are most welcome and encouraged to contribute

Related

- [How do I ask and self-answer a correct, high quality Q&A pair without attracting downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314165/1595451)

Comment: Thank you for moving the discussion to meta, Rubén! I will provide some extra context for the discussion regarding reasoning and possible steps that should be taken that will benefit the community - looking forward to community feedback and suggestions on what would be the most beneficial way to proceed.

Comment: It is a canonical question and answer and so i voted to open it again, so that other can helpo with their answers

Comment: @nbk I think that it should not be reopened while we are discussing it here.

Comment: Thanks, @nbk - though, I must point out that I don't see a problem in it being closed and still be helpful (even I can't argue well against collection of questions being, well, a bit too broad :) - I and others can still improve answers, and after a decision is reached, we will have all the building blocks at hand. What I would do, though, on reopen, is at least split general and service-specific entries into separate answers while we disccuss.

Comment: i was not the first and hopefully also not the last to vote to reopen. It.is a braid question,without a doubt, but with that answer it is helpful and concetrated

Comment: Btw, just to have a clear policy: can this Q&A *currently* used as a dupe target in case a canonical / detailed answer cannot be found or would it be better to wait until we reach a consensus? I am a bit torn on the matter and a community input is highly appreciated!

Comment: @OlegValter No. Dup questions should be questions and answer meet the quality guidelines : 1) [ask], 2) [answer], by the other hand we should not deliberately make changes that should be changed later.

Comment: Thanks, duly noted! Will retract a couple of older flags (phew, only one) while I am at it

Comment: @OlegValter also, the answer should be contained within it. It would be counterproductive to close a duplicate and that the next reader that may already have the information diagnosing the issue is redirected towards how to obtain debugging information.

Comment: (Something seems to be missing near *"So what we keep the question as there"*)

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks. I added some slight updates. I not remember what was in my mind about that specific statement ... I think that I was asking for suggestions to keep the question open... Nowadays it's open.

Answer (score 11):

I really have a thing for how to debug X style questions, but X has to be defined to a simple single message, specially if said message can mean several things depending the context. Rather than having one question for several messages, is better to have several questions for each message instead. That way, readers would only find information relevant to the issue they are having.

Comment: Hi @Braiam - thank you for feedback - we have actually been discussing this option (I am the OP and currently drafting up an answer with info in that regard). I agree that having multiple questions each targeting a specific error / error group looks like a better alternative. Before the question got closed, I was considering splitting it into multiple answers on a single question, but the idea of a decentralized approach resonates well with me

Comment: Welcome back!!!

Answer (score 4):

Regarding

> in Google Apps Script language in hopes to improve long-term maintainability of
> [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) tag.

don't forget the **tag wiki**. We could add to it a list of *canonical questions* as it was done on the tag wiki of [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) (and maybe other tags)

<sup>Many of the "more specific" tags were synonymized / removed in favor of "combo tagging" (using two or more tags instead of one)</sup> 


Also don't forget that we could use more specific tags for canonical questions for errors which context is relevant, i.e.

- [google-apps-script-simple-triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-simple-triggers)
- [gs-installable-triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gs-installable-triggers)
- [google-apps-script-web-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-web-application)
- [google-apps-script-addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-addon)
- [gsuite-addons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gsuite-addons)

among others

Related

- [When is it appropriate to create a tag, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252944/1595451)
- [How do I write a good tag wiki? Is it okay to use/copy content published elsewhere?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318337/1595451)
- [Canonical question for "You do not have permission" in Google Sheets custom functions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398266/1595451)
- [Could we have a [google-apps-script-faq] tag similar to [c++-faq] and [r-faq]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420721/1595451)

Answer (score 3):

As the OP of the discussed post, I have to add that there is a proposal (which I fully support) to split the post into multiple Q&As that specifically target each question separately and make them community wikis as well as update the corresponding [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) language tag wiki in a similar way to how it is done by [JavaScript wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info).

The idea for the post came as a result of a prolonged observation of a stream of questions and answers (I am guilty as charged of the latter as much as others) that explain a more or less fixed set of frequent errors in the context of a question, usually dealing with *what* has to be done instead of *why* they happen in the first place (and given the questions, I totally understand why).

I agree with all points made by Rubén and would like to provide additional context for some of them:

**It's primarily opinion-based**

I agree that the definition of *common* is lax (at least in a way that I presented it in the question). When creating the Q&A, I considered the question common if it had:

1. *more than a page* of questions that all effectively ask to explain what the error message means or why it happens.
2. *one or at least a closed list* of root causes and therefore could be answered in a generalized form without any loss of meaning.

**It's a "listing" question type**

Before posting, the [extended discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314618/error-reference-collections-bane-or-boon) regarding "listing" (or "reference") Q&As was taken into consideration, and the reason why I decided to proceed was that similar projects with an exception of [[tag:php]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php) list were concentrating on creating a hub of links to other questions and not on providing tailored answers (with links to canonicals upon discovery).

---

To highlight what the primary consideration for going forward with this Q&A is as of now:

1. Continue adding value to the current answer
2. Linking canonical Q&As if such exist
3. If a positive decision is reached, split the Q&A into multiple community wikis that follow the same structure which I envision as follows:

   - common error message (with truncated variable part) **as title**, something like "How to fix [error message here]" to make them more discoverable
   - concise description of the meaning of the error
   - steps to reproduce the issue *in general*
   - guides on how to fix the issue and code samples where applicable
   - references to related Q&As dealing with edge cases or otherwise potentially of interest
4. Post answers in / update existing canonical Q&As (if any)
5. Edit tag info wiki Q&A-style linking them while avoiding creation of "list"-type question.

Answer (score 3):

[google-sheets-custom-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-custom-function) is now a synonym of [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script). The combo [`[google-apps-script][custom-function]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%20%5Bcustom-function%5D) (very likely that most of the questions having this combo are about Google Sheets custom functions) currently has 787 results / 332 questions https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcustom-function%5D

---

I think that one of the projects that could be derived from this question is a retagging project for questions about Google Sheets custom functions

So far I just created [google-sheets-custom-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-custom-function) and proposed the tag excerpt and wiki.

In the context of this discussion I suggest to look for questions about Google Sheets custom functions that claims that an error occurred but that is cause to the Google Sheets custom functions limitations like

1. The execution time exceed the 30 seconds limit
2. Use a method that requires an authorization scope

To find these questions you could start searching for *candidates* by using

- [[custom-function][google-apps-script] error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcustom-function%5D%20%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%20error)

Remember, while you are editing a question fix other problems or improve the question to make it clear, specific, etc.

Related

- [Should I approve suggested edits that only add/remove tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251261/1595451)
- [Canonical question for "You do not have permission" in Google Sheets custom functions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398266/1595451)

Comment: Note for others: there is a generic [tag:custom-function] which is "a bit" of a mess (besides, it does not have a wiki). Since we now have a dedicated tag, I would suggest at least swapping them (especially considering the amount of specific restrictions imposed on such functions I fully support the idea)

Comment: @OlegValter I just posted [Canonical question for "You do not have permission" in Google Sheets custom functions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398266/1595451)

Comment: `787`? [custom-function] alone only contains 474 questions.

Comment: @TheMaster 787 results ->  meaning questions & answers. Adding `is:question` to the referred search returns 332 results