# Canonical question for "You do not have permission" in Google Sheets custom functions

Tags: discussion, canonical

TL;DR I'm looking for guidance regarding which question should be used as a canonical question for Google Sheets customs functions returning "You do not have permission"

---

This question is derived from [What should we do with "How to solve common errors in Google Apps Script development"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398230/1595451)

The search [[google-apps-script] You do not have permission](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%20You%20do%20not%20have%20permission) returns 527 results, as they are too many I tried to narrow the search by including tags like [google-sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) [custom-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-function), [google-sheets-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-formula) but then I realized that there are many questions that doesn't include these tags that should do, and many of them should be marked as duplicate of a question with a TL;DR answer like

> Your custom function is calling a method that requires authorization but custom functions doesn't support those methods because they run anonymously

I don't know what question should be used as a canonical question or if we should post a brand new question to make it clear that is a canonical question and avoid "complaints" from the OPs.

---

More related searches

- [[google-apps-script] title:"You do not have permission"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%20title%3A%22You%20do%20not%20have%20permission%22) , as of October 7th 2022, returns 84 questions.
- [[google-sheets] "You do not have permission" -[google-apps-script]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-sheets%5D%20%22You%20do%20not%20have%20permission%22%20-%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D), as of October 7th 2022, returns 2 results

---

The oldest question that I found is

[No permission to call msgBox in Google Apps Scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10506105/1595451)

- It has 7k views.
- It doesn't include the error message in the question title or body, but it's included in the body of the answer.

One pair of Q/A with the highest scores is

Q: [Custom function throws a "You do not have the permission required to setValue" error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15933019/1595451) (score 20)
A: [Serge insas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15936281/1595451) (score 28)

- It has 53k views.

Comment: Thank you, Rubén - while researching this error I've seen the Q&A you mentioned - the problem is (at least it was for me at the time) that while your answer is both correct and detailed, the accepted and highly upvoted one as of now cites outdated documentation. I am thinking of two possibilities here: update Serge's answer to include new wording, or publish a standalone community wiki with references to that and other canonicals - as far as my experience goes, this error happens in a broader context as well (albeit the most prominent use case, I agree, is incorrect usage of custom functions)

Comment: @OlegValter I just found [Process for nominating and promoting canonical questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276010/1595451) :)

Comment: Yep, seen that one - well, this is basically what we arw doing now, right? :)  Btw, I've updated the initial question to have a more focused title, grammar and formatting - probably still worth to update answers to their best as well. 
A wiki answer could be added on top of this question, but I am not sure about what happens when a non-owner makes the answer a CW - do all subsequent ones also become CWs?

Comment: Although, come to think of it, nevermind the idea about adding to this question - the second most common reason for the issue is way too off and deserves a separate canonical. Explicit authorization scopes and where to find them, so to speak

Comment: @OlegValter Regarding updating Serge's answer that should be done very carefully, actually the best is that Serge update his answer by himself (he has the [tag:google-apps-script] gold badge and is still active)

Comment: [I see you also considered that one, apologies - but leaving it here for reference] There is an [additional candidate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30587331/you-do-not-have-permission-to-call-openbyid) for this canonical (that one I linked to my Q&A earlier). Ironically enough, this one has an answer to most of the situations *in the question itself*. I prefer to use more targeted query: `[google-apps-script] "do not have permission" score:8`

Comment: I like [this Q&A pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840894/not-allowed-to-execute-sendemail-from-custom-function-but-ok-in-script-editor) regarding this issue - edited the question a bit to highlight error