# If a question can be easily Google searched or tested to see the answer, should I still ask it?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm asking this to check whether my understanding is correct.

Some page (I forgot which) on Stack Overflow told me that I should always Google search thoroughly before asking a question and I should show research effort in my question.

My understanding is that forcing people to show research effort can reduce duplicate questions. People will search on Google and say "Oh! Someone asked this on Stack Overflow before" and find the answer.

However, what if I Google searched, and found the solution, **but not on Stack Overflow**? Should I still ask a question?

I think *yes*. Because the aim of Stack Overflow is to build a repository of good questions and answers. So if the question helps build a repository of good questions and answers, I should post the question.

On the other hand, what if the question can be answered by testing? For example, "What ads will admob display if I set the ad unit ID to an empty string?" This question can be easily answered by testing.

I think this kind of questions are OK to be asked because this can save the time of testing of future visitors.

Am I right about the two situations?

Comment: No, I don't think Stack Overflow needs *all* the information. There's no point in reproducing all the documentation in javadoc, MSDN etc. If the answer is in an obscure and transient location, then maybe. As for testing - how hard is it to test? If it's a matter of creating a 10 line console app, then no, that's not worth putting on SO IMO. If it took hours, then that's a different matter.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3001761

Comment: Please no. By asking a question on Stack Overflow about something that is easy to Google, that question will very likely push its way in front of the official documentation or whatever other resources already exists

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer is not black-and-white.  Ultimately it will depend greatly on the other resource.

- Is the other site an official site for the framework/language/library or otherwise officially connected to the framework/language/library?
- Is the answer found on a random blog, forum, or other Q&A site?
- Is the answer easily found via searching (high ranking)

Firstly, **Stack Overflow is not a replacement for the official documentation** ([except when the feature is explicitly designed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow)). If the answer is easily found in the documentation for the framework/language/library, then no, it doesn't need to be duplicated here.  As [Pekka 웃 suggests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323511/if-a-question-can-be-easily-google-searched-or-tested-to-see-the-answer-should#comment346708_323511), we don't need to make the official documentation more difficult to find.

The documentation should never become out of date as the framework/language/library matures, but a Stack Overflow question easily can.  We don't need a highly ranked outdated answer that distracts from the official documentation.  This also holds true for any FAQ's or Wiki's set up on the official website.

What if the answer is found **only** on another forum/Q&A/blog, but not on Stack Overflow and is not connected to the official documentation of the language.  I don't believe we should be shooting those questions down.  Why does the fact that the answer exists elsewhere in the Interwebs, even if it is high ranking in Google, mean that it can't be asked here.  How would a user know that the site is trustworthy, or answer is accurate?  There's plenty of crap out there and helping filter the crap seems to fit with the goals and ideals of Stack Overflow.

For the testing portion of the question, Stack Overflow is not a replacement for basic testing and experimentation.  If you can set up a test case in less time<sup>*</sup> than it would take to write a good question and wait for a well written answer, then there is virtually no value in the question on Stack Overflow.  But if the scenario takes hours to setup and run, and/or is loaded with edge cases that need considered, then having the information in Stack Overflow would be a benefit to the programming community.

To summarize, if the documentation is difficult to find or it out dated, then I see value in a Stack Overflow post.  Likewise if the solution is not from an official source, there is also value.  The point is to make high quality information more easily found, and if it can't be found or tested easily, or is of unknown quality, then there would be a benefit to having the question here.

---

<sup>*</sup> the time component here is hyperbole.  The point is that if the test case is quickly set up and the result is easily obtainable with minimal effort, then there doesn't seem to be value in a Q&A pair that would need to be maintained.

Comment: `How would a user know that the site is trustworthy, or answer is accurate? There's plenty of crap out there and helping filter the crap seems to fit with the goals and ideals of Stack Overflow.` that is a fair point, but if there is a good-looking third party resource that answers the question, then I expect the OP to have tried that, and failed. +1 otherwise