# Is there a way to post handy solutions to questions not being asked on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I was googling for 'Python convert German date to day of week'. Since I could not find anything I wrote my own script to convert a date like this:

```
"04.07.2016" -> 0 (Monday)
"05.07.2016" -> 1 (Tuesday)
 ...
"10.07.2016" -> 6 (Sunday)
 ...
"17.07.2016" -> 6 (Sunday)
```

Since this could be useful for other folks, I would like to post this somewhere so it can be easily found (I might also need this again in the future).

Comment: You could ask a self-answered question, but for  this one I'd stick to library functions...

Comment: Was your script anything like this? [which day of week given a date python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9847213/1324033) - (found by using your own search term minus the "german")

Comment: @Jan Dvorak Ok good idea. I do stick to library functions... ;-)

Comment: @user2177047 a small code snippet to help you https://ideone.com/HhQmTs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could ask a canonical self-answered question, which is basically a "fake" question with a presupplied answer. The question would be something like "How can I get the day of the week from a date?", and the answer would be your script -- *included entirely in the answer* -- with an explanation of what it does, its constraints, etc. The benefits of this approach are that if someone has a better solution, they can post it. I'd suggest not accepting your own answer for at least a couple of days, to encourage other people to contribute.

**Before doing this**, make sure to check for any preexisting canonical questions, or yours will get closed as a dupe. Search well. If you find *nothing* that's similar, post it as your own Q&A pair.

[NB: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847213/which-day-of-week-given-a-date-python) question is highly related. Before you post your own, make sure that it doesn't answer that question; if it does, post it as an answer there.]

You'll also want to make sure that your solution is as bugfree as possible.

Comment: Thank you, nice to know that now.

Comment: @user2177047 You're very welcome! I'm a bit miffed that I couldn't find the question that this was eventually closed as a dupe of, though; I'd have closed as duplicate otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Another place to post something like this would be **[Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow)**, which will be launching very soon.

Documentation (Which is currently in private beta), is very much focused on individual code examples (or "mini tutorials"), and editing by the community, so I think Docs.SO be a good place to post a code snippet for this, once it launces publicly.

Comment: Thanks! I will check it out if I need something like that again.