# Documentation reputation doesn't seem to be disabled

Tags: bug, status-declined, reputation, documentation

A few hours ago I got the **Documentation Preview Now On Stack Overflow** email. It said that:

> While we’re getting our ducks in a row for the public beta, a few things are disabled:
>
> - [...]
> - Documentation reputation
> - [...]
>
> These will all be turned on in time for the public beta, and your badges* and reputation from the private beta will be awarded then.

As it says, my reputation from the old private beta doesn't seem to have been transfered yet.

However, when I view my reputation history here on Stack Overflow, I see that I've just earned +2 for reviewing a documentation edit and +10 for an upvote on documentation I contributed to. The reputation system doesn't seem to be disabled as intended.

Comment: Can confirm that I see the same changes in rep on your profile, but that may be because I was on the beta as well.

Comment: @CalebBrinkman I was wondering about that, but it's also visible when logged out.

Comment: I can reproduce this - I am also on the beta, and I got +4 reputation for two documentation edits that I made

Comment: Repro'd earlier with an edit I made.

Comment: Just to confirm I am not in the beta and I can see the rep changes in your profile

Comment: I assume this comes under the bit where Kevin Montrose said "During this time reputation and profiles will be a little "weird" since bits will be hidden" (emphasis on weird!)

Comment: What's "Documentation" here?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe It's [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation) but if you are not in the beta, you won't be able to see it. Maybe start at [the beginning](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow) instead...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Rep is kind of "half on" right now, which isn't quite what was intended... but everyone'll get a recalc when Documentation opens up anyway.  Rather than fix it, we'll just wait for the (Coming Soon™) release.

Basically,

[image: Pardon our mess]

Comment: You had a chance to use an animated under construction gif and totally blew it. I'm just putting that out there.

Comment: Shouldn't rep from docs be separated from the main site?

Comment: When rep is recalculated, will I lose the (undeserved) [access to moderator tools](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) I will probably gain by then?