# Tag scoping and general programming concepts

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-topics

So today the Java language got the topic "Recursion".

For anyone not familiar with recursion (shame on you?):

> Recursion: see *Recursion*

or also:

> Recursion: Defining a function through means of itself. Prominent example: Fibonacci. The Fibonacci(n) = Fibonacci(n-2) + Fibonacci(n-1)

This is a **basic principle of programming**, heck it's a basic principle of **maths**.

Should we really have a topic for concepts spanning across all of programming (or across a paradigm) in each and every language?

Comment: I've created the topic recursion in Java and: No, we should not! The thing is, documentation is new and I did not find a more appropriate place to put this topic. Is there a way to put it somewhere more generic?

Comment: OT: I'll never get why the Fibonacci is the go-to example in recursion. although it has exponential time. IT: No. But to be honest, [what should we actually document?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328458/what-kind-of-topics-should-i-document)

Comment: As an addendum to this question: and if we shouldn't have a generic concepts section, how do we document these things?