# Should we prevent too granular documentation that already exists elsewhere?

Tags: discussion, documentation

I've noticed this happening mostly in the [CSS tag](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/topics). While programming languages documentation seems to be focused on problems (e.g. "Array sorting"), CSS has a lot of topics about basic language syntax. For instance there are examples listing all possible [background properties](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/296/backgrounds#t=201607212352337580142).

I understand that it might be useful to have them, but CSS is already extremely well documented on the internet (MDN, MSDN, W3C and many others). So this goes against the idea mentioned in [the original Documentation announcements](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow):

> If a project already has awesome documentation that's easy to search and cite, then there's no need to duplicate it on Stack Overflow. We're interested in fixing what's broken with documentation, not just moving them onto Stack Overflow.

[The other announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306213/warlords-of-documentation-your-questions-answered) mentioned our concern about:

> “duplicate the existing documentation just to get rep”-behaviors.

It seems we've got exactly this problem now.

The solution was:

> We’ll accomplish both by having a pretty tight “someone actually requested this” -> “it was useful to someone” loop, and making sure reputation incentives are aligned with that loop. It will not be possible to earn rep just for posting or editing Documentation Topics or Examples.

But all those topics seem to have been requested. And there are requests for more similar ones.

I think the problem is that there's no clear answer to [“What kind of topics should I document?”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328458/what-kind-of-topics-should-i-document). People don't know that perhaps the topics are too granular so they keep requesting more like them. Just to document everything they can think of. And get some sweet rep at the same time.

A similar thing is happening in the [HTML tag](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html/topics) where we have all possible `<input>` tags documented. The difference is that the HTML topics try to also cover the more complex bits about validation and accessibility (could use the problems as topic names, though). Still, all of this is already well documented and easy to find on the Web.

---

**So should this kind of documentation be prevented and topics closed?**

Or is this all OK and I should proceed to create examples for every possible CSS property?

Comment: As long as there are good examples I think its fine. If it just 'this and this and this exist, and now leave me alone' its bad. Just my 5 cents

Comment: In my own opinion, the question I wanted to ask is "This SO's new Documentation is necessary"? Right, I agree with you in your first emphasis and good examples were in SO already together with posted questions/problems. Also yes to your second emphasis, that kind of behavior is spreading... they love reps hohoho! The true objective of why we're creating documents is fading, more of becoming useless.

Comment: The key benefit of Documentation that the team keeps mentioning to us is examples. Good, useful, clear, abundant examples. Not many places have good examples for CSS implementations... CSS Tricks has some, but they're often outdated and you often have to scroll through a bunch of prose to get to them. CSS topics are fine as long as they have good examples (like any other language in Docs). But if a topic exists, that topic's syntax and related info should be included, too.

Answer (score 15):

Here are my observations of how authors (more commonly known as "web developers") perceive existing sources:

- W3Schools: either you're blissfully ignorant, or it's the worst place on the Internet and how dare you cite it in any reasonable technical article, presentation, discussion, or Q&A.
- MSDN: no one really refers to this except for features specific to Windows Store apps, Internet Explorer, or Microsoft Edge. Note that I'm talking about *features*; bugs are better documented elsewhere.
- MDN: the (current) holy grail of web platform docs.
- WebPlatform.org: most authors have probably never even heard of this. Even I don't know if it's really taken off. Has it?
- W3C: too technical, dry and verbose, often hard to understand. Which is fine, because **the official specifications were never intended for authors to begin with**. They were intended for vendors looking to implement standards. That's why sites like MDN exist, to provide reference lists similar to the specifications except in a way that is accessible to authors.

So what does Stack Overflow Documentation intend to achieve? The [Documentation tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/documentation) makes it a point to emphasize its example-centric nature:

> #### It's all about examples.
>
> Examples illustrate common tasks or solutions to common problems - remember "Show, Don't Tell". A good example is self-contained and succinct, and more often than not contains code. It is more important that code in examples be illustrative and focused than that it be copy/paste-able; leave out boilerplate when it distracts from the concept the example is meant to illustrate.
>
> Because our goal is to ensure developers always have great examples, topics can't be created without at least one example.
>
> In addition to examples, a topic has some optional sections. These serve to make examples more succinct, by allowing for documentation of common parameters, syntax, and other remarks that would otherwise need to be duplicated between examples.

Notice that the third paragraph makes a clear distinction between examples and sections. Obviously since HTML and CSS aren't "programming languages" in the traditional sense of the word, the Parameters section doesn't really make sense. But I think the Syntax and Remarks sections are actually the best place for reference-like examples to go. For instance, the Syntax section can list the grammar and possible values of each property in a specific CSS module, or single-line examples of how to write each selector.

Now look at [Documentation for CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/topics). Look at the topics. Open a topic and look at the examples. Are those real-world examples showing you how to design and implement a specific pattern, widget or module in HTML and CSS, or are those discrete sections each describing a CSS property or selector?

Also notice how examples are sorted. They're not sorted in any meaningful order except for votes. So, in a topic for [the `background` family of properties](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/296/backgrounds), an example for a specific background property gets voted above another example for another specific background property. You would think that the higher property is thematically the "first" property, but no, it's higher simply because more users upvoted it. That doesn't make any sense. You don't see a W3C CSS spec where the propdefs are sorted by how many users liked this property more than that other property. You don't even see an MDN document where properties are sorted that way. Because it simply doesn't make sense to sort sections of properties this way.

Real-world, self-contained, complete code examples are different. They *can* be sorted by popularity, because you want to see what the more popular patterns and techniques are. That's where sorting by votes makes sense. And that, based on my understanding, is what Documentation is trying to be.

Not just Yet Another Reference Guide to CSS, or just another MDN clone. We have enough of that already. MDN isn't perfect, but it's as good as it gets. Even so, it doesn't have to be perfect; there already exists an authoritative source in the form of W3C CSS specifications, maintained by the working group themselves.<sup>1</sup>

What Documentation is trying to achieve, is making use of the technical details from MDN and the official specifications, to build real-world code examples that authors can *put into practice*.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>This is why I almost never use any other source as a reference except the spec itself when answering questions (and why I will continue to do so), despite the fact that it was never intended for authors. But I do so because I'm capable of applying what's covered in the spec to my answer or to the subject matter of the question I'm answering in a way that is meaningful to readers.</sub>

Comment: *"Real-world, self-contained, complete code examples are different. They can be sorted by popularity, because you want to see what the more popular patterns and techniques are."* This implies that all of the examples within a section should basically be equivalent, simply offering different ways of completing the same (or similar) task. Which seems pretty stupid. Obviously there should be a canonical way that documentation would encourage, not a bunch of random different possibilities that the community can vote on. Also, they clearly misnamed it. Should've been "Stack Overflow Cargo Cult."

Comment: @Cody Gray: Each example is meant to accomplish a unique task. These tasks are then grouped by topic. Having multiple examples that all aim to accomplish the same thing, albeit in different ways, is indeed stupid.

Comment: Then having the sort order determined by votes doesn't make sense. Which means I don't understand your answer. Why should "splitting a string" be sorted above "determining the length of a string"? Why should "changing the bullet style for an unordered list" be sorted above "creating an unordered list"? This defies logic and makes the documentation more difficult to understand.

Comment: @Cody Gray: In that case, let's agree that being able to vote on individual examples at all is asinine.

Comment: Well, it still makes sense to allow voting as a measure of quality. If an example is wrong, misleading, or useless, then one would vote it down. Not sure about voting it up, though. Arguably that is useless. I'm a big fan of downvoting. :-)

Comment: @Cody Gray: I always forget about that.

Comment: This answer doesn't make it any less muddy to me.. When the official docs already have great examples of usage, do examples of said methods also still belong here? because... that's what's happening.

Comment: @Kevin B: Admittedly, my answer is somewhat specific to CSS, seeing that the question discusses a problem that affects CSS more than other languages. The official docs most certainly don't have much in the way of real-world examples.

Comment: This helped me clear my head a bit better about what the intent is now. The tour is lacking a major detail .... that's it's ***not supposed to be like*** the cited resources. It doesn't help that some of the private beta content made it appear that every html element or all css properties needed to be documented and mass perception seems to be that it should include everything and anything

Comment: The help docs don't help either to educate people either as far as what Documentation is not intended to be. Neither do the rejection reasons

Comment: @charlietfl: I feel like the only way to educate people (at least, those who care) is to have at least one tag that acts as a model for what Documentation is supposed to be, with everything done right. After all, Documentation is all about learning by example, right?

Comment: @BoltClock assumes they would look at that tag. A one time mandatory interactive presentation of good and bad examples before being able to edit/review etc makes sense to me. Can be used as a point of reference for rejections also

Comment: @charlietfl, your comments re tour and help should be a separate question(feature request)

Comment: @charlietfl, Michael Freidgeim: [Nicol Bolas has posted such a request.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329291/documentation-by-example-example-of-good-documentation)