# Can Documentation go back to private beta?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, documentation

There are still a lot of bugs in Documentation, many people saying how bad it is (because it actually is), edit wars on every example that gets more than 20 votes up, many people trying to get their hands into some reputation, a broken system for making new tags, no way to merge topics from one tag into another (something that is crucial to growth, as a tag may be split into others as content grows), etc., etc.

I think for some reason there was a rush to launch it, and it went wrong.

There really has to be more work on the edit approval system. Right now it leads to ever-changing content.

There also need to be clearer rules on what a topic should be and what an example should be.

I was in the private beta, and a lot people were saying a lot should change, but it didn't. The content was good in the private beta, because the people on it were clearly dedicated to creating good content. That is not happening right now because the system does not protect good content at all.

People should have +X reputation in the "tag" to approve, and an example with many votes up should need much more approvals than a newly created one. Topic creation, topic deletion, and example deletion should be even more restricted. But these are just some ideas, we never had the chance to discuss these ideas, and what we've got right now is not working at all.

There were bugs in the private beta that were never addressed properly, and they persist now.

Let's admit something went wrong, go back to a private beta, **have a real discussion**, and then increase the number of users in batches (of 10.000, for example) until the rules are clear and content is limited, but good, and then launch it again.

---

**UPDATE AFTER DECLINE**

Since although the request had support from the community, it has been declined by SO, I encourage everyone to come up with ideas to make documentation great.

Also I think SO should rethink this decision, given that [some users explained perfectly what's going on with this public beta right now](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329513/2002588) (even in the most voted answer to this question), and doing so they received a lot of support from the community. Their forecast is not good at all, and I agree with it.

Comment: I'm not confident that we've got enough people in the private beta to have really identified emergent pain points with the system.  I'm not sure going *back* to a private beta would solve those points.

Comment: **This, this, this!** That would probably be the best way of handling this whole situation.

Comment: @Makoto I would respond the same I said in chat since day 0: [if you believe you aren't getting enough stress you keep pushing it gradually, you don't open the floodgates all the way](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31845982#31845982)

Comment: @Makoto I think the public beta has gone on long enough. Everyone sees there are issues with almost every part of the system, and I don't just mean bugs.

Comment: Yup, I agree with @Makoto, the main purpose of the public beta currently is to test out the features of Documentation and the system itself with a larger of group of audience. Private Beta has too limited users and many bugs can't be reproduced

Comment: @luweiqi why had SE go from virtually no users to a massive flood of users?

Comment: @Braiam:  I was also in the private beta, but y'know, I didn't really get a chance to kick the tires or really stress things out enough to see what could've broken.  Now we realize there are quite a few issues, but that I feel was largely possible due to the sheer volume of users and discussions happening around it.  I don't disagree that ramping up is better than an in-or-out beta, but I also don't think that reverting to a private beta is a solution, either.

Comment: @Braiam There was around 2k users in the private beta

Comment: @luweiqi There were a lot of bugs reported in the private beta, and they never were fixed. To stress test the system, you can add +10000 users in one day.

Comment: @Makoto well, at this point I only see two options: wait till it crash and burn or abort the baby now and save our pains and suffering. From a results point of view, I think we invest less resources aborting now than waiting.

Comment: True too, I personally reported a lot of bugs in Docs-beta *(and was ranked 7th in the beta in terms of rep)*

Comment: Bugs is only one issue. The whole system isn't robust enough to even do what it needs to do and certainly isn't intuitive.

Comment: Going back to a private beta alone won't help, someone needs to come out and actually state what the actual point of the whole thing is and how it is *supposed* to work. Preferably, with an example as [suggested by Nicol Bolas](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329291/1324033). "Examples, examples, examples"

Comment: @Sayse Of course it wont, but it is a good way to start. After that, we would need to have a big discussion about why the public beta failed.

Comment: One thing that does exist now is lots of bad examples, and lots of examples of what the whole thing is not intended to do such as duplicate existing documentation. There definitely needs to be a better education process

Comment: This sounds like a good idea. I would even recommend to go back to the alpha stage so they deeply rethink the whole stuff.

Comment: If they found the issues in private beta, why wouldn't they have solved them there?

Comment: Maybe the *get people to feel like they belong so they work for you for free and then get people addicted to something (reputation in this case)* business model is thriving on the internet, take almost all the grown up web companies as an example.

Comment: I signed up for the private beta but was never even invited to it

Comment: The ability to comment on topics is a good proposal to improve the quality while reducing the number of edits and avoid associated rudeness: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328895/why-are-there-no-comment-features-for-examples

Comment: Why would batches of 10 people be useful?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It's extremely bad to 'flicker' like that, and I'll explain why. This is going to be a little long-winded, so if you're short on time:

> **tl;dr**: Docs would be an inferior product compared to what it could have been if we did this; it's much better to deal with some cleanup as needed.

By 'flickering', I mean precisely what you're suggesting, which is taking a product that's been out in public beta for more than a few hours and making it private again. As someone that has shipped *a lot* of software in my career as a developer, doing this has *always* turned out to be a major mistake.

We went public because we *knew* we had gone as far as we possibly could with feedback from a small group of testers and people working at the company. You can't build in an echo chamber.

#### We know what we need to work on because it has been public this long.

We can't go back to a tight-knit group of people testing documentation, even if that group grew larger, because closed groups quickly become snow blind to things that are missing or sub optimal. Let's say we pulled it back now, and worked immediately on the larger friction points - *how would we know that we're not making it worse with such a limited group testing it?* And then we go public again, and *uh oh*. It has to stay out.

This iterative process really needs to happen while the product is *fully* in the hands of the people that want to use it. Closed betas become echo chambers after some time passes, we can't go back to that at this point.

#### There's too much ownership and enthusiasm to lose

*A ton* of documentation has been written by *many* people, and in order to finish building this system, *we need to hold their interest*. Turning off everything they've done for a while is pretty antithetical to that goal; we'd only get a percentage of them back.

I'd rather clean up some messes than yank the rug out from *everyone*, even if it's just for a few weeks. *You never get that kind of enthusiasm and river of ideas back*.

When Q&A launched there were more than a few that were really worried about what it was missing, it went on to do rather well.

#### It is our top priority as a company to bring Documentation to a mature product

We are iterating *very* fast, we're getting really good and actionable feedback, and we're making what I think are very good decisions about what to do next. We need this feedback to continue with that degree of momentum.

There is a whole team of people, Kevin included, who have no other task but pushing forward with what Documentation needs as quickly and responsibly as possible. None of this is getting done 'someday', it's getting done ***right now.***

#### It *is* early beta, we anticipate some cleanup

The reason that we didn't give a whole ton of guidance on what to create and how to organize it is because *you, as the largest group of developers on Planet Earth are a lot better at figuring that out together.* We're here to help guide it, but we need to see how you actually want to *use* it, and work to support the best use cases.

We got more insight in the last week than we did during the entire private beta period, and it would be a *really big* mistake to risk that.

You don't need to worry too much about it, we can fix anything that needs fixing or reorganized once we've firmly settled in how everything works. What we can't do is bring back all of the participation that we'd lose if we shut it down for a while, which makes the decision pretty clear for us.

I know it seems rough, I know it's missing things - but we're on it, and we'll take care of it. If you want to help, please just help us aim for the best *possible* feature-complete product that we can hit, and [we'll go that way really fast](https://blog.codinghorror.com/go-that-way-really-fast/) ;)

Comment: Can we start with removing all the default subtitles for "Examples, Syntax, Parameters, Remarks" and just let it flow naturally? It's great that there's organization, but it's not a working format yet. I'd love if we could let it be open for a bit, and see what patterns emerge organically. So far I've seen examples being pinned to the top which aren't actually examples, but more of an introduction.

Comment: @4castle You think it's really just enough guidance to make people feel really awkward about there not being more? We could possibly go at it from more of a _feature_ standpoint, I gotta think about it more.

Comment: "*A ton of documentation has been written by many people, and in order to finish building this system, we need to hold their interest.*" Considering the *quality* of information, holding their interest sounds like a *really bad idea*. That is, if you're interested in making good documentation. "Too big to fail" is never a good mentality to have for a project.

Comment: About the documentation already written, the system makes it very hard to protect good content that was achieved reaching consensus (which is what makes Stack Exchange amazing basically, and you as a comunnity manager must know it very well). That's why many of us are loosing enthusiasm, I think the revision in the approval system must be 1st on the review list.

Comment: @MarcoScabbiolo It is. It's the highest priority thing to push.

Comment: @NicolBolas I hear you. I don't think _anything_ is actually too big to fail (though I understand what the term conveys), I think it's a question of mitigating risks to success and to that, I'm _very_ convinced that pulling it out of public beta would be very detrimental. I'd rather work our butts off to get a few of the biggest needs out really fast, see how that goes, and then keep iterating at that kind of pace.

Comment: "which is taking a product that's been out in public beta for more than a few hours and making it private again" we aren't even asking to go private (non visible) again, but restrict the people that can do stuff with it. You can keep it public, just that less people pulling the strings behind scenes.

Comment: The syntax, parameters and remarks sections are suggestive of reference documentation, which is at odds with the examples-first/only _cookbook_ that we're told SO Docs is intended to be.  (Actually saying "we're building a cookbook" would be a great first step, whatever you do.  Or saying whatever it is you want us to build.  If you don't know either... I'm not sure what to do then.)

Comment: Can we get some more insight into what you think needs fixing? There have been a lot of discussions about what needs fixing, but I haven't really been seeing any staff marking things as [status-planned] or many notes about what things are being worked on. It would be nice to have some assurance that people are being heard.

Comment: @4castle That's a pretty darn good idea. I'm not sure that one _doesn't_ exist - gimme a few to check (there's been a lot posted in the last week here)

Comment: @TimPost [Here's the current list of things that are "status-planned"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-planned+documentation). We're missing a lot of the weightier topics.

Comment: Kevin is going to be posting our immediate plans and roadmap shortly (as he's the lead dev on it). I'll ping you @4castle when it goes out with a link so you don't miss it (though I'll probably feature it for a day or two after he posts it so everyone notices it).

Comment: @Jeffrey Based on Tim's answer ("We're here to help guide it, but we need to see how you actually want to use it...") and other responses I've seen on Meta, I get the impression that the SO team isn't going to come out and say "We want you to build a cookbook" or "We want you to build reference documentation." There are still fundamental questions about Q&A that the team has never really answered ("Are we really building a library of answers or is it ok to become a personalized debugging service?").

Comment: @Jeffrey  This leads to much hand-wringing and soul-searching on Meta, but I think the team wants it that way: they want the community to decide for itself. I disagree with that approach and wish they would just say, definitively, "No, we are *not* a personalized debugging service" or "We aren't trying to be a library of common questions and answers anymore, we want to answer *all* coherent programming questions," but I don't think they will ever do that, and I think the same thing will happen with Documentation.

Comment: "There have been a lot of discussions about what needs fixing, but I haven't really been seeing any staff marking things" In fairness, @4castle, today's only the first day after the weekend.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot That might be okay if Docs were an unstructured, free-text wiki that let us build whatever, but the tools they have given us seem intended to be used one way (cookbook) and we're trying to use them in all sorts of different ways.  I think some guidance is essential.  (But I agree, it doesn't seem forthcoming.)

Comment: *“It is our top priority as a company to bring Documentation to a mature product”* – It’s sad that this is your *top* priority. There are so many things that would need some more priority on the Q/A part. Documentation, being somewhat pushed only by the company, with the community being very spectical about it from the very first day, seems like an odd candidate for the top priority, and it certainly isn’t when you ask the community. And speaking of mature products, what happened to teams?

Comment: I'm also had to downvote this (despite some good feedback) because of the same quote as @poke - as I have a disability which makes it difficult to read sites that are as bright as SO. I can force a dark theme but the fact that stackexchange ignores issues which can improve site quality for a number of people and focuses everything on this. It is disheartening to say the *least*

Comment: Here is the real risk for the SO company. The users you most want contributing to Documentation are losing or may lose interest in contributing with the sorts of things that are wrong with it. Worse, the horribly designed rep system may contribute to some of the same valuable users losing interest in SO Q&A as well. Don't be blinded by a "defeat is not an option" mindset.

Comment: Thank you for the TL;DR, I appreciate your enthusiasms for thug livers like me.

Comment: @JGreenwell: "*the fact that stackexchange ignores issues which can improve site quality for a number of people and focuses everything on this.*" To be fair, if Docs.SO were actually *good*, then it would improve things for more people than those like yourself. Also, if SO has not implemented a dark theme in *eight years*, they're certainly not going to start now.

Comment: @NicolBolas I used the dark theme issue as an example, one that was mentioned [2 years ago](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274388/why-is-there-no-dark-theme-on-so) and the flashing blue lights reminded me of. The real point is that by making SOD a top priority SO is missing a number of issues which are higher priorities for its users. Btw. epilepsy is estimated [to affect 2.2 mil people](http://www.epilepsy.com/learn/epilepsy-statistics) and TBI about [1.7 mil](https://www.cdc.gov/traumaticbraininjury/pdf/bluebook_factsheet-a.pdf) - only two of the conditions with photosensitivity

Comment: You don't go in beta with just your fingers crossed. You got the technical part right but the `know your target` part you failed at. Do us users need the kind of 'documentation' that you push through? What profile of developers asked for it? What did they want? For many people, what you term documentation isn't, it is a 'how-to` database. You push things and oh well move fast break things, time will tell, and well we'll tune it. People create for free the value that you are reaping through your equity stake. At least KNOW YOUR USERS. Because this chaos makes it look like you don't.

Comment: @JGreenwell: Those statistics are only for the United States. One country, among one hundred and ninety six. There are in fact more like 22 million epilepsy sufferers.

Comment: @user3743222: Yeah I hate this _"move fast break things"_ nonsense. Maybe it's good at generating revenue (until the bubble bursts, that is) but it makes for a horrendous end user experience, and I'd expect a company of software experts to know that.

Comment: The private beta was not exhausted because not everyone who signed up for it was added to it e.g. me

Comment: It's nice that it's your top priority, but you risk losing interest of the experts and a lot of bad publicity if you don't fix and improve Documentation soon (6-8 weeks would probably be too long). Just don't say afterwards you weren't warned. :)

Comment: @rdans Not that it terribly matters now, but... when did you sign up? As far as I know, we invited (or at least attempted to invite) everyone who was on the list. If we missed you, I'm sorry about that. It was certainly not intentional - the plan was always to invite everyone before swapping back to SO for public beta.

Comment: "you, as the largest group of developers on Planet Earth are a lot better at figuring that out together" Apparently, what web developers figured out was that they wanted to make an [MDN clone](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328804/should-we-prevent-too-granular-documentation-that-already-exists-elsewhere/328898#328898). The result is something that's worse than even *W3Schools*. I shudder to imagine what would happen if those same people piled themselves all over MDN.

Answer (score 174):

There is a general sense among Stack Exchange personnel that Documentation.SO is a good system, it just needs time to cook. That a few tweaks here and there, a change to the rep system, a few rate limits, fixing the tons and tons of bugs, just give it time to be adjusted and we'll make it all better.

To this, I say:

***The Emperor Has No Clothes***

Docs.SO is not a good system. It won't become a good system with a few tweaks. It is not a good idea struggling to get out from under the weight of bugs. Why?

Because it's not an idea at all.

Ideas have *coherency*, and thus far, there is nothing even *remotely* coherent about Docs.SO. Nobody seems to know what it is. Nobody seems to be able to say [what Docs.SO is supposed to look like when it's working](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329291/documentation-by-example-example-of-good-documentation?noredirect=1&lq=1). Nobody seems to have a consistent view of what a "topic" should and shouldn't be, what an "example" should and shouldn't be. Nobody even [knows what it means to up/downvote an example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329329/what-is-the-purpose-of-voting-on-documentation).

If you can't even answer basic questions like that, then it's not a coherent idea.

Stack Overflow was a coherent idea, even in its formative stages. Did it have lots of what we would now consider crap? Sure. But even in its formative stages, we had a firm understanding of what Q&A was about as a *concept*. We knew that we wanted to discourage discussion, and we knew we wanted to use Q&A to build a knowledgebase.

Where is a similar declaration of principles for Docs.SO? Without that, it's simply a naked guy. A poorly conceived thing that's being forced on everyone because the guy is in charge.

Stop trying to make "Fetch" happen; it's *not going to happen!*

Comment: It used to be that I fought with you on this, but since then I've actually used Docs, and I can confirm that all of this is true.

Comment: I must agree with you. They probably thought: "*ok most people just come to SO to get a code snippet to get something going, let's give them exactly that.*". And they went public telling us "*make examples about code, and let everybody play with this.*" Let's change the name to **Random code snippets constantly changing**

Comment: At the risk of being completely unconstructive: thank you.

Comment: @MarcoScabbiolo +1. Amazingly, when I upvote an example it retains my upvote even after it was rewritten from scratch.

Comment: "Nobody seems to know what it is." That may be exxagerated a little bit. It's example centric documentation for things that haven't already a good documentation. And I actually have a very good idea what an example is. Still I agree. They haven't thought it through. Somewhere in their minds is still a big miracle/black box that magically ties up all lose ends. This happens mostly if you have answers to only 80% of the important questions and think this is enough.

Comment: Voting on an example: Up - This example is clear and useful in the context of this topic, Down - This example is unclear and/or not useful in the context of this topic.

Comment: Topic: A somewhat complete field of problems in the tag that can all be solved by a single or a few strategies and set themselves apart from the rest by some common element. For the optimal size: say the equvalent of 5-10 related questions on the Q&A part. (This is just a try to define it to show it is actually possible to do that.)

Comment: @Trilarion: "*Up - This example is clear and useful in the context of this topic*" Does that mean that it is more useful than the examples above or below it? Because that's the effect that upvoting it has. "*Down - This example is unclear and/or no useful in the context of this topic.*" Then why is it in the documentation at all? If it's outdated, make that clear in the text. If it's needlessly suboptimal or just flat-out garbage code, *delete it*.

Comment: "Does that mean that it is more useful than the examples above or below it?" But this is the usual stuff you have for Q&A here. Also there the up vote button text doesn't say "more useful than others". Just vote all up that you deem useful and vote all down that you wouldn't want to have as example for the topic. It works the same way as in Q&A (I guess).

Comment: @Trilarion but when there is a question, the answer is yes: "this answer provides better answer than the others here." and of course you can think that multiple answers possess this property. And yes that's a problem when new answers are added later.

Comment: @Elazar But that's exactly the same way as voting on Q&A. The problem here is that rep is currently multiplicative not shared. The voting is okay as far as I can see it. If you are worried about new answers added later, include a mechanism to let old votes fade away. That was already proposed several times.

Comment: @Trilarion: "*But that's exactly the same way as voting on Q&A.*" No, it's not. Some answers answer a question better than others. But every example in a topic deals with a specific, and in many cases *different* aspect of the topic. None are *objectively* better than others. An example is either good at showing what it shows, or it should be edited or deleted.

Comment: It is as if there should be a "use case" and competing examples, voted as answers.

Comment: @Elazar: You mean like a [task?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329183/734069) With examples as different ways of achieving the same task?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Yeah I guess so. I don't see the competition part in your post but I generally agree.

Comment: There aren't enough points awardable for how acutely accurate this answer is. Thank you @NicolBolas for articulating the profoundly obvious in a way that even the tone deaf, myopic and delusional might see, hear and comprehend. Design is important. This SO.docs has nought but a dream.

Answer (score 17):

You know how this can be done: restrict access to the tooling to everyone but a handful.

Right now we are all pulling the rope to opposite sides and not saving the little kitten. We are in-fighting with the current tools, between contributors, between reviewers, between everything and getting *absolutely nothing done*, not even badly done.

You need fewer people calling the shots and fewer hands into the jar! Fewer people able to submit stuff and fewer people able to review it. At least, that way we can solve stuff that doesn't present itself when you scale, to then solve the problem of scale. Having fewer problems to solve all at once is more productive than having all the problems cropping up and trying to solve them at the same time. Let's focus on one problem, which I believe the most important is: what's expected of this thing. Then when we figure out that, we can start tackling the scale problems or whatever becomes the next thing.

Comment: This is hyperbolic. We're talking about a site that gets thousands of answers a day, most seen only by a few people; if we survive that, I don't think edits to a wiki are going to kill kittens. The system you're describing existed in the form of tag wikis for *years*, and even though it was gated by a considerable rep threshold there've still been widespread problems with plagiarism and general apathy. You may be unaware of this, but if so only because that system is... Mostly unused. Designing a system that no one uses isn't a good use of anyone's time.

Comment: @Shog9 *"Designing a system that no one uses isn't a good use of anyone's time."* Hence why people want to take this down and start fresh with clear goals in mind.

Comment: @Shog9: "*You may be unaware of this, but if so only because that system is... Mostly unused.*" Of course Tag Wikis were mostly unusable. It was a feature that A) wasn't easily discover-able, and B) wasn't indexed in searches. If the powers that be bothered to actually make the feature able to be used, then people would use it.

Comment: @Shog9 Not sure it's better to have a poorly designed system widely used. I'm curious to see how you'll deal with all the top-voted crappy content we currently have.

Comment: What exactly do you think Docs is, @Nicol? Based on your frequent rants, I get the feeling you want it to be a Sharepoint-style CMS with ownership and tons of control over who can edit what, when. It's not. It's a wiki. Attached to tags. With proper search indexing, titles, and hopefully a lot more discoverable. And whadda ya know, you're right - folks are actually using it... Which is why Braiam here is so unhappy.

Comment: @Shog9: "*It's not. It's a wiki.*" No, it isn't. A Wiki is just text. A Wiki allows *users* to decide what the organizational scheme is, not have one imposed upon them. A Wiki allows the users to decide the order information is presented in. Docs.SO is not a functional wiki. "*folks are actually using it*" To create tons and tons of crap. I fail to see how that's an improvement. At least the few curated tag wikis *didn't suck*. I'd much rather have a rarely used feature that is sometimes used well than a frequently used feature that is always used terribly.

Comment: @Shog9: Also, characterizing the opposition as "ranting" simply because they oppose something is not an effective way to convince people that the system is working fine. I always put forth reasoning for my positions. Thus far, you have not. You simply say that it will work itself out. That's not an answer. Showing that the system is working fine, or at least that the system *could* work fine, is a more effective way.

Comment: I'm not characterizing "the opposition" as ranting, @Nicol. *You* are ranting. Multiple back-to-back comments, hyperbole, responses that barely acknowledge what you're responding to before dropping back to a repetition of whatever criticism you feel isn't being heard. That's ranting. It's certainly not discussion. In months, your argument hasn't changed: I get it, you want a system with a different structure and much, much more editorial control. That isn't this system though. It might not be suitable for your purposes. If you need a sportscar, don't go to the truck dealer.

Comment: @Shog9: "*I get it, you want a system with a different structure and much, much more editorial control.*" Then you don't get it. It's not about what ***I*** want. It's about what *you need* in order to be able to get multiple people to build documentation like this successfully. You *need* an overarching vision. You *need* to give the concepts in your documentation real meaning that everyone understands. You *need* to give people the ability to build structure as they see fit for the specific needs of a system. Otherwise, all you'll have is a disorganized code-dump.

Comment: @Shog9 - Sorry man, I totally agree with Nicol on this, you are off base and everything this post mentions is spot on.  I know Tim Post suggested keeping it out in the open - wild have you - but I'm sure your internal developers hate you guys right now.

Comment: Uh... Whose idea do you think Docs *was*, @JonH. It ain't like CMs or accountants or salespeople or execs are sitting around thinking to themselves, "y'know what would really make my life better? Decent programming docs." This was Kevin's idea, and he's dedicated a pretty big chunk of his last year to making it happen. You don't have to believe that, and y'all can continue ignoring the past 11 months of discussion regarding it in favor of your conspiracy theories if you want... But I don't have to pretend to take them seriously.

Comment: Take it easy. My hates you comment was basically saying devs dont apprecite that much stress. Sorry about that.

Comment: Sorry, @Jon. Of course, no one appreciates stress. The devs are putting a lot into this, and Tim & I are doing what we can to support them. That said, spirited debate is one thing; a couple of folks were getting pretty personal in their criticisms of the dev team earlier, and I don't think that's appropriate. I'm pretty happy to be part of an organization that supports and listens to its developers, that *doesn't* strip them of influence. If that's not where you were going, I sincerely apologize.

Comment: I agree i didnt mean it in such a way. Hate is such a hateful word i wanted to kid but it didnt come across that way. I look at this project similar to jobs/careers. It started off rough but ended up quite nicely. Its not perfect but its always a work in progress. We as the general SO public need to be patient and give it time. I believe in Kevins work because he is a smart guy so i trust it will get better.

Comment: _"Let's focus on one problem"_ Yeah, like Q&A!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think Documentation should go back to private beta. Instead there is a need for someone that sets the direction towards a vision and someone to ensure that the ongoing work is on the correct path to that vision. Unfortunately I don't see that.

After reading the tour, I was very much in the mood: "Yes, this is what we need" but after reading what has been made so far (in the tags I follow), I was disappointed. The current documentation is no help to anyone.

Also I can't see that it is any where near what the tour describes. Maybe I didn't get the real intend of Documentation after reading the tour but I expected it to deal with typical problems (i.e. typically questions) and give a good detailed description of different aspects of solutions (i.e. collecting the best from the best answers). Something like that could be linked when the same question was asked for the 20'th time.

So my view is that Documentation is currently going in the wrong direction. But that doesn't mean it should be "closed" - rather it should be (friendly) pushed in a better direction.

As an example:

In the "C Language" the highest rated topic is "Hello world". I don't see that matching this quote from the tour: "We can do better. You can help."

Comment: "In the "C Language" the highest rated topic is "Hello world"" It's what contributors provided. And it's what people usually do first when learning a new language, to get started. Probably contributors just tried to reproduce existing documentation approaches. It's all about need / It's all about examples. The question is: Do we need "Hello World" examples? This is a serious question from me because I'm not sure if we need them or not. The second thing is how to find all that needed and cool examples. The topics are just a long badly ordered list.

Answer (score -9):

I don't believe that anything will be gained by going back to private beta as it was a week ago: a separate site, very limited set of users, **no ability to *link* to anything on the main site**.

Let's face it: information that no one but the authors and a tiny group of editors can read isn't much good; you're not really "documenting" anything if what you write stays private. Yet, that's what we had in private beta: a system where you could play around with the mechanics of the editor, pretend you were writing something that might be useful... But which wouldn't actually get read by anyone who needed it. Tests of voting behavior, topic/improvement requests, the behavior of the reputation model... Were all kinda just play-acting. At some point, to know how this thing's gonna actually work, to know which concerns have merit, to know what *everyone has missed...* You gotta actually be able to show it to folks.

Now, it would've been nice to have a bit more of a gradual rollout *on Stack Overflow*, purely from a support perspective. But, I'm not sure that would've been any less chaotic. Sooner or later, all of this stuff is gonna have to be fixed, one way or another; at some point, artificially hiding problems by constraining availability is counter productive. By the same token, it's silly to talk about having a "real discussion" while excluding the majority of people who'd be interested in having it.

We'll be working hard to review, triage, and fix problems. And discussion of the system is now open to *all* users of Stack Overflow, not just the handful who signed up for the beta. The success or failure of the system will be determined by how all of us participate in this.

Comment: At least going back to beta would give you time to define what's a good tag/topic/example, and write proper guidelines about _what_ people should do with this whole Documentation thing. Currently it's a mess, and if you don't mitigate the useless/bad tags/topics/examples propagation, it might not be possible to remove all that garbage later.

Comment: You can have private access to the interactive tools (editing, submitting, reviewing) and still be publicly. What we need right now is less people with full access.

Comment: Meh. I was around for the private beta of Q&A, and I was around for the private beta of docs. Neither one was as chock-full of high-quality stuff as folks like to remember. You don't refine gold by carefully protecting the ore from the heat.

Comment: Can fix breakdowns in a Volkswagen that you try to race, but will never make it a Formula One car that was designed for that purpose

Comment: Obviously writing proper guidelines won't solve the issue we have now with people using it to re-create existing documentation, since the tour specifically states it is not for that, and yet that's what is happening (and being re-enforced with upvotes!). Needs more just in time training or something.

Comment: When we say "private beta", we're basically asking you to stop allowing people to contribute content. The whole ideology with "examples" has become cancerous. I've yet to see any effective documentation practices which don't just get bulldozed by someone else so they can get rep.

Comment: @Shog9: "*You don't refine gold by carefully protecting the ore from the heat.*" You don't refine gold by pretending that ore is already refined and just handing it to people either. The *basic model and purpose* of Docs.SO is confusing and poorly defined. By contrast, the basic model of Q&A was very well explained, and people are able to get the general gist almost immediately.

Comment: That can be accomplished with rep-limits and rate-limits, @4castle. Which already exist, and can (and probably should) be adjusted. "Private beta" implies limited availability: a select group of users can use it, no one else. Very few people can write anything useful with no intended audience and no feedback.

Comment: I understand that in addition to being an outsourcer for Tech Support, SO aims to become the same for documentation.  You need to make money and that's understandable. You either do not have a clear concept of what your new product is or you have reasons to withhold it.

Comment: You overlooked the possibility that I'm just a being of pure evil and enjoy cackling maniacally while perching my hands together with just the tips of the fingers touching, @PM77-1. There may be other possibilities as well, but let's try and focus on the negative here. Or, y'know, ask an actual question if you're unclear about something.

Comment: From [Tim's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329469/2055998): "The reason that we didn't give a whole ton of guidance on what to create and how to organize it is because... " I was mostly commenting on this concept. He actually gave his reason for "*withholding it*". I also believe that it's an understatement.  Sounds more like "... we didn't give almost any ...".

Comment: In all seriousness, @PM77-1: I'm not gonna even try to address that in a comment thread; it took me about an hour to get through it in chat yesterday, and that was close to real-time. If you're curious about what Tim's getting at in that statement, post a question and I'll try & elaborate in the space of an answer; alternately, [drop into chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117558/documentation-public-beta) if you'd rather have a more informal conversation.

Comment: _"The success or failure of the system will be determined by how all of us participate in this."_ To be blunt, the problem with this is that a massive chunk of "us" (and I mean like one or two _million_ people) are morons. You only need to spend an hour in the review queues to see that. :(

Comment: `you're not really "documenting" anything if what you write stays private` I _beg_ your pardon? That's like telling an aspiring band that they're not musicians until a record producer listens to their demo. Actually, the visibility bar you're setting (public beta, accessible to all SO users) is more like telling them that they're not musicians until they're featured on MTV. Absolutely laughable.

Comment: If you wanna play guitar in your room and call yourself a musician, go right ahead @Tigerhawk. Don't expect others to do so though.

Comment: "I don't believe that anything will be gained..." Hmm. What about more time to fix the obvious bugs and less wasted time of the contributors? I think that would be something. The alternative would be we just don't contribute anymore until SO fixes Documentation but that would be close to a fail, wouldn't it?

Comment: More time to fix the bugs we didn't see until folks actually started using it en masse? Don't use it if you don't want to, @Trilarion; no one's making you.

Comment: @Shog9 I know, however if noone does. it might become a failure. We all want to do it right, we just differ about the best way. I don't really count me as an expert, but you'll see if the current format or anything that can be fixed in the near future can attract enough experienced people to make it really good. Maybe, maybe not.

Comment: If you want to raise children who never become famous and call yourself a father, go right ahead. Don't expect others to do so, though. Kim Kardashian's dad, though? Now _that's_ a father!

Comment: I don't think attenuating the access would be "artificially hiding problems"... it would be preventing them from occurring on the scale that they did. I believe the problems that have occurred would probably have occurred even if we had stayed in closed beta for more than a day or rolled out access more gradually. The key second part of that belief though is that I think those problems would've happened on a *much smaller scale*. The sheer scale of the problems (frequency, if you will) is what has led to the massive outcry/swell of criticism, in my opinion.

Comment: But that's nothing that battening down the hatches and a thorough postmortem can't fix.

Comment: @Shog9 "If you wanna play guitar in your room…": playing on stage when you are not ready to play yet, won't make people call you a musician either. They will boo you off-stage instead. Put aside that the whole guitarist analogy doesn't really work too well, I think that Docs went on stage too early. People are booing. No one is calling Docs a musician right now.

Comment: @Shog9 "More time to fix the bugs we didn't see until folks actually started using it en masse?" I just now tried to review and run into editing conflicts which were difficult to solve. I find it somewhat hard to believe you didn't think about editing conflicts until the start of the open beta. They are somewhat at the heart of collaborative editing and not trivial. I guess at least now we should think about section wise updates and temporary locking of edits if there are too many unreviewed concurring edits on the same topic/section of a topic. It's annoying as it is.

Comment: Getting booed isn't fun, but it's still an important lesson, @Gordon.

Comment: We *thought* a lot about edit conflicts, @Trilarion. Even built in things to help avoid them. No substitute for actually seeing how folks run into them in practice though. Some of the most important lessons here have been things that only happen at scale, situations like those surrounding that Java Arrays topic - that's just not something that happens with a small, self-selected group of people.

Comment: @Shog9 yes, valuable learnings. Still, you could have had that from playing smaller stages first instead of the center stage at prime time so to say. But I guess it's too late for that now.

Comment: In theory, sure. We could've limited this to a subset of *tags*, for instance @Gordon - if we'd started with *just* C# or *just* JavaScript, that'd have cut down traffic considerably while still exposing some of the same issues. I suspect that if we hadn't stayed in private beta so long, we'd probably have done something like that. But, there's no going back now.