# What makes something relevant and/or important enough to warrant a topic?

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-topics

I recently [responded to a request](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/2435/ipython#t=20160722144210427) for an `IPython` topic, but it was promptly deleted. An instead an IPython "example" was placed on the [Introduction to Python](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/193/introduction-to-python/7847/ipython#t=201607221532012940745) page (not by the same user, I believe). IPython has [many features](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)—it would take more than one example to document them properly.

[This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328458/what-kind-of-topics-should-i-document) is a similar and related question; please delete this if it is not distinct enough to warrant its own post.