# Is it ok to reject a documentation change request that is a clone of the existing official documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation, plagiarism

I just participated in the creation of a new tag and some changes have went in. It just happens that those changes are exactly the official documentation pasted into Stack Overflow. I rejected those changes as copy with no credit.

My questions are :

- is that a sound judgement? Or is OK to copy paste **official** documentation from other sites; they generally are free of license so I don't think that would be a problem here.

Comment: *Always* reject plagiarized and/or unattributed content.

Comment: I think the wording should be changed... IMO, copying official docs content to SO docs should not be done, even if attribution is given.... We're looking to fill in the gaps here with original content and useful examples that you can't find in the official docs...

Comment: But what if the official documentation is written by the same person that creates the entry on SO, in that case it is not plagiarized.

Comment: See Daniel's comment above, @MarkRotteveel, and [the original announcement](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow) "If a project already has awesome documentation that's easy to search and cite, then there's no need to duplicate it". It is _explicitly_ an anti-goal for SO Docs to simply reproduce existing material, regardless of who the original author is.

Comment: Alright, I guess that makes it clear.