# Should Documentation links point to external or internal resources?

Tags: discussion, documentation, external-links

This came up while discussing an edit to one of the Haskell documentation pages. A user proposed an edit to change a link to `Data.Text` from [Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.1/docs/Data-Text.html), where the official, core documentation is about the pacakage, to an [internal](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/haskell/3406/data-text) link to SO Documentation for `Data.Text`.

It seems to me that external links can provide more value (since we aren't going to replicate all of the information about functions and  type signatures or the source code internally) by pointing someone back to the original documentation for the package while still providing additional explanations and examples.

On the other hand, SO.Documentation is, at least in part, built around the idea of "No more broken links" as discussed in the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/documentation). Should we have external links in the documentation? If not, should we replicate all of the relevant information inside the documentation?

Comment: Related, from the other side of the pond [How to make topics redirect to the better, existing documentation?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329669)

Answer (score 1):

Internal links are completely OK, since they wouldn't go down before Documentation goes down.

External links shouldn't be discouraged, I think. Many languages & frameworks are already well-documented ([example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html)) - we would just reinvent the wheel by replicating existing documentation instead of giving links.