# Rolling back plagiarism rejected

Tags: discussion, documentation, plagiarism, proposed-changes, documentation-review

I recently [proposed a change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/134118?filter-tags=symfony) to documentation to roll back [plagiarism](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/134075?filter-tags=symfony). The content had been completely copied from the [symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html).

Naturally my change was rejected.

How to get this plagiarized content removed and is there a different approach I should take in the future?

Comment: [Apparently deleting it isn't workable either](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/346082/792066)

Comment: There we go https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/134120?filter-tags=symfony

Comment: *"Excellent. Thanks ... Undo♦"*  Heh... how apropos :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There were two reviewers who rejected your proposed change. One of them was banned from review because of failed audits shortly after rejecting your change. I manually banned the other reviewer with a message explaining their mistake.

I don't know if there's much else to be done to prevent this sort of problem. Possibly the reviewers didn't see the change comment because it's somewhat inconspicuous compared the the swaths of red removed from the example?

Comment: @PaulCrovella: Yes, the rollback should also remove any reputation gained from the proposed change. That hasn't happened yet in this case, but I expect it will be reversed in the next recalc. In the future, we might implement an automated flag to notify moderators so they can investigate and take any further action.

Comment: Flag something on the main site (like a post by the plagiarist) for moderator attention pointing to the Documentation content, so a moderator can deal with handling the content, the plagiarist and the reviewers that enabled the plagiarism to be posted in the first place.

Comment: It'd be better if people could flag Documentation content *directly* of course. Hint, hint.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yeah. That's coming soonish.

Comment: There needs to be a forum users' legal advocacy group that tracks these IP thieves down and takes legal action.  And I want my flying car too.

Comment: @PaulCrovella: I guess we are still trying to figure this all out. As a moderator I'd like to know about plagiarism, because we need to educate not only the person that did the copying, but also the reviewers that allowed copied content to be added to the site.

Comment: "I manually banned the other reviewer with a message explaining their mistake." I did not there way to send message for SO users. Can moderators send message to SO users?

Comment: @DamithRuwan: [Yes we can.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/02/moderator-messages/)

Comment: @JonEricson Thanks. can you please send me a test private message fro me? I like to see  how it works.