# Documentation that does not add much to the manual?

Tags: discussion, documentation

Several documentation pages I looked at so far (not all, and I did not do an extensive research) frankly had only little more content than the basic man page / manual every user can easily bring up themselves.

#### Example

For example, https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/git/355/rebasing/1211/local-branch-rebasing#t=201608051507536786845 , which is the documentation about `git rebase` with the most upvotes at the moment. If you do a `git help rebase`, the initial chapter of that man page explains exactly the same (and then some) in quite understandable language; the Documentation page is shorter, has copied the ASCII images and examples (in slightly different order) from the `git help rebase` and while not outright copying the text from the manual, does not add anything on top of it. In fact, it is quite close to "git rebase rebases a branch on top of another one", i.e., almost recursive definition.

Basically, the information content of the answer is the same as opening the manual and having a quick glance at the provided images.

The one sentence in the original manual which documents what the command actually *does*, "The commits ... are then reapplied to the current branch, one by one, in order", is not represented in the Documentation page. This sentence in itself would answer almost all questions a newbie could have about `rebase` (which is a pretty simple operation, but often unnecessarily shrouded in mystery or FUD).

I could of course easily just improve this Documentation myself, no problem. But I do note that a similar effect appears again and again: very light documentation where the user would maybe be better served by reading the original manual.

I would also not bother about this if this did not happen to be the question with the most upvotes by far on that topic.

So, to sum it up:

#### TL;DR: Question

Should a page that documents little more (or even less) than the original manual be flagged/downvoted (in case I am not able or not inclined to improve it) or is such factually correct but quite superfluous documentation, that is much approved by all other readers stumbling accross it, part of the intended goal of Documentation?

I am specifically comparing this page to the existing, original, easily accessible documentation; I am not saying that every Documentation page should be complex and heavy.

Comment: depends on the tag and how well the official docs document the feature. If the documentation here supplements the official docs, i don't see a reason *not* to have it. If it is no better, then.... it's rather useless.

Comment: Personally, I'd *much* rather have documentation for everything I need in a single, concise format that can be found via a search engine without the need to remember 100 different commands for 100 different applications. If it's literally verbatim from Git itself, I would mind a little bit because it's just a copy + paste from Git output. But not having to remember what the fuck the Git command is to bring up *that information* is **extremely useful** not only to me, but also to novices who are just starting with the language/framework/etc. PS - it took me a long time to figure out `rebase`...

Comment: @Sulthan Not literally the same format, but the same structure. As in, a topic has multiple examples. Easily browsable, searchable, etc.

Comment: A thought on this: after setting up Documentation with the existing content of the original manuals by SO users with enough time for that, the examples can be supplemented with the real smart examples. Without the first setup, Documentation would be only examples of some edge cases, i.e. not too accessible.

Comment: Ditto @ChrisCirefice. I'd rather have documentation that "reminds" me of some basic task syntax as well as documentation that adds to my info-base after the basic syntax is embedded in my brain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Several documentation pages I looked at so far (not all, and I did not do an extensive research) frankly had only little more content than the basic man page / manual every user can easily bring up themselves.

When documentation was in beta I noticed that there were pretty sparse offerings, and unfortunately I simply didn't have enough time to improve all the issues I saw.

Now that documentation is out of beta, I've seen similarly sparse documentation for many more tags. I spent some time on a few topics that I knew information about, and attempted to improve things, but frankly there has been too much changing too quickly for me to try to keep up, so I've stepped back from it to see where things are going.

I know I'm not alone in this. I've seen similar statements from a number of high-rep users.

> Should a page that documents little more (or even less) than the original manual be flagged/downvoted (in case I am not able or not inclined to improve it)

My belief is **no**, and here's why.

- Documentation is new
- Documentation is filling a void
- The void is enormous
- These things take time

Do you remember when Wikipedia came out? I know it's been a while, and many developers here are young enough that may very well not have been around for it.

I certainly remember reading Wikipedia in the early days. It was ***awful***. The content was sparse. Many links were broken. Articles kept moving. There were edit wars and lots of spammers using it.

I was in school at the time, and students were forbidden from using it as a reference (to be fair, Encyclopedias shouldn't be used as references anyway, they're useful for *finding* references and synopses of topics).

In any event. These problems went away through a lot of hard work and a lot of *time*.

Documentation is similar in scope to Wikipedia. It's deep information on a lot of topics. There are tools that need to be built and fixed for problems that we don't even know we're going to have yet.

---

So here's where I circle back to why I don't think we should downvote and flag correct but superfluous posts.

***You have to start somewhere***. It might not be the *best* information **yet**, but if you react negatively to it, it's more likely to be removed than it is to be improved.

Documentation is not the same as Q&A. When you downvote a question or answer on SO the expectation is that the author either fix it or remove it. Documentation is group owned. There's no single user who has ownership over any particular topic or even any particular example. It's similar to downvoting a community wiki answer: No one's really going to notice.

If it's good as-is: upvote

If it can be improved and you have the time to improve it: improve it

If it can be improved and you don't have the time to improve it: leave a note for the future

If it can't be improved: downvote

---

So how do you leave a note for the future?

Ideally we'd have talk pages, or commenting, or feedback, or discussions directly tied to the documentation topics and examples. Not just a one-way flag of "this is a problem fix it", but full dialogue capabilities. We don't really have that, so meta has to do for now.

Unfortunately that means there's no way to tell which meta discussions are related to any particular topic or example. This is a problem on SO as well, There's no way to formally link a meta question to a normal SO question or answer. Instead the way it's typically done is to leave an informal comment linking to the meta discussion.

And again unfortunately that can't be done on documentation yet from what I've seen of it.

Comment: Thanks for putting a positive spin on it ("how do you leave a note for the future"). I hope/assume something like this (talk pages etc.) is in the works.  Of course you are right, it is all new. We'll see how it pans out.

Comment: Accepted - better late then never. Oh and by the way, in my western country, pupils are *still* not allowed to use Wikipedia. But these days, the reason is not its quality, but the fact that it is not a primary source. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is the very problem that Documentation was supposed to solve. From the [original Documentation announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow):

> Documentation is often an afterthought, obviously done just to say that it exists, with little concern for its quality. We've all seen plenty of this in our time.

Followed by an example of [this Tweet](https://twitter.com/jamiedixon/status/633923416886800384):

> Got to love some commercial API documentation: "GetRowEnumerator(); - Gets the rows enumerator" - No further information.

And now what I said about this, in response to that announcement:

> However, that means that the documentation is going to be a direct reflection of the developer's attitude toward documentation. If a developer thinks that Javadocs are enough, that's what you'll get.

So hey, guess what? It turns out that a lot of the developers who made only a token effort to contribute useful documentation when it's their job aren't too likely to do so when they get paid in Internet points. Did I ever tell you the definition of insanity?

**TL;DR: Answer**

If you think a page in Documentation fails whatever criteria are set out for such pages (like "useful" for SO answers or "useful, clear, research effort" for questions), downvote. If you think it meets the criteria for flagging (whatever those are), do so. But if it's just "I think it could be better in specific ways," go ahead and make some edits to improve it. Without that, it'll never get any better.

However, keep in mind that other people's opinions are just as worthy as yours. If other readers are approving such pages en masse, maybe they are good pages. "You're entitled to your opinion, but it's wrong and I'm flagging it" isn't the way this "voting" thing is supposed to work.

If someone is wrong on the Internet and you're actively encouraged to do something about it, what are you waiting for? Just don't expect to be the boss.

Comment: "If someone is wrong on the Internet and you're actively encouraged to do something about it, what are you waiting for?" That's what this meta topic is about; finding out if "we" actually think that the described effect is something to worry about at all.